# Interfaces vs Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-types

What is the difference between these statements (`interface` vs `type`) in TypeScript?

```ts
interface X {
    a: number
    b: string
}

type X = {
    a: number
    b: string
};
```

Comment: Found this article explaining the differences - https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/interface-vs-type-alias-in-typescript-2-7-2a8f1777af4c

Comment: Similar question [difference between type and class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131898/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-class-in-typescript/51132333#51132333)

Comment: Hi, interface and type, looks similar but interfaces can use for "Declaration merging" and "Extends and implements" which "type" cannot do.

Comment: editor's note: please *stop* bringing tag duplication back in titles - you are going against explicit position supported by both the company and the community at large. See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). The most recent version should satisfy both sides.

Comment: One difference that doesn't really seem to be hit upon by any answers is that interfaces create a new, distinct type whereas a type alias is just that: an *alias* (think of it like a C macro that expands to the full type). It's a tricky distinction. The place you're most likely to notice it is in error messages and tooltips, where your type alias can "decay" from it's tidy one-word name to its full definition. Whether that's a good thing depends on circumstance and preference.

Comment: TYPE:
1. Extendable: 
```js
type Point = PartialPointX & { y: number; };
```
2. primitives: 
```js
type Name = string;
```
3. unions: 
```js
type CardType = string | null;
```
4. tuples: 
```js
type Data = [number, string];
```

Interface
1. Extendable: 
```js
interface Point extends PartialPointX { y: number; }
```

2. Declaration merging:
```js
interface Point { x: number; }
interface Point { y: number; }
const point: Point = { x: 1, y: 2 };
```
As you can see both of them can be extended, the cases you can use TYPE is more than Interface.

Comment: @snarf could you expand or provide some example or reference regarding your previous comment?  I am like get into this when need to provide the type for the error of rejected promise in an endpoint and I was only bale to provide unknown, I know is a bit difficult lacking contest but I feel the above distinction provide by you could had help in that situation

Comment: @CarmineTambascia Maybe by way of analogy. Familiar with C#? While interfaces are similar enough between the two languages, TypeScript's `type` keyword is more like a souped-up version of C#'s `using` aliases, e.g. `using StringComparer = System.Func<string, string, int>;`. You aren't declaring a new type there, you're just saving some typing. The distinction just isn't as impactful in a structurally typed language and I'm not sure it's relevant to your situation.

Comment: Difference between types & interfaces as in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces).

Comment: In version of 2022 with interfaces you can't combine intersections and create top level tuples and types are not extendable.

Answer (score 1298, accepted):

**Update March 2021**: The newer TypeScript Handbook (also mentioned in [nju-clc
answer  below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65164318/52277)) has a section [Interfaces vs. Type Aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) which explains the differences.

---

**Original Answer (2016)**

As per the [(now archived) TypeScript Language Specification](https://javascript.xgqfrms.xyz/pdfs/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf):

> Unlike an interface declaration, which always introduces a named object type, **a type alias declaration** can introduce a name for any kind of type, including primitive, union, and intersection types.

The specification goes on to mention:

> **Interface types** have many similarities to type aliases for object type
> literals, but since interface types offer more capabilities they are
> generally preferred to type aliases. For example, the interface type
>
> ```
> interface Point {
>     x: number;
>     y: number;
> }
> ```
>
> could be written as the type alias
>
> ```
> type Point = {
>     x: number;
>     y: number;
> };
> ```
>
> However, doing so means the following capabilities are lost:
>
> - <strike>An interface can be named in an extends or implements clause, but a type alias for an object type literal cannot</strike> No longer true since TS 2.7.
> - An interface can have multiple [merged declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), but a type alias for an object type literal cannot.

Comment: What does "multiple merged declarations" mean in the second difference?

Comment: @jrahhali I think the *augmented* scenario in [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782896/in-typescript-what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-interface) answers your question

Comment: @jrahhali if you define interface twice, typescript merges them into one.

Comment: @jrahhali if you define type twice, typescript gives you error

Comment: @jrahhali `interface Point {
      x: number;
}

 interface Point {
        y: number;
 }`

Comment: I believe first point `extends or implements` is no longer the case. Type can be extended and implemented by a `class`. Here's an example http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20MyType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Hello%20implements%20MyType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20name%20%3D%20%22aaa%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20age%20%3D%20123%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20t%3A%20MyType%20%3D%20new%20Hello()%3B

Comment: ps.: You can quazi "extend" `type`s too. Consider the following: `type PartialPerson = { firstName: string; }; type Person = PartialPerson & { lastName: string; };` ...although, I would not recommend it. : )

Comment: does not help much without any example.

Comment: This answer needs updating due to new TypeScript changes in 2.7+, see https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/interface-vs-type-alias-in-typescript-2-7-2a8f1777af4c

Comment: What about type union which interface does not provide ?

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Comment: I can't believe this user got 200+ for copy pasting what one finds instantaneously. This answer gave no good explanation.

Comment: @basickarl That may be your opinion, but this was the first thing when I Googled the difference between an interface and a type and it basically answers anything I needed to know. The points aren't awarded per complexity, but for being useful, which this answer most certainly was, at least to someone.

Comment: Being able to `merge declarations` is a double edged sword,  and in many contexts NOT being able to do that might be preferred.  OTOH, being able to does provide for more flexible evolution of existing systems, by letting newer code evolve the interface without changing the existing code.

Comment: Concerning `An interface can be named in an extends or implements clause, but a type alias for an object type literal cannot`: This works since TypeScript v2.2, not since v2.7. I tested it with different TS versions and the earliest it lead to a type error was with v2.1 (`error TS2422: A class may only implement another class or interface`).

Comment: If you are wondering which one you should use: `If you would like a heuristic, use interface until you need to use features from type`

Comment: I argue that this hooey about merged interfaces is an anti-pattern and not a desirable feature. Therefore types should be preferred.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. Do you think this is possible in TypeScript? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77588045/470749

Answer (score 1977):

## 2019 Update

---

The current answers and the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/) are outdated. And for those new to TypeScript, the terminology used isn't clear without examples. Below is a list of up-to-date differences.

### 1. Objects / Functions

Both can be used to describe the shape of an object or a function signature. But the syntax differs.

**Interface**

```
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

interface SetPoint {
  (x: number, y: number): void;
}
```

**Type alias**

```
type Point = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
};

type SetPoint = (x: number, y: number) => void;
```

### 2. Other Types

Unlike an interface, the type alias can also be used for other types such as primitives, unions, and tuples.

```
// primitive
type Name = string;

// object
type PartialPointX = { x: number; };
type PartialPointY = { y: number; };

// union
type PartialPoint = PartialPointX | PartialPointY;

// tuple
type Data = [number, string];
```

### 3. Extend

Both can be extended, but again, the syntax differs. Additionally, note that an interface and type alias are not mutually exclusive. An interface can extend a type alias, and vice versa.

**Interface extends interface**

```
interface PartialPointX { x: number; }
interface Point extends PartialPointX { y: number; }
```

**Type alias extends type alias**

```
type PartialPointX = { x: number; };
type Point = PartialPointX & { y: number; };
```

**Interface extends type alias**

```
type PartialPointX = { x: number; };
interface Point extends PartialPointX { y: number; }
```

**Type alias extends interface**

```
interface PartialPointX { x: number; }
type Point = PartialPointX & { y: number; };
```

### 4. Implements

A class can implement an interface or type alias, both in the same exact way. Note however that a class and interface are considered static blueprints. Therefore, they can not implement / extend a type alias that names a union type.

```
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

class SomePoint implements Point {
  x = 1;
  y = 2;
}

type Point2 = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
};

class SomePoint2 implements Point2 {
  x = 1;
  y = 2;
}

type PartialPoint = { x: number; } | { y: number; };

// FIXME: can not implement a union type
class SomePartialPoint implements PartialPoint {
  x = 1;
  y = 2;
}
```

### 5. Declaration merging

Unlike a type alias, an interface can be defined multiple times, and will be treated as a single interface (with members of all declarations being merged).

```
// These two declarations become:
// interface Point { x: number; y: number; }
interface Point { x: number; }
interface Point { y: number; }

const point: Point = { x: 1, y: 2 };
```

Comment: If the official documentation is outdated, where can the information that you provided be confirmed?

Comment: Based on this post, it seems that the *only* reason to choose an interface over a type alias is if you wish to use the declaration merging (point 5) feature of interfaces. Beyond that, they are equivalent (and I'd argue that type aliases offer more concise syntax).

Comment: I always using interfaces for object type literal, otherwise using types make more sense, also I think that declaration merging shouldn't be used in anyways, actually I'll never expect that an interface is being declared in another file of the project with some extra properties, type checking is made originally to make your life easier not to make it harder with this ninja-like interfaces :D

Comment: another good blog https://jameshenry.blog/typescript-classes-vs-interfaces/

Comment: @maxedison I don't know how much outdated the current official docs are but it states: "you should always use an interface over a type alias if possible". [Check it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases)

Comment: So basically, it is "nearly a personal" choice to what we really feel comfortable using? Apart from one reason, you can just use `type` or `interface`? I am still confused to when I should use one or the other.

Comment: Is there a difference in error messages? Do error messages refer to the interfaces by the name of the interface and error messages refer to types by their structure?

Comment: There is [a `Partial` interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) for such partial interfaces in practice, no need to introduce a "PartialInterface" manually like in the examples. `Partial<Point>` allows for objects that only contain some of the `Point` interface.

Comment: Could someone please provide some motivation for why you would want interface merging? That seems potentially confusing to me. Why would you want to spread the definition of your interface across different blocks?

Comment: @Vanquish46 the use case for this is when one library provides the original interface and another library (a plugin, for example) extends the interface.

Comment: Am I the only one bothered by the fact that `type` prevents another _variable/object/class/function_ to use the same name, or import one of the same name, while `interface` do not?

Comment: @FMCorz I don't see why not. I was able to re-use the name to define variable/function in the same file but not redefine the same type, which of course won't happen since types cannot be merged.

Comment: 'type' saves you a click. i.e. on hovering over a 'type'  vscode shows full definition but not in case of interface, for interface you need to ctrl+hover to see definition :D

Comment: I'd like to point out that part 3 of this answer incorrectly conflates intersection ("&") and extension ("extends"): According to [this other stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52681859/8796651), the two operations have slightly different behavior, and therefore may not be interchangeable in the way this answer implies.

Comment: Personal opinion here but I think this is best practice. I prefer to always use `type`, and only use `interface` when dealing with the prototypal inheritance chain (classes and extended functions)

Comment: A use case for declaration merging that I ran into: You are using an ORM (object relational mapper) that automatically generates interfaces for your database tables. You then define the interface again with other properties (business logic). Now you can recreate the ORM interface files without having to worry about whatever you added yourself. In another language (eg C#) you could do the same with partial classes.

Comment: @jabacchetta, it also worth mentioning in point 3, when it comes to the composition of types it is better to extend with interfaces than intersecting types, because intersection just recursively merge properties, and in some cases produce `never`. Interfaces detect such conflicts, and you will be able to resolve them early. Another difference is performance, interfaces are cached, whereas type aliases will be computed every time, these will influence total project compiling time.

Comment: how is point 4 a comparison since the PartialPoint is a union type whereas an interface is an intersection type. it is not an easy matter to inherit union types as they are designed with composition in view.

Comment: Type vs Interface Errors

@CMCDragonkai to answer your question the official documentation answers this in one of their playground:

Interfaces and Types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?e=83#example/types-vs-interfaces

Lines 42-46 read (In case this link is not valid in the future)

// That said, we recommend you use interfaces over type
// aliases. Specifically, because you will get better error
// messages. If you hover over the following errors, you can
// see how TypeScript can provide terser and more focused
// messages when working with interfaces like Chicken.

Comment: I wonder what microsoft's reasoning is behind having two different syntaxes with so much functional overlap

Comment: Another difference I didn't see was mentioned so far is that type alias can not be declared with `export default` while interfaces can be exported as a default.

Comment: @Vanquish46 To expand on what Michal said, declaration merging is **necessary** in Typescript, because it’s the only way to explain something that a lot of Javascript libraries do: extend native objects and objects from the language’s “standard library” (the objects corresponding to web site elements, events, and so on that a browser natively exposes as part of the spec). Since Javascript libraries can do this, and often do, Typescript needed a way to describe it in the type domain or else you wouldn’t have any type safety for those extensions.

Comment: I think this is the official docs for 'type alias vs. interface': https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces and it seems up-to-date.

Comment: for the action parameter used for react reducer-functions using a single object union type is awesome `type Action = { type: "addItem", ...} | { type: "removeItem, ...} | ...` (the inner type is just a property name, not a type). When trying to accomplish that with interfaces you would require a lot of boilerplate code because you would need an interface for each object.

Comment: found the name for it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. Do you think this is possible in TypeScript? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77588045/470749

Comment: This explains the syntax differences, but why does Typescript have different two ways to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 526):

## Relevant in 2021

For typescript version: 4.3.4

---

### TLDR;

My personal convention, which I describe below, is this:

> Always prefer `interface` over `type`.

When to use `type`:

- Use `type` when defining an alias for primitive types (string, boolean, number, bigint, symbol, etc)
- Use `type` when defining tuple types
- Use `type` when defining function types
- Use `type` when defining a union
- Use `type` when trying to overload functions in object types via composition
- Use `type` when needing to take advantage of mapped types

When to use `interface`:

- Use `interface` for all object types where using `type` is not required (see above)
- Use `interface` when you want to take advantage of declaration merging.

### Primitive types

The easiest difference to see between `type` and `interface` is that only `type` can be used to alias a primitive:

```
type Nullish = null | undefined;
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'pear' | 'orange';
type Num = number | bigint;
```

None of these examples are possible to achieve with interfaces.

When providing a type alias for a primitive value, use the `type` keyword.

### Tuple types

Tuples can only be typed via the `type` keyword:

```
type row = [colOne: number, colTwo: string];
```

Use the `type` keyword when providing types for tuples.

### Function types

Functions can be typed by both the `type` and `interface` keywords:

```
// via type
type Sum = (x: number, y: number) => number;

// via interface
interface Sum {
  (x: number, y: number): number;
}
```

Since the same effect can be achieved either way, the rule will be to use `type` in these scenarios since it's a little easier to read (and less verbose).

Use `type` when defining function types.

### Union types

Union types can only be achieved with the `type` keyword:

```
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'pear' | 'orange';
type Vegetable = 'broccoli' | 'carrot' | 'lettuce';

// 'apple' | 'pear' | 'orange' | 'broccoli' | 'carrot' | 'lettuce';
type HealthyFoods = Fruit | Vegetable;
```

When defining union types, use the `type` keyword

### Object types

An object in JavaScript is a key/value map, and an "object type" is typescript's way of typing those key/value maps. Both `interface` and `type` can be used when providing types for an object as the original question makes clear. So when do you use `type` vs `interface` for object types?

#### Intersection vs Inheritance

With types and composition, I can do something like this:

```
interface NumLogger { 
    log: (val: number) => void;
}
type StrAndNumLogger = NumLogger & { 
  log: (val: string) => void;
}

const logger: StrAndNumLogger = {
  log: (val: string | number) => console.log(val)
}

logger.log(1)
logger.log('hi')
```

Typescript is totally happy. What about if I tried to extend that with interface:

```
interface StrAndNumLogger extends NumLogger { 
    log: (val: string) => void; 
};
```

The declaration of `StrAndNumLogger` gives me an [error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIFcC2AZA9gc32mQG9kAoZK5AGwIC5kAKANzhsZCwCNoBKZAF4AfMha5gAEwDc5AL7lQkWIhQBlMFACCISRhwEiUZBAAekXQGc0WPIWJlK1Ovkat2jS5tD4BIsRIyFHLSQA):

`Interface 'StrAndNumLogger' incorrectly extends interface 'NumLogger'`

With interfaces, the subtypes have to exactly match the types declared in the super type, otherwise TS will throw an error like the one above.

When trying to overload functions in object types, you'll be better off using the `type` keyword.

#### Declaration Merging

The key aspect to interfaces in typescript that distinguish them from types is that they can be extended with new functionality after they've already been declared. A common use case for this feature occurs when you want to extend the types that are exported from a node module. For example, `@types/jest` exports types that can be used when working with the jest library. However, jest also allows for extending the main `jest` type with new functions. For example, I can add a custom test like this:

```
jest.timedTest = async (testName, wrappedTest, timeout) =>
  test(
    testName,
    async () => {
      const start = Date.now();
      await wrappedTest(mockTrack);
      const end = Date.now();

      console.log(`elapsed time in ms: ${end - start}`);
    },
    timeout
  );
```

And then I can use it like this:

```
test.timedTest('this is my custom test', () => {
  expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

And now the time elapsed for that test will be printed to the console once the test is complete. Great! There's only one problem - typescript has no clue that i've added a `timedTest` function, so it'll throw an error in the editor (the code will run fine, but TS will be angry).

To resolve this, I need to tell TS that there's a new type on top of the existing types that are already available from jest. To do that, I can do this:

```
declare namespace jest {
  interface It {
    timedTest: (name: string, fn: (mockTrack: Mock) => any, timeout?: number) => void;
  }
}
```

Because of how interfaces work, this type declaration will be *merged* with the type declarations exported from `@types/jest`. So I didn't just re-declare `jest.It`; I extended `jest.It` with a new function so that TS is now aware of my custom test function.

This type of thing is not possible with the `type` keyword. If `@types/jest` had declared their types with the `type` keyword, I wouldn't have been able to extend those types with my own custom types, and therefore there would have been no good way to make TS happy about my new function. This process that is unique to the `interface` keyword is called [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

Declaration merging is also possible to do locally like this:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

interface Person {
  age: number;
}

// no error
const person: Person = {
  name: 'Mark',
  age: 25
};
```

If I did the exact same thing above with the `type` keyword, I would have gotten an error since types cannot be re-declared/merged. In the real world, JavaScript objects are much like this `interface` example; they can be dynamically updated with new fields at runtime.

Because interface declarations can be merged, interfaces more accurately represent the dynamic nature of JavaScript objects than types do, and they should be preferred for that reason.

#### Mapped object types

With the `type` keyword, I can take advantage of [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) like this:

```
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'orange' | 'banana';

type FruitCount = {
  [key in Fruit]: number;
}

const fruits: FruitCount = {
  apple: 2,
  orange: 3,
  banana: 4
};
```

This cannot be done with interfaces:

```
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'orange' | 'banana';

// ERROR: 
interface FruitCount {
  [key in Fruit]: number;
}
```

When needing to take advantage of mapped types, use the `type` keyword

#### Performance

Much of the time, a simple type alias to an object type acts very similarly to an interface.

```
interface Foo { prop: string }

type Bar = { prop: string };
```

However, and as soon as you need to compose two or more types, you have the option of extending those types with an interface, or intersecting them in a type alias, and that's when the differences start to matter.

Interfaces create a single flat object type that detects property conflicts, which are usually important to resolve! Intersections on the other hand just recursively merge properties, and in some cases produce never. Interfaces also display consistently better, whereas type aliases to intersections can't be displayed in part of other intersections. Type relationships between interfaces are also cached, as opposed to intersection types as a whole. A final noteworthy difference is that when checking against a target intersection type, every constituent is checked before checking against the "effective"/"flattened" type.

For this reason, extending types with interfaces/extends is suggested over creating intersection types.

Also, from the TypeScript documentation

> That said, we recommend you use interfaces over type
> aliases. Specifically, because you will get better error
> messages. If you hover over the following errors, you can
> see how TypeScript can provide terser and more focused
> messages when working with interfaces like Chicken.

More in the [typescript wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance).

Comment: Honestly, I think declaration merging is quite a terrible feature that will sometime be quite obscure. To me it feels often like "extending prototypes" in javascript: you extend functionality that also leaks to other parts of the program. Sure it can be powerful and will make things possible, but really shouldn't be used/considered often.

Comment: @paul23 to extend used external libraries with their own types it's very helpfull and easy to use

Comment: @ZiiMakc sure, but that's the same argument that could be said to prototype extending. We need to look into how much problems it provides to someone who just "adds" a library.

Comment: If you're using eslint you can set `"@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions": [ "error", "interface" ]` to check this behaviour for you.

Comment: Coming from more traditional OOP (Java), I find it strange to use an interface for everything. The semantic meaning has been quite different from different perspectives. Would I for example return an interface as a response type for example? I don't want to 'nag', but I feel that the meaning in terms of certain design practices seems to get lost because Typescript interfaces aren't quite what I'm used to in terms of design pratise. I hope this doesn't bring any beginning programmers problems later on. Just my two cents.

Comment: @html_programmer If anything, I find the term "interface" very apropos since in statically typed languages, what we are saying with an interface is "an object shaped like this" not "an object typed like this" (as is the case with a class/type).  That's pretty much what it means in TypeScript: something shaped like this.

Comment: I would add: Use type when you want to deeply merge interfaces or Record-types. I.e. `interface A { ... }; interface B { ... }; type AB = A & B`. Interface extension works only at one level, but intersections can merge their object-like props.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. Do you think this is possible in TypeScript? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77588045/470749

Answer (score 268):

As of TypeScript 3.2 (Nov 2018), the following is true:

| Aspect | Type | Interface |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Can describe functions | ✅ | ✅ |
| Can describe constructors | ✅ | ✅ |
| Can describe tuples | ✅ | ✅ |
| Interfaces can extend it | ⚠️ | ✅ |
| Classes can extend it |  | ✅ |
| Classes can implement it (`implements`) | ⚠️ | ✅ |
| Can intersect another one of its kind | ✅ | ⚠️ |
| Can create a union with another one of its kind | ✅ |  |
| Can be used to create mapped types | ✅ |  |
| Can be mapped over with mapped types | ✅ | ✅ |
| Expands in error messages and logs | ✅ |  |
| Can be augmented |  | ✅ |
| Can be recursive | ⚠️ | ✅ |

⚠️ In some cases

Comment: Could you please provide more information about how the table/image you provided was generated? e.g. source code or links to documentation

Comment: yes, I meant the source of the content, not its presentation.

Comment: I don't believe a _class_ can _extend_ either a type  or an interface, and I can't really see why you would want to??

Comment: @DanKing is right: a class extends a value, not a type.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP meant the class implements an interface or a type

Comment: Is there a source for this comparison? Would be nice to have some links for further reading.

Comment: Avoid posting images of text, instead include the actual text directly into your post. Images of text are not easily parsable or searchable, and are not accessible to visually impaired users.

Comment: This table lacks any sources to support its contents and I wouldn't rely on it. For example, you can define recursive types using `type` with certain limitations (and as of TypeScript 3.7 these limitations are gone too). Interfaces can extend types. Classes can implement types. Moreover, presenting data as a screenshot of a table makes it completely inaccessible to people with impaired vision.

Comment: @iX3 found the source of this content https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#types-or-interfaces , actually was a   tweet from this answer's original author

Comment: @jacobq Here. https://twitter.com/karoljmajewski/status/1082413696075382785?s=20

Comment: As far as I can tell (as Sept. 2021), this table is Karol Majewski's original work. The GitHub link cites the Tweet, and the twitter conversation mentions a forthcoming book. I am hopeful that the book with include references (e.g. to the spec/docs), but so far I have not seen any.

Answer (score 124):

---

### When to use `type`?

---

**Generic Transformations**

Use the `type` when you are transforming multiple types into a single generic type.

Example:

```
type Nullable<T> = T | null | undefined
type NonNull<T> = T extends (null | undefined) ? never : T
```

---

**Type Aliasing**

We can use the `type` for creating the aliases for long or complicated types that are hard to read as well as inconvenient to type again and again.

Example:

```
type Primitive = number | string | boolean | null | undefined
```

Creating an alias like this makes the code more concise and readable.

---

**Type Capturing**

Use the `type` to capture the type of an object when the type is unknown.

Example:

```
const orange = { color: "Orange", vitamin: "C"}
type Fruit = typeof orange
let apple: Fruit
```

Here, we get the unknown type of `orange`, call it a `Fruit` and then use the `Fruit` to create a new type-safe object `apple`.

---

### When to use `interface`?

---

**Polymorphism**

An `interface` is a contract to implement a shape of the data. Use the interface to make it clear that it is intended to be implemented and used as a contract about how the object will be used.

Example:

```
interface Bird {
    size: number
    fly(): void
    sleep(): void
}

class Hummingbird implements Bird { ... }
class Bellbird implements Bird { ... }
```

Though you can use the `type` to achieve this, the Typescript is seen more as an object oriented language and the `interface` has a special place in object oriented languages. It's easier to read the code with `interface` when you are working in a team environment or contributing to the open source community. It's easy on the new programmers coming from the other object oriented languages too.

The official Typescript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases) also says:

> ... we recommend using an `interface` over a `type` alias when possible.

*This also suggests that the `type` is more intended for creating type aliases than creating the types themselves.*

---

**Declaration Merging**

You can use the declaration merging feature of the `interface` for adding new properties and methods to an already declared `interface`. This is useful for the ambient type declarations of third party libraries. When some declarations are missing for a third party library, you can declare the interface again with the same name and add new properties and methods.

Example:

We can extend the above `Bird` interface to include new declarations.

```
interface Bird {
    color: string
    eat(): void
}
```

---

That's it! It's easier to remember when to use what than getting lost in subtle differences between the two.

Comment: I've found this answer to be the best in explaining when to use one vs the other.

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer. Use Interface for what an Interface is intended for. For other use cases, use type alias

Answer (score 65):

[TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) gives the answer:

> Almost all features of an interface are available in type.
> The key distinction is that a type cannot be re-opened to add new
> properties vs an interface which is always extendable.

Answer (score 28):

### Update April 2023:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html (Go to the new page)

---

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html (This page has been deprecated)

> One difference is that interfaces create a new name that is used everywhere. Type aliases don’t create a new name — for instance, error messages won’t use the alias name.

Comment: This is now outdated and no longer true since TypeScript 2.1. See. https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/interface-vs-type-alias-in-typescript-2-7-2a8f1777af4c

Answer (score 25):

### Examples with Types:

// create a tree structure for an object. You can't do the same with interface because of lack of intersection (&)

```
type Tree<T> = T & { parent: Tree<T> };
```

// type to restrict a variable to assign only a few values. Interfaces don't have union (|)

```
type Choise = "A" | "B" | "C";
```

// thanks to types, you can declare NonNullable type thanks to a conditional mechanism.

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;
```

### Examples with Interface:

// you can use interface for OOP and use 'implements' to define object/class skeleton

```
interface IUser {
    user: string;
    password: string;
    login: (user: string, password: string) => boolean;
}

class User implements IUser {
    user = "user1"
    password = "password1"

    login(user: string, password: string) {
        return (user == user && password == password)
    }
}
```

// you can extend interfaces with other interfaces

```
    interface IMyObject {
        label: string,
    }

    interface IMyObjectWithSize extends IMyObject{
        size?: number
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

Other answers are great! Few other things which `Type` can do but `Interface` can't

#### You can use union in type

```
type Name = string | { FullName: string };

const myName = "Jon"; // works fine

const myFullName: Name = {
  FullName: "Jon Doe", //also works fine
};
```

#### Iterating over union properties in type

```
type Keys = "firstName" | "lastName";

type Name = {
  [key in Keys]: string;
};

const myName: Name = {
  firstName: "jon",
  lastName: "doe",
};
```

#### Intersection in type ( however, also supported in Interface with `extends`)

```
type Name = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
};

type Address = {
  city: string;
};

const person: Name & Address = {
  firstName: "jon",
  lastName: "doe",
  city: "scranton",
};
```

Also not that `type` was introduced later as compared to `interface` and according to the latest release of TS `type` can do *almost everything which `interface` can and much more!

---

*except `Declaration merging` (*personal opinion: It's good that it's not supported in type as it may lead to inconsistency in code*)

Answer (score 14):

**Difference in indexing.**

```js
interface MyInterface {
  foobar: string;
}

type MyType = {
  foobar: string;
}

const exampleInterface: MyInterface = { foobar: 'hello world' };
const exampleType: MyType = { foobar: 'hello world' };

let record: Record<string, string> = {};

record = exampleType;      // Compiles
record = exampleInterface; // Index signature is missing
```

[Related issue: Index signature is missing in type (only on interfaces, not on type alias)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300)

So please consider this example, if you want to index your object

Take a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64970414/typescript-assigning-an-interface-or-a-type-to-a-recordstring-string) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58251698/does-this-typescript-example-violate-the-liskov-subtitution-principle) about violation of Liskov principle

**Difference in evaluation**

See the result type of `ExtendFirst` when `FirstLevelType` is interface

```js
/**
 * When FirstLevelType is interface 
 */

interface FirstLevelType<A, Z> {
    _: "typeCheck";
};

type TestWrapperType<T, U> = FirstLevelType<T, U>;


const a: TestWrapperType<{ cat: string }, { dog: number }> = {
  _: "typeCheck",
};

// {  cat: string; }
type ExtendFirst = typeof a extends FirstLevelType<infer T, infer _>
    ? T
    : "not extended";
```

See the result type of `ExtendFirst` when `FirstLevelType` is a type:

```js
/**
 * When FirstLevelType is type
 */
type FirstLevelType<A, Z>= {
    _: "typeCheck";
};

type TestWrapperType<T, U> = FirstLevelType<T, U>;


const a: TestWrapperType<{ cat: string }, { dog: number }> = {
  _: "typeCheck",
};

// unknown
type ExtendFirst = typeof a extends FirstLevelType<infer T, infer _>
    ? T
    : "not extended";
```

Comment: That's the biggest practical difference imho - an interface will never be assignable to `Record<string, unknown>`

Answer (score 11):

The key difference pointed out in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) is that `Interface` can be reopened to add new property but `Type alias` cannot be reopened to add new property eg:

This is ok

```
interface x {
  name: string
}

interface x {
  age: number
}
```

this will throw the error `Duplicate identifier y`

```
type y = {
  name: string
}

type y = {
  age: number
}
```

Asides from that both interface and type alias are similar.

Answer (score 9):

In typescript, "interface" is recommended over "type".

- "type" is used for creating `type aliases`. You cannot do this with "interface".

  ```
   type Data=string
  ```

  Then instead of using string, you can use "Data"

  ```
  const name:string="Yilmaz"
  const name:Data="Yilmaz"
  ```

Aliases are very useful especially working with generic types.

- `Declaration Merging:` You can merge interfaces but not types.

  ```
  interface Person {
      name: string;
    }

    interface Person {
      age: number;
    }
    // we have to provide properties in both Person
    const me: Person = {
      name: "Yilmaz",
      age: 30
    };
  ```
- functional programming users use "type", object-oriented programing users choose "interface"
- You can’t have computed or calculated properties on interfaces but in type.

  ```
   type Fullname = "firstname" | "lastname"

    type  Person= {
       [key in Fullname]: string
    }

    const me: Person = {
       firstname: "Yilmaz",
       lastname: "Bingol"
    }
  ```

Answer (score 9):

In my daily development, I use this cheatsheet when I don't know which to choose.

[image]

For more information, you can read my blog: https://medium.com/@magenta2127/use-which-interface-or-type-alias-in-typescript-bdfaf2e882ae

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the brilliant answers already provided, there are noticeable differences when it comes to *extending* types vs interfaces. I recently ran into a couple of cases where an interface couldn't do the job:

1. [Couldn't extend a union type using an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56085306/error-message-an-interface-can-only-extend-an-object-type-or-intersection-of-o)
2. [Couldn't extend generic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370163/extending-generic-typescript-interface)

Answer (score 5):

### Interfaces vs types

Interfaces and types are used to describe the types of objects and primitives. Both interfaces and types can often be used interchangeably and often provide similar functionality. Usually it is the choice of the programmer to pick their own preference.

However, interfaces can only describe objects and classes that create these objects. Therefore types must be used in order to describe primitives like strings and numbers.

Here is an example of 2 differences between interfaces and types:

```
// 1. Declaration merging (interface only)

// This is an extern dependency which we import an object of
interface externDependency { x: number, y: number; }
// When we import it, we might want to extend the interface, e.g. z:number
// We can use declaration merging to define the interface multiple times
// The declarations will be merged and become a single interface
interface externDependency { z: number; }
const dependency: externDependency = {x:1, y:2, z:3}

// 2. union types with primitives (type only)

type foo = {x:number}
type bar = { y: number }
type baz = string | boolean;

type foobarbaz = foo | bar | baz; // either foo, bar, or baz type

// instances of type foobarbaz can be objects (foo, bar) or primitives (baz)
const instance1: foobarbaz = {y:1} 
const instance2: foobarbaz = {x:1} 
const instance3: foobarbaz = true
```

Comment: A fellow willem!

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to compilation speed, composed interfaces perform better than type intersections:

> [...] interfaces create a single flat object type that detects property conflicts. This is in contrast with intersection types, where every constituent is checked before checking against the effective type. Type relationships between interfaces are also cached, as opposed to intersection types.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance#preferring-interfaces-over-intersections

Answer (score 3):

Want to add my 2 cents;

I used to be *"an interface lover"* (preferring `interface` to `type` except for Unions, Intersections etc)... **until** I started to use the type "any key-value object" a.k.a `Record<string, unknown>`

If you type something as "any key-value object":

```
function foo(data: Record<string, unknown>): void {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    // whatever
  }
}
```

You might reach an dead end if you use `interface`

```
interface IGoo {
  iam: string;
}

function getGoo(): IGoo {
  return { iam: 'an interface' };
}

const goo = getGoo(); 

foo(goo); // ERROR
// Argument of type 'IGoo' is not assignable to parameter of type 
// 'Record<string, unknown>'.
//  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 
// 'IGoo'.ts(2345)
```

While `type` just works like a charm:

```
type Hoo = {
  iam: string;
};

function getHoo(): Hoo {
  return { iam: 'a type' }; 
}

const hoo = getHoo(); 

foo(hoo); // works
```

This particular use case - IMO - makes the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another difference.  I will... buy you a beer if you can explain the reasoning or reason as to this state of affairs:

```
enum Foo { a = 'a', b = 'b' }

type TFoo = {
  [k in Foo]: boolean;
}

const foo1: TFoo = { a: true, b: false} // good
// const foo2: TFoo = { a: true }       // bad: missing b
// const foo3: TFoo = { a: true, b: 0}  // bad: b is not a boolean

// So type does roughly what I'd expect and want

interface IFoo {
//  [k in Foo]: boolean;
/*
  Uncommenting the above line gives the following errors:
  A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a      
    literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
  A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
  Cannot find name 'k'.
*/
}

// ???
```

This sort of makes me want to say **the hell with interfaces** unless I'm intentionally implementing some OOP design pattern, or require merging as described above (which I'd never do unless I had a *very* good reason for it).

Answer (score 1):

Demonstrate the ability to recursively re-write Object Literal types and interfaces recursively and not class members/properties/functions.

Also how to distinguish and type check differences and workaround to the problem discussed above, when Record<any, string|number> doesn't work due being interfaces and things like that, you work around it.
This would allow for simplifications to the following potentially for mongoose types:
https://github.com/wesleyolis/mongooseRelationalTypes [mongooseRelationalTypes, DeepPopulate, populate](https://github.com/wesleyolis/mongooseRelationalTypes)

Also, a bunch of another approaches to do advanced type generics and type inference and the quirks around it for speed, all little tricks to get them right from many experiments, of trial and error.

Typescript playground:
[Click here for all examples in a live play ground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhaBvAUNH1gHsA7ZAJwFdgl8SAKABzICMQBLYaMALmkLIFtG8EgBpoDZm2iNupFoQDmouiRYA3MEnh4ZSFQoCUGTNlwBfTOcyhIMBMgAi0Fnzoh4feISQwASvAIkACYAPGCEAJ6iYeEAfEYmOATEuhRUtOKs7Fw8-IIiYkyZUjp6imIq6pra0LIG8bjQlg2ayDSG3LwCQkYNDSTwSGQkhNAAjADcCY0WxkjhdFoAkl5CAGZgwPAAgtAAvD0N2bWKU9I5XSJTwNz2GvBT8Nx2qMJTq0+ISPavDYTwkJpAltuFherhAiU5CcwThHuc8lMGgALG53H4wgBWH2QKERuD+APggQAQiC8WCITVdFD0TDcHDOgi6cjUZpacysXBPri6eYGuZLJg5gs4Cgkf4ANYocBQPwQMggJB7aDLTQkdabHbwAAemkIgV8-moIWiojIhAlhHwAHdCHEAPzQADkAE0ndwnQA5J3QAD0vugLuMSWQ0ECyr+1ugt00bUmwq0sDFkulNjlCtQMpg+wT+FWYegOr1BugfgCJoiZotVttDudbo93rB-ugnuDRFDHiQYBjYGVAGVwgJ8CAaE6uz2NGAnfp4-MtABZAaT7uD4cgZW5-MT3uTTAtrYgEA2mBkGBUHj4JX9YBnrRyC-WKDQBNOFbqjaIaDUF8kMCBFgkBYIgwA3B81k-CBRDkaBrSRNgkXKfAFhIICvzCcNVnNShgOIKQjQ8b86CAkCQAAOiFedoAXMAJXgABREgSGofsUkoIZ4GCWBC11TwSzLY1QkrDgIhiOJ9lBXAAG0AGk32gOjwjzOAAF1oHtbgaFgWS1KLPjDXLITImgc1LRtO11OZGi6MY5iSFY8h2P6LidJiJ4dOgAAyUsjSCYIl27Xs10YEdRCdW9kHwPgADEWHgEBAidGJ9BmSiRWs+AAHliNw0CuJ44sDME00RNicSDhwWT5MU5TYDUjS4A8vT9SKvyStMmsLMdDLspIwg8u0mSVLidyhtS18fEm5Uepy0jglVCDNRiKwO2vL9lXQUwOF8Sa9xDJVOmVfoIDI+AAEIyLAcY-QDV9dn2RkhBW5JzgAJiOxAyNWC6WiQOMbpfKj7vhJ60sXWj4DLM81E4mT4HCGBmpLY5RFgcrJMquSYLhhGVKeLzqIhqGIBh4IZNR5acC27zYFmKiMuJmHMsESgcYgLi2YK-SqVKCmNqmKqYJq-M6u4OSkdsTnHUGtTvIZ-xodUWHUdc0aVPGqjFgEoJFlgedsx5qFoAAHxqIcQo3U3HpIPcWwAVQgIloFWH9gHFYAJSN8CP02UQWbAO8fMMp1FKdUQADVQLIeA4h1UAyECIkYG9jVEDBlVtZCWAca5lqM98wJdf11HI5AaP0YFrGRmz+HtugAADAASdA5O845THrtSnlL6OLAaYx061gutgiHvOO4iWg+KytohiEuo5j-mGkFkZhdU6Bu4XvvcGMFPP2gLYdgxg+N5By4GmJU-jlSvfNmgYlL+P4Ez-ZexWXuSwW1geCYDAOhlHwBsRCwAwgcBABAfA+ETKO0CKIF2JA3yJ1WHIQC8VwjQBvEMEmStoDqFYIEDQuFoCsDohwMM8B4B0DEMhBUaJYLwTdngMITolSJzVHwOQWg4IaFwaBFgBCqiCHgfAJEGEKK3y0MmD2ZYUCrT-A+CAr18qTyHuWEe4Qx5cVENbE2hsFBiSMJYCaiAdj7CkRKGRciwAKKUYfOILY8H8LpiKOUl8zHuwsf4WRyR5FeEUcEB+9iAxyEcYEYwB5FRCH6kBHB8C8AeKNopCAnBnFLEzjjMeSiJ68TzpnIywhZ6oxziozORcFhQTgGPcqmBj4rwUvDWqXdoBaRzt5GShhJ5-CVggx0XTuibzLh-aA4SAzfxYL-f+zEgFMJGKBCBUC7ywOdj+OQSCUGaBAOgzBJBsFaFCYQogxCWCkL7InSh1CGDgDZPQhCMyWHkPYZw+hPD9mCPgMI0R+pxHvlTtAcxlifHWL8conJJZVHGgyQvLJ2jcjdFNijM+ujjgGKfqfWmRiqJ2yxcqcFQRIWDNsVsUQCLji6OtstdOcotjvXcZKAFpAgXeEJUE3h+DUk+QgMSGlfyPH0t0Iy-xgSAYhL4WE8JAAqTA9FtRgBcG4b8+ZoYKGjOM4AKgOHROoBUpENp4DdLgT+CACwnaLFgvgBU4Y-xIHFAgwOrA1SgU2Tcxhay-iI2mYpF8kDM4iXDNazw0BRE4LoDYJ2F55CeCEHcF84poAcO1E7PB0cYD+0DnaxAMAPB8GoOgjCUD1jIG6Na0B1rxkcEmYAt2FFoDit9APV8uLAj4ujiCwqU82oz1EkU2uJSC5lMQPPQZ1TalV3qUpEWTSWm1zaR00FMA+k9J4Hq-plSt5bXZY2nGeTsltryaaQpcBilzvzuWftEBh2V2qg0idp8p3oJnbnEsC7LLPrVgDP4YbIHIPkBxb8ZAlT+rwHIh8gahBaDiSFa1b41S-LzTeY0J0+7svokrLw9EOFIDVN479HMe3HtJfC82I4yWwvyLAMeqMaJUN7eWZt48qPduMuRheBiJJTD4H-J4VGNYigAApsAlDjVt3M92dtiIxx9v9RLKi0lJGu4RdLHq2ExMA4QjJ1m0vJppcm5M4xUipQw3llN-jUwuilr4UOeCQOhwCap7DYZYPIZUlm0MYaw0QHDBGzbriiMJWeA8JFwHsC56zbmhBcQc05yeIWbOYaEJF-JpVUaRakuOP+TphrOdQ6F2zQh7Mecc+yWAVHlRJgK-IVLHG6AZaKygIBDFssyVWQbNexW-6YDiMfKYRBcPoMnkmerIWmstVRpJg+Km1Oz2VPxj2Qm2t0EY2JGgy6vBPBxqIckRzC1-BIJpMi+2wAkHkMkuAhhdhxFUPgfh+huClogHuBo7hAK9bGwNt2DWrPDYNKNyexnVPqemwJubDHD3wyWytpAa34aiH25dI7J3YA3akPgEc-xCCTAxS4gusB8D2FVequQdwvt1fexzVZesRSTy8xAIjlsX6HtWZ6WVWh+tfYp-AH7x7N3w23UU8n85WMVWgHU1rk6ZYE23V9pnHhRAyWSjxrQeOIBqucITzQX3orMT4CT8Uwm87c-CLz0qgvtKi4Cz8-eIWj5TDZ5wJ0bOthOimFbj0VuneWECyFx+Nvyd27Z8SJ3DQveu+ywHm+Fu74hbQMfW39vycoED7gKPIerMJ4V9AK38PlRSWtsS6kCh1aD00HwA2Mfyc7G4Fb9k-vT5e+r-H2v2WeS4AAAyN6s8p47rxP6+lfErlXGqNDUDZ-OO2hBcI660PsTOOP+8E+ifAYn9XggIoAERfYAOKeFX6IRYxfz17j7-j1XmqSAj4WGPif9XlQz9x8fwf6vVmT5X-npzVtSPCHX6srfhAd8qn3zEIflRJPoXMXtFCxMauGPsHPifkPmfvzhfuPkQJPqlv7hluyjAQ-sPggfAJfoctAffmrovqsprlFM-pgWrtgfqOzngYQJPoAcYFhIQDhIcjqLKq4PAG0ELlcKtC+J8BtFtJADgBQafufrgUgejlMBANaIBG7DQL9GRJvp4IYMfA0CAo7M6A7u6Jts0J8GRFbjobgIwP0LRJMHSOoVoHHtQQHiksyLgAoV7oYTgMYf8BKGYTCBYZofHtoXYTgA4U3sYOYZAFoC3rYb4QoVQAADL4AgJuAORQiBFmCpTpyxbuaEDfpZZWapHxblYv6lAkYXC+bGR77uAH7tgvTZEkDLDIBhB3ycCwDBbZaVHBCVGRYMFSphZVHJC1HwBkREA0Bf7WE740BgB+xnadZTBTBgAUQWD6BAA)

```
    class TestC {
        constructor(public a: number, public b: string, private c: string) {
    
        }
    }
    
    class TestD implements Record<any, any> {
    
        constructor(public a: number, public b: string, private c: string) {
    
        }
    
        test() : number {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    type InterfaceA = {
         a: string,
        b: number,
        c: Date
        e: TestC,
        f: TestD,
        p: [number],
        neastedA: {
            d: string,
            e: number
            h: Date,
            j: TestC
            neastedB: {
                d: string,
                e: number
                h: Date,
                j: TestC
            }
        }
    }


    type TCheckClassResult = InterfaceA extends Record<any, unknown> ? 'Y': 'N' // Y

    const d = new Date();
    type TCheckClassResultClass = typeof d extends Record<any, unknown> ? 'Y': 'N'      // N

    const metaData = Symbol('metaData');
    type MetaDataSymbol = typeof metaData;

    // Allows us to not recuse into class type interfaces or traditional interfaces, in which properties and functions become optional.
    type MakeErrorStructure<T extends Record<any, any>> = {
        [K in keyof T] ?: (T[K] extends Record<any, unknown> ?         MakeErrorStructure<T[K]>: T[K] & Record<MetaDataSymbol, 'customField'>)
    }

    type MakeOptional<T extends Record<any, any>> = {
        [K in keyof T] ?: T[K] extends Record<any, unknown> ? MakeOptional<T[K]> : T[K]
    }

    type RRR = MakeOptional<InterfaceA>
    const res  = {} as RRR;

    const num = res.e!.a; // type == number
    const num2 = res.f!.test(); // type == number
```

Making recursive shapes or keys of specific shape recursive

```
    type MakeRecusive<Keys extends string, T> = {
        [K in Keys]: T & MakeRecusive<K, T>
      } & T
  
    type MakeRecusiveObectKeys<TKeys extends string, T> = {
        [K in keyof T]: K extends TKeys ? T[K] & MakeRecusive<K, T[K]>: T[K]
    }
```

How to apply type constraints, for Record Types, which can validate interfaces like Discriminators:

```
    type IRecordITypes = string | symbol | number;
    
    // Used for checking interface, because Record<'key', Value> excludeds interfaces
    type IRecord<TKey extends IRecordITypes, TValue> = {
        [K in TKey as `${K & string}`] : TValue
    } 


    // relaxies the valiation, older versions can't validate.
    // type IRecord<TKey extends IRecordITypes, TValue> = {
    //     [index: TKey] : TValue
    // } 

    
    type IRecordAnyValue<T extends Record<any,any>, TValue> = {
        [K in keyof T] : TValue
    }    

    interface AA {
        A : number,
        B : string
    }

    interface BB {
        A: number,
        D: Date
    }

    // This approach can also be used, for indefinitely recursive validation like a deep populate, which can't determine what validate beforehand.
    interface CheckRecConstraints<T extends IRecordAnyValue<T, number | string>> {
    }

    type ResA = CheckRecConstraints<AA> // valid

    type ResB = CheckRecConstraints<BB> // invalid

Alternative for checking keys:

    type IRecordKeyValue<T extends Record<any,any>, TKey extends IRecordITypes, TValue> = 
    {
        [K in keyof T] : (TKey & K) extends never ? never : TValue
    } 
    
    // This approach can also be used, for indefinitely recursive validation like a deep populate, which can't determine what validate beforehand.
    interface CheckRecConstraints<T extends IRecordKeyValue<T, number | string, number | string>> {
        A : T
    }

    type UUU = IRecordKeyValue<AA, string, string | number>

    type ResA = CheckRecConstraints<AA> // valid

    type ResB = CheckRecConstraints<BB> // invalid
```

Example of using Discriminators, however, for speed I would rather use literally which defines each key to Record and then have passed to generate the mixed values because use less memory and be faster than this approach.

```
    type EventShapes<TKind extends string> = IRecord<TKind, IRecordITypes> | (IRecord<TKind, IRecordITypes> & EventShapeArgs)

    type NonClassInstance = Record<any, unknown>
    type CheckIfClassInstance<TCheck, TY, TN> = TCheck extends NonClassInstance ? 'N' : 'Y'

    type EventEmitterConfig<TKind extends string = string, TEvents extends EventShapes<TKind> = EventShapes<TKind>, TNever = never> = {
        kind: TKind
        events: TEvents
        noEvent: TNever
    }

    type UnionDiscriminatorType<TKind extends string, T extends Record<TKind, any>> = T[TKind]

    type PickDiscriminatorType<TConfig extends EventEmitterConfig<any, any, any>,
        TKindValue extends string,
        TKind extends string = TConfig['kind'],        
        T extends Record<TKind, IRecordITypes> & ({} | EventShapeArgs) = TConfig['events'],
        TNever = TConfig['noEvent']> = 
            T[TKind] extends TKindValue 
            ? TNever
            : T extends IRecord<TKind, TKindValue>
                ? T extends EventShapeArgs
                    ? T['TArgs']
                    : [T]
                : TNever        

    type EventEmitterDConfig = EventEmitterConfig<'kind', {kind: string | symbol}, any>
    type EventEmitterDConfigKeys = EventEmitterConfig<any, any> // Overide the cached process of the keys.

    interface EventEmitter<TConfig extends EventEmitterConfig<any, any, any> = EventEmitterDConfig,
                TCacheEventKinds extends string = UnionDiscriminatorType<TConfig['kind'], TConfig['events']>
                > {
      on<TKey extends TCacheEventKinds, 
                    T extends Array<any> = PickDiscriminatorType<TConfig, TKey>>(
                        event: TKey, 
                        listener: (...args: T) => void): this;

     emit<TKey extends TCacheEventKinds>(event: TKey, args: PickDiscriminatorType<TConfig, TKey>): boolean;
    }
```

Example of usage:

```
    interface EventA {
        KindT:'KindTA'
        EventA: 'EventA'
    }

    interface EventB {
        KindT:'KindTB'
        EventB: 'EventB'
    }

    interface EventC {
        KindT:'KindTC'
        EventC: 'EventC'
    }

    interface EventArgs {
        KindT:1
        TArgs: [string, number]    
    }
    const test :EventEmitter<EventEmitterConfig<'KindT', EventA | EventB | EventC | EventArgs>>;

    test.on("KindTC",(a, pre) => {
        
    })
```

Better Approach to discriminate types and Pick Types from a map for narrowing, which typically results in faster performance and less overhead to type manipulation and allow improved caching. compare to the previous example above.

```
    type IRecordKeyValue<T extends Record<any,any>, TKey extends IRecordITypes, TValue> = 
    {
        [K in keyof T] : (TKey & K) extends never ? never : TValue
    } 

    type IRecordKeyRecord<T extends Record<any,any>, TKey extends IRecordITypes> = 
    {
        [K in keyof T] : (TKey & K) extends never ? never : T[K] // need to figure out the constrint here for both interface and records.
    } 
    
    type EventEmitterConfig<TKey extends string | symbol | number, TValue, TMap extends IRecordKeyValue<TMap, TKey, TValue>> = {
        map: TMap
    }

    type PickKey<T extends Record<any,any>, TKey extends any> = (T[TKey] extends Array<any> ? T[TKey] : [T[TKey]]) & Array<never>

    type EventEmitterDConfig = EventEmitterConfig<string | symbol, any, any>


    interface TDEventEmitter<TConfig extends EventEmitterConfig<any, any, TConfig['map']> = EventEmitterDConfig,
        TMap = TConfig['map'],
        TCacheEventKinds = keyof TMap
    > {
        
        on<TKey extends TCacheEventKinds, T extends Array<any> = PickKey<TMap, TKey>>(event: TKey, 
            listener: (...args: T) => void): this;

        emit<TKey extends TCacheEventKinds, T extends Array<any> = PickKey<TMap, TKey>>(event: TKey, ...args: T): boolean;
    }
   
    type RecordToDiscriminateKindCache<TKindType extends string | symbol | number, TKindName extends TKindType, T extends IRecordKeyRecord<T, TKindType>> = {
        [K in keyof T] : (T[K] & Record<TKindName, K>)
    }

    type DiscriminateKindFromCache<T extends IRecordKeyRecord<T, any>> = T[keyof T]
```

Example of usages:

```
    
    interface EventA {
        KindT:'KindTA'
        EventA: 'EventA'
    }

    interface EventB {
        KindT:'KindTB'
        EventB: 'EventB'
    }

    interface EventC {
        KindT:'KindTC'
        EventC: 'EventC'
    }

    type EventArgs = [number, string]

    type Items = {
        KindTA : EventA,
        KindTB : EventB,
        KindTC : EventC
        //0 : EventArgs,
    }

    type DiscriminatorKindTypeUnionCache = RecordToDiscriminateKindCache<string 
    //| number,
    "KindGen", Items>;

    type CachedItemForSpeed = DiscriminatorKindTypeUnionCache['KindTB']

    type DiscriminatorKindTypeUnion = DiscriminateKindFromCache<DiscriminatorKindTypeUnionCache>;

    function example() {
        
        const test: DiscriminatorKindTypeUnion;
        switch(test.KindGen) {
            case 'KindTA':
                test.EventA
                break;
            case 'KindTB':
                test.EventB
                break;
            case 'KindTC':
                test.EventC

            case 0:
                test.toLocaleString

        }
    }


    type EmitterConfig = EventEmitterConfig<string 
    //| number
    , any, Items>;

    const EmitterInstance :TDEventEmitter<EmitterConfig>;

    EmitterInstance.on("KindTB",(a, b) => {
        
        a.

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

As for choosing one over the other, I believe it is best said in the second edition of the TypeScript Handbook:

> For the most part, you can choose based on personal preference, and TypeScript will tell you if it needs something to be the other kind of declaration. If you would like a heuristic, use interface until you need to use features from type.

You can read the whole comparison between `type` and `interface` in the [Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) (part of the official TypeScript documentation).

At the time of writing this answer, the version of TypeScript is `5.1`

Answer (score 1):

tldr; use interfaces for "classes", use types for most other things.

**types better capture the dynamic nature of most JavaScript code**

For the most part, the type better support most of the constructs that you can meet in JavaScript.

As an example, I'll use [fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock), which can be used to test code making fetch requests. The library is quite flexible in how you can setup your expectations.

```js
fetchMock.get("http://example.com", response);
fetchMock.get(/\/users/, response);
fetchMock.get({ url: "http://example.com", query: { q: 'foo' } }, response);
fetchMock.mock({ method: 'get', url: "..." }, response);
```

This list of examples is far from complete.

The union types (which don't work with interfaces) is perfect for describing this type of input.

```js
get(matcher: string | RegExp | { method?:'get', url?: string, query?: {} })
mock(matcher: string | RegExp | { method: 'get'|'put'|'post', ...})
```

**interfaces work well with code that is intended for monkey patching**

I am currently writing a medium article about this, and in the process I read a lot of what others write (which brought me to this SO question also).

Some are really good at describing the syntax, and how declaration merging works. But I find that most fail to explain *why* this is not just a good idea; it is essential for TypeScript to be useful at all.

The thing is, in JavaScript, "classes" can be monkey patched, i.e. you can add new functions, or modify existing functions at runtime.

I will use [chai](https://www.chaijs.com/) as an example.

Chai is an assertion library for unit testing, and it allows you to write fluent assertion code like this:

```js
test('user', () => {
  const actual = getUser();
  actual.should.deep.equal({
    firstName: "John,
    lastName: "Doe"
  })
})
```

Chai makes this possible is by actually modifying the native JavaScript `Object` prototype. Since everything inherits from `Object`, the syntax works for *all* values (except `null` and `undefined`)

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'should', { ... })
```

The TypeScript definition of `interface Object` can be found in `/lib/lib.es5.d.ts` in the typescript npm module. It looks like this:

```js
interface Object {
    /** The initial value of Object.prototype.constructor is the standard built-in Object constructor. */
    constructor: Function;

    /** Returns a string representation of an object. */
    toString(): string;

    /** Returns a date converted to a string using the current locale. */
    toLocaleString(): string;

    ...
}
```

So now, TypeScript knows that everything, which is not `null` or `undefined` will have a `toString()` function.

But TypeScript doesn't know about the new property from chai, so the example above would generate a TypeScript compiler error.

As this is not an uncommon JavaScript practice, TypeScript would be useless if this type of code could not be properly supported. And that's why the declaration merging of interfaces is crucial to making TypeScript useful.

Since chai itself is not written in TypeScript, the support is added by the `@types/chai` library, the relevant code is in `index.d.ts` and looks like this:

```js
interface Object {
    should: Chai.Assertion;
}
```

Once you have added that module, the TypeScript compiler will know that `should` is *also* a valid property on every object.

Chai itself has a plug-in architecture, that allows you to add new types of assertions. For example, [sinon-chai](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/sinon-chai-es/) adds assertions for spys, stubs, or mocks created with [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/)

```
const spy = sinon.spy();
spy(42);
spy.should.have.been.calledOnceWith(42)
```

This is possible to describe because the `Chai.Assertion` from before is defined as an interface, not a type alias. And the typescript definitions for `sinon-chai` adds to that specific interface.

So if you have classes, they could potentially be monkey patched, you should use an interface to describe them.

If you write the class in TypeScript you actually get the interface out of the box:

```
class Foo {}
```

This creates both a value `Foo` and an `interface Foo`, and other libraries extending your code, can add to the `interface Foo`.

So mostly don't have to define interfaces explicitly for your TypeScript code. They *can* help if you want to have multiple classes conform to a common interface.

When creating or maintaining TypeScript definitions for pure JavaScript modules, interfaces should probably be used for everything that is a class in the original module; particularly examples like chai, where the modules are designed to be extended through plug-ins.

**NOTE**: I would just add that the interface that is created for your class automatically is an interface of the public members of the class. It tells nothing of inheritance, which can surprise people with a Java/C# background.

```js
class Foo {
  print() { console.log("foo") }
}
function printFoo(foo: Foo) {
  foo.print();
}
// Valid of course,
printFoo(new Foo());
// Also valid - which might be surprising.
printFoo({ print: () => {} });
```

**NOTE**: Also, as a `class` in TypeScript create both a value and an interface type, you can both "extend" and "implement" the class name.

```js
class Foo {
  print()
}
// extends is a JavaScript construct. This defines an inheritance
// relationship. Here it's the _value_ Foo, that is referred to
class A extends Foo {}

// implements is a TypeScript, not JavaScript, construct. This refers
// to the _interface_ Foo. 
class B implements Foo {
  print() {} // Necessary to correctly implement Foo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the discussions I've seen or engaged recently the main difference between types and interfaces is that interfaces can be extended and types can't.

Also if you declare a interface twice they will be merged into a single interface. You can't do it with types.

Answer (score 0):

I’d like to clarify it is **not just a personal choice** between `interface` and `type` when defining an object type in TS. They *differ* in the underlying mechanism of **how TS evaluate them**.

Previous answers have already pointed out the difference in semantics between `interface` and `type`, like `interface` can use declaration merging, while `type` can not. But the real difference is that `interface` is a real type definition, while `type` is just an *alias* of a type. When TS evaluate them, `interface` is **lazy**, it will only be expanded when necessary, while `type` is **eager**, it will be expanded immediately.

Let’s see an example:

```js
type Boxed<T> = { value: T };

type BoxedString = Boxed<BoxedString> | string;
```

If you paste the above code to TS playground, you will get an error, and type of `BoxedString` will be `any`:

```js
type BoxedString = Boxed<BoxedString> | string;
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type alias 'BoxedString' circularly references itself.(2456)
```

Why? Doesn’t TS support recursive type definition? No, it does. It is common to define a tree-like structure in TS:

```js
type TreeNode<T> = {
    value: T;
    left: TreeNode<T>;
    right: TreeNode<T>;
};
```

You can define the `TreeNode` type without any problem, either using `type` or `interface`. The problem originates from the **eager** evaluation of `type`. If we replace `type` with `interface` in the above example, it will work:

```js
interface Boxed<T> {
  value: T;
}

type BoxedString = Boxed<BoxedString> | string;
```

Or just use an object literal type without defining a `Boxed` type:

```js
type BoxedString = { value: BoxedString } | string;
```

Why? According to my experience, object literal types and types defined using `interface` are **lazy**, that is, they will not be expanded until they are used. Let’s try to expand the original `BoxedString` type manually:

```js
type BoxedString = Boxed<BoxedString> | string;
// TS find `Boxed` is a type alias, so it will expand `Boxed<BoxedString>` immediately
// to expand it, it should first expand `BoxedString` inside `Boxed<BoxedString>`
// To expand `BoxedString`, it should first expand `Boxed<BoxedString>` immediately
// ... Never ending
```

However, when `Boxed` is defined by `interface`, TS will not try to expand `Boxed<BoxedString>` immediately, it will wait until `BoxedString` is used. The same thing happens when using object literal types.

So, what’s the difference between `interface` and `type`? `interface` is a real type definition, while `type` is just an alias of a type. When TS evaluate them, `interface` is **lazy**, it will only be expanded when necessary, while `type` is **eager**, it will be expanded immediately.

It is not rare to use recursive type definition in TS – especially for library authors. My advice is to always use `interface` when defining an object type, it also enables declaration merging, which is very useful when you’re writing a library and later someone wants to write an extension for it.

Answer (score -1):

**Interface** was designed specifically to describe object shapes; however **Types** are somehow like interfaces that can be used to create new name for any type.

We might say that an **Interface** can be extended by declaring it more than one time; while types are closed.

https://itnext.io/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript-cf5758211910