# How to make interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

For example I have this class property:

```
public messages : Array<{session: string, messages: [{profile_picture ? : string, type: string, text: string}]}> = []
```

I want to make something like this `public messages : MessagesInterface` in order to be able to use that interface in different places.

I know that is should like something like this:

```
export interface MessagesInterface {
    session: string, 
    messages: [{profile_picture ? : string, type: string, text: string}]
}
```

But how to specify that it is array of messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options. You can specify an indexable interface as:

```
export interface MessagesInterface {
    [key:number]: {
        session: string, 
        messages: [{profile_picture ? : string, type: string, text: string}]
    }
}
```

Or instead export a type

```
export type MessagesInterface = {
    session: string, 
    messages: [{profile_picture ? : string, type: string, text: string}]
}[]
```

I'd still encourage breaking it into multiple interfaces to help readability whichever path you choose.

Comment: No. The whole `MessagesInterface` is array which consists of objects which includes `session` and `messages`

Comment: What difference is between type and interface?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types

Comment: In this specific case, the type will carry the other array functions (.length and such) while the interface will not. The interface is purely indexable, the type is an actual array. You could make the interface extend Array<T> if you wanted to achieve both.