# typed react - props as `type` or an `interface`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, flowtype

I have react code

`export default class MyComponent extends Component<Props,State>`

The question is, do I write props like a `type` or an `interface`?

```
type Props = {
    isActive: Boolean,
    onClick: Function
}
```

or

```
interface Props {
    isActive: Boolean,
    onClick: Function
}
```

also, what is the direrence, when I am not using typescript, but classic webpack+babel setup?

Or, does it even matter much to mee?

Answer (score 40):

It is 2020 now and I would favor `type` in almost all cases with `React` props (general type vs interface post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types)). Common cases that can be only expressed with type aliases:

```
// given some props from another comp that are to be altered
type ExternalProps = { a: string; b: { c: number } };

type Props_IndexType = ExternalProps["b"]; // { c: number; }
type Props_MappedType = { [K in keyof ExternalProps]: number }; // { a: number; b: number; }
type Props_DiscriminatedUnionType = { tag: "tag1"; foo: string } | { tag: "tag2"; foo: boolean}
type Props_typeOf = { foo: string } & typeof defaultProps; // see class comp example

// conditional types - ok, this one is a bit contrived, but you get the point
type Props_ConditionalType<T> = T extends true ? { a: string } : { b: number };
const Comp = <T extends {}>(props: Props_ConditionalType<T>) =>
  <div>{"a" in props && (props as any).a}</div>
render(<Comp<true> a="foo" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Class component [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=40&ssc=71&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKFEljgG84iA7AEySjgF85tcCi6GAFpWuMlSoB6KXADmwAG5JmcAM64kcMDjBreOPCmYQYACw5w0uMHHMp4KInYhwARlpQAbGBySsqGABPMC0AUQAPXyhmbwAFXX0AXgY4FAAudRgoYGY5UndMxjRM5gBXEA9OHi4KSkCQrQSIPQB9AEk2JAiAFUa4FMjo2K9mvQBtfDd8AF0CmVSSuHLKjgKuBtC4MbVWgFkUMFDWPq2UxnGAaThcuABrJCCITDghjhGdmdKKqu552UYGWWPzWhWBqyg602TUSrQAIsA1GgciBcg5-ABVZjACDMU5ac52FByTL4GDEgCMZF4EAgmTU2Vycm4cAAPqlySSCJyAEzUzC0zJuWleVCqWrQ7aw4KhADyL0JArpWRyeRZADI7I1nnB2JgUGUfDt-uokFo0F4UGp9NZwHBuihwKLdRAAO6qMpdKCSSgLaxsYAwHEjLWhfTCOAQO4AGjsZkRkeYWgTKHcgasuMZylYsbcZXgTzK8iQ8HMWkguRgkp2rQAwrjWIHg958QAeHoAPgGcB69qiKlY%20myZS0AH5UkCGarmTwimCVr8JZR-Qy4PW7Sl233fGx9PQuB2ABQ6FpqTI1%20sBoO4luNdsdgCUAw7VDgcFbjcUHfo%20BQ%20BuqgnnocDqpqx6JGk%20jGEED4AHQoFwrZSJ%20L6UCw7BQIerbrmArbDkgXYoEk%20BKv%20UgdrGYhoBUKgwLBcglmEoogLRABCQTtKwh6ELSMD4A%20D51NIshoMYJjwGIcYOHArqBmYAHRPqaBIGo1YQSkh6MJypKclSBRKvSjJqjw7JacSOnEny%20mCu4IpitwT7qq%20oZIDqeoGkaiR1DKWgAMrkr43Y%20TquSBv56JCcuuKru5howDs3aAqSACC-5Liu8ChTA4WBYSSz4LWaWRRaVr6MlRzbgO%20jIEIsE4bitGtjssY5QRDDOQyDjAGgTCoGIzBeEEupIPqcUJSksWeaedRvp1uUAWFAVIJFb7oRwh5PvQzmrSWZQxHAh7bW%2074oUdx3vmAHY7EUABSvmygAcrBU5MsAmBBIe5iIrBQFqLG5ReF4sY8g%20iFSJdZ3Ha2l2tbd91PS9eRvR9X1qM9S3-YaQNwCDYMQ5Q51vkhp0E8dgnORslCU1Qa2Ya25W2JyxG6f%20SrEaRcDkZREDUSxzB0QxMBMUgfMwOxnHcTgpj8eTlBAA) for illustration (OP mentions them, but above cases also apply for Hooks):

```
// cannot do that with interfaces
type Props = ({ tag: "tag1"; foo: string } | { tag: "tag2"; foo: boolean }) &
  typeof defaultProps;
type State = typeof initState;

const defaultProps = { a: "A" };
const initState = { c: "C" };

class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  static readonly defaultProps = defaultProps;
  state = initState;

  render() { ... }
}

render(<App tag="tag1" foo="foo" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The only cases, I would consider interfaces:

- You do [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) of prop types in the global scope (uncommon nowadays)
- You want to hide type implementation details, as interfaces create a new name used in error messaged, IDE type infos etc. ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases))

Comment: Considering the following quote from [TypeScript Performance Github wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance) -> "extending types with interfaces/extends is suggested over creating intersection types", do you still favor `type` over `interface`?

Answer (score 17):

Interfaces are a little more powerful than the corresponding type declaration, but for a set of react props, it likely doesn't matter.
You can read about the differences between types and interfaces [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types).

Since you're unlikely to be extending that interface or augmenting it elsewhere, using either is probably fine. But I would say that an interface is generally preferred for defining object types since they're a little more flexible.

Comment: this answer could be outdated. And as for the "more powerful" part, the opposite could easily be argued as well. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types#comment96004001_52682220 . There are also more discussions around the internet as for whether interfaces are really "better".

Comment: @ZenVentzi if it was outdated before, it might be preferred again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72598769/intersection-types-vs-interfaces-in-typescript . If the reasoning behind being "better" is to allow more flexibility when defining complex/union types, then some might see that as defeating the purpose of using TypeScript in the first place. All comes down to preference. Here's some pros for Interface: (1) define, more specifically, the shape of objects and their contracts, (2) has declaration merging, (3) can be implemented by classes, and (4) just looks syntactically prettier (imo)