# Should we use type or interface for defining properties for Functional Typescript React Component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

When using React Functional components with Typescript we need to define properties interface/type. Which one is the preferred solution type or interface and why?

> "React.FC makes sure the signature of our function is correct and the return value is valid JSX. Furthermore due to TypeScript generics, we can pass the type of our props either inline or by supplying an interface/type."

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-react-functional-components-with-hooks-in-typescript-6d61075edddc

Comment: And applied to React: [typed react - props as `type` or an `interface`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49562569/1218980)

Comment: Ultimately it doesn't really matter.  I use the same mental rules that I apply to any type, which is to use `interface` when dealing with all known properties and to use `type` when there is something that would require it, like a union or a conditional.