# How to create a literal value for a type?

Tags: typescript

Continuing from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51132333/936293, why does the following not work?

```
type MemberModel = mongoose.Document & {
  familyName: string,
  otherNames: string,
  email: string
}

function f(m: MemberModel):void { }

f1( { email: "abc@gmail.com" });
```

The last line results in a compiler error:

> Argument of type '{ email: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MemberModel'.  Type '{ email: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Document'.
>    Property 'increment' is missing in type '{ email: string; }'.

Doesn't `{ email: "abc@gmail.com" }` conform to the shape specified by the type `MemberModel`?

In this situation, how do I pass a suitable literal to `f`? (At this time I want to avoid changing `MemberModel` to a class yet as I inherited this code from a template.)

Comment: Why *would* that be a valid `MemberModel`? It doesn't even have all of the props you define inline in the type, let alone whatever `mongoose.Document` requires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is no the object literal does not conform to that type. It does not conform as the object literal  only has the `email` field. The type needs to satisfy both `mongoose.Document` which has a lot of methods (including `increment` which is the error you are getting) and also all the fields you specify are required, so even we take into account just that part it still would not work as it has the fields `familyName` and `otherNames` missing.

You could take in a `Partial<T>` of this type which allows us to specify any subset of the fields of the type:

```
type MemberModel = mongoose.Document & {
    familyName: string,
    otherNames: string,
    email: string
}

function f(m: Partial<MemberModel>): void { }

f({ email: "abc@gmail.com" });
```

The more correct approach though might be to read-up on how `mongoose` defines schemas and classes [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) for example. You are probably looking for something like :

```
type MemberModel = mongoose.Document & {
    familyName: string,
    otherNames: string,
    email: string
}
var memberModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    familyName: String,
    otherNames: String,
    email: String
});

var MemberModel = mongoose.model<MemberModel>('MemberModel', memberModelSchema);
function f(m: MemberModel): void { }

f(new MemberModel({ email: "abc@gmail.com" }));
```