# How to extend interface from annonymous class

Tags: typescript

Assume I have annonymous class:

```
const AnonymousClass = class {}
let a: typeof AnonymousClass;
```

How to extend interface from it?
Compiler fails on this:

```
interface I extends typeof AnonymousClass {

}
```

Playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20AnonymousClass%20%3D%20class%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%3A%20typeof%20AnonymousClass%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20I%20extends%20typeof%20AnonymousClass%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an expression in an `extends` or `implements` clause but you can create a type alias and use it instead. You can even use the same name as the anonymous class `const` as they are in different spaces ([value space vs type space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131898/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-class-in-typescript/51132333?s=1|28.2223#51132333))

```
const AnonymousClass = class {
    static staticField = 0;
    instanceField = 0;
}

let a: typeof AnonymousClass;
type AnonymousClass = typeof AnonymousClass
interface I extends AnonymousClass {

}
let foo: I;
foo.instanceField // invalid
foo.staticField // valid
```

The code above extends the static interface of the class, you probably want to extend the instance interface of the class, which you can do with an extra `InstanceType` conditional type:

```
const AnonymousClass = class {
    static staticField = 0;
    instanceField = 0;
}

let a: typeof AnonymousClass;
type AnonymousClass = InstanceType<typeof AnonymousClass>
interface I extends AnonymousClass {

}

let foo: I;
foo.instanceField // valid
foo.staticField // invalid
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20AnonymousClass%20%3D%20class%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20staticField%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20instanceField%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%3A%20typeof%20AnonymousClass%3B%0D%0Atype%20AnonymousClass%20%3D%20%20InstanceType%3Ctypeof%20AnonymousClass%3E%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20I%20extends%20AnonymousClass%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%3A%20I%3B%0D%0Afoo.staticField%20%2F%2F%20invalid%0D%0Afoo.instanceField%20%2F%2F%20valid%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AnonymousClassStatics%20%3D%20typeof%20AnonymousClass%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20IS%20extends%20AnonymousClassStatics%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20fooS%3A%20IS%3B%0D%0AfooS.staticField%20%2F%2F%20valid%0D%0AfooS.instanceField%20%2F%2F%20invalid)