# What type has the `class` created by a `function`?

Tags: typescript, decorator, code-splitting, first-class

**The goal is** to do a code splitting in my TypeScript code.

I use (experimental) decorators to support ORM-like data mapping from models to persistent storage.
One of types needs to have a decorator parameterized with a name of a table which will store the entities of that type.
In order to do a code splitting I have extracted domain model to a separate file (`entity-model.ts`):

```
/* I am using dynamodb-data-mapper */
import { 
  table,
  hashKey,
  attribute
} from '@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper-annotations'

export class Entity {
  /* attributes */
}

/* this entity is parameterized with name of the table
   where data will be stored */
export function entityGroupClassFactory(tableName: string)/*: ???*/ {
  @table(tableName)
  class EntityGroup {
    @hashKey()
    id: string,

    @attribute({ memberType: embed(Entity) })
    children: Entity[]

  }
  return Entity
}
```

When I use this file in the following way:

```
import { entityGroupClassFactory, Entity } from './entity-model.ts'
import { DataMapper } from '@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper';

const mapper : DataMapper = createDataMapper()
const tableName : string = deterineTableName()

const EntityGroup = entityGroupClassFactory(tableName)

/* eventually I do */

let entityGroup = mapper.get(/*...*/)

/* and at some point I am trying to do this: */

function handleEntityGroup(entityGroup: EntityGroup) {
  /* ... */
}

/* or this: */

async function fetchEntityGroup(): Promise<EntityGroup> {
  const entityGroup = /* ... */
  return entityGroup
}
```

For the both functions (`handleEntityGroup` and `fetchEntityGroup`) TypeScript reports the following error:

`[ts] Cannot find name 'EntityGroup'. [2304]`

I am not sure about the correctness of such approach and I will look for other options to do the code splitting. But as a beginner in this area I would like to get answer to question: **what is `EntityGroup` in this example code?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a class, you get both a value (representing the class constructor) and a type (representing the instance type of the class) with the class name.

When you are using a function to return a class, and putting it in the `const` you are basically only getting the value, the instance type has no reason to be created.

Fortunately you can use `InstanceType<typeof EntityGroup>` to get the instance type associated with the constructor `EntityGroup`.

```
const EntityGroup = entityGroupClassFactory(tableName)
type EntityGroup = InstanceType<typeof EntityGroup>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for such a quick answer! I am just trying to understand now, whether it is possible to merge these two things (constructor and instance type) together. I will read through advanced types documentation, thanks a lot for pointing to this feature of TS.

Comment: I definitely will! but I would like to understand the answer better before. May I ask you to clarify "const" part. Will there be any difference if I put it into variable instead of a constant?

Comment: @Alexander no that does not matter. Maybe this will help with understanding values VS types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131898/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-class-in-typescript/51132333#51132333