# How do you export an interface from a namespace?

Tags: typescript

How do you export an interface from a namespace in typescript?  Is this limited to declaration files?  Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

```
namespace Foo {
  export interface Bar {}
  export class Baz {}
}

export const { Baz } = Foo; // Works just fine
export const { Bar } = Foo; // Type 'typeof Foo' has no property 'Bar' and no string index signature.
```

Typescript 3.3.1

It's worth noting, the official documentation has this as a use case so I was very confused when I saw it wasn't working: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

**Update (thanks Titian):**

My main objective was to export this type, I solved this using Titian's advice:

```
namespace Foo {
    export interface Bar {}
    export class Baz {}
}

export const type Bar = Foo.Bar // now exportable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the interface in a location where a value is expected. Classes are both types and  value (see [values vs types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131898/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-class-in-typescript/51132333#51132333)) that is why it works.

If you use the interface in a type annotation it will work as expected:

```
namespace Foo {
    export interface Bar {}
    export class Baz {}
}

Foo.Baz // Works just fine
let bar : Foo.Bar // ok
```