# Using a class expression/value as a type

Tags: typescript

If I declare a class in usual way, I can use the class name as a type:

```
class Foo {
  foo: number
  constructor(x: number) {
    this.foo = x
  }
}
let foo : Foo // all fine
```

But if I declare a class by assigning a class expression to a variable, I can't use that name as a type:

```
const Bar = class Bar {
  bar: string
  constructor(x: string) {
    this.bar = x
  }
}
let b: Bar // 'Bar' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Bar'?
```

Using `typeof Bar` as suggested does not work, since I want the type of instances of `Bar`, rather than of the class itself.

[typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oDNEC5oDsBXAWwCMBTAJ3WmHnwgBdLDhH5KAKADzyLKoBKFDQyMAFgEsIAOmxIAvNG40AvqnWo6DRtABCYStCWhIMA0bQZShvE0qT8Acxrb7rdl17R7jp8KsMaAlpGRsjJRUMdU0Qcl0waDwERQJyAHc4RE4AFgAmQVQ43VIk-UNjNMyLTgAicXIQEHha4QB6NuhxeEyAEyQASVoOSnI2EABPaF6x8FHghuCJgAdyaHhMaFIAflRUTEJ8Nkl6aGWHfEYANTAQQnIUznlkxGE8ADd4SV6RDDd4OIyZpOJ6IOSvDR7A5HRgnfBnC7XW73GrhMoWALQDrQdLiMC6aQLNZ0SijNhLVbTWaGfFwrpUci7P70CAA8hA+Ag8JhQyFTSoc6OJF3B7ZMCFQWXG4i1GCIA)

How do I get the type of instances of a class which has been defined using in the second way?

#### Rationale

The reason I'm interested in defining a class in this way is that I want to have an interface describing the static methods certain classes will have, as described [in the handbook here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes) (the third example in that section).

[Here's that example with a single line added showing the problem again](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/PTAEAEGcBcCcEsDG0AKsD2AHApraBPASQDt5p4BDAG3gC8Lz1iAuUAM2smwCgQJj0hALaYaiMgEFi+Vhypdu8YtFwdE2UAGEq6RAGtNTGLACuydLFABvbqFDFsAd1AAKABboTsVsRNCARrgANKBCSiYqPn6BsACUrNq6eiQqsGrYANzcAL7cisqqFOpaOvophcU2duT6LvGgAG7o8AAmWbnciEbQJUkJpQbdpuaWALygiFQUkJC9+qDwIlTYQtjKs4llBWlFGlUTQ2bQFu5RAcGhZzGx1rnVSHp11rZ2B8SQ6MsAdDoA5i4AIkC2EwoGBmABsSydly2Sy3GWPUQoH6SVA4wczk2jwAzEEAEwABliQA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typescript has two name spaces, a  value space and a type space (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51132333/125734)). A class declaration adds a name in both value space and type space in the context where it is declared. A class expression, only adds these in the class scope. So you can use `BarExpression` as both the constructor and the type inside the class.

```
const Bar = class BarExpression {
  bar: BarExpression // Valid in the class
  constructor(x: BarExpression) { 
    this.bar = x
  }
}
```

In the enclosing scope, you are only left with the `const` named `Bar` that you can use as the constructor, but the type in not added to the enclosing scope ( const declaration has no reason to add a type to the enclosing scope).

You can get the instance type of a constructor using the `InstanceType` conditional type. And you can also add a type alias declaration, in order so get a similar effect to a class declaration:

```
const Bar = class Bar {
  bar: string
  constructor(x: string) {
    this.bar = x
  }
}
type Bar = InstanceType<typeof Bar>
let a : Foo = new Foo(42)
let b : Bar = new Bar("hello")
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oDNEC5oDsBXAWwCMBTAJ3WmHnwgBdLDhH5KAKADzyLKoBKFDQyMAFgEsIAOmxIAvNG40AvqnWo6DRtABCYStCWhIMA0bQZShvE0qT8Acxrb7rdl17R7jp8KsMaAlpGRsjJRUMdXVGAE8AB3J9Q2NoAEkdMHxgcgAVRPIAHnik+EwUygA+VBByXTBoPARFAnIAdzhETgAWACZBWvroUibKtPwOys4AInFyEBB4GeEAelXocXhOgBMkdNoOSnI2EDjoHZPwY+D54MLocpGAflRUTEIcxkl6aASHfCMABqYBAhHILU48maiGEeAAbvBJDsRBg3PA6jIlk4oYg5LCNG8Pl8fvg-gDgaDwRZOOExhYAtB1tB2uIwLppLdknRKMc2PckhcroZ2aTNlRyK80fQIBjyFj4DjwmFDINNKh-o5KWCId0wINNYCQTqaaRBEA)

Comment: Thanks! I was just trying more things myself before looking back here and `type Bar = typeof Bar.prototype` seemed to work fine. Is that equivalent to using `InstanceType<typeof Bar>`?

Comment: `InstanceType` - brilliant - that's what I was looking for, thanks!