# Getting an enum from a string in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I have an enum in typescript which has 20+ fields. I have  UI application where user can put information in some freetext (for example let's say the color the person likes). My requirement is to take this color information and call the midtier service. The midtier service has Color defined as Enum which is kept in sync with UI enum definition. I need to convert the user input text to enum (in front end side) as there are compilation issues being thrown during build. I am not finding a way to perform the conversion (for example from the user input string to a specific enum element). Any pointers will be helpful.

Here is the sample code

```
       export enum Color {
          green='green',
          orange='orange',
          yellow = 'yellow'
...... 
and so on
       }
```

User gives the input as green (which is a string). When I am calling the service on midtier, it expects an enum.

Regards

Comment: `yourEnum[ thatString ]` ? Hard to tell without a [mre]

Comment: just provided the code sample.. please let me know if you need any other details

Comment: So your service expects one of ~20 defined colors, but your user can input any text as a value. Ain't that a conflict? What prevents the user from entering something that ain't a value in your enum?

Comment: Actually we have identified this design issue but as of now our UX designer is working on it. However in order to support existing application, I am working on some enhancement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript supports [reverse enum mapping](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-enum). So `Color[1] === 'Green'`, and `Color['green'] === 1`.

That being said, your UI is likely running TS exported to JS, and this enum does not exist in [value-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131898/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-class-in-typescript#:%7E:text=4%20Answers&text=Typescript%20has%20two%20different%20universes,will%20obviously%20exist%20at%20runtime.). If that assumption is correct, you are better off exporting the enum to an object to be mapped in a more vannilla-js way

Comment: thanks.. let me check this. Actually I am  more of a server side developer and not fully familiar with these concepts