# force only instance of class to be passed

Tags: typescript

```
class Foo {
    foo = '';
}

class Bar {
    bar = 0;
}

function getNumber(value: Foo | Bar): number {
    if (value instanceof Bar) {
        return value.bar;
    } else {
        return value.foo.length;
    }
}

console.log(getNumber({bar: 1}));
```

here is the example in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQGaOgXmgHJCBuVAX1VVEhgCEwAnFdTAIyf2gAYzLUsAVwB2wAC4BLeMOgBzAKZiAcoIC2beYwAUANzAhB8gFxxcAH2gNGAShPC1G5mkzQJWaLv2HXwiGLCi8vDuVtYsLi6MioKMMnoG8gB0HIxkLuTQ8iAQ8uERGFFiMXFeSTjwiSDywrJiABZpmJT8wNIQ8FWV8LJaCsoOmlrIKSYAjOTW1mRAA)

this code will throw an error in runtime, but will compile without a problem

is there a way to force that instance of the class to be passed not any object matching it?

edit:

I mean to force users to use it like that

```
const bar = new Bar();
bar.bar = 1;
console.log(getNumber(bar));
```

but calling it with `getNumber({bar: 1});` to throw an error saying something like: value is expected to be an instance of Class Bar or instance of class Foo, a generic object was sent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between type and class in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131898/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-class-in-typescript)

Comment: @STh no, updated the question to clarify what I want

Comment: I'm afraid you can't because TypeScript uses a [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system). I checked out the [`InstanceType` utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#constructor-signatures) but it doesn't work in your example. Probably you need to check your type at runtime or use a type guard, since the prototype cannot be determined at runtime (even if in your example it looks like it can)