# Maintain type safety while expressing, "This object literal's values are all of type T."

Tags: typescript

Here is an example in which `T` is `StringConstant`.

```
type StringConstant =
    'fooValue' |
    'barValue' |
    'bazValue';
```

#### Attempt 01

We have tried casting each property in an object literal `as StringConstant`. The downside is that this approach does not type check the property values.

```
const StringConstant01 = {
    foo: 'fooValue' as StringConstant,
    bar: 'barValue' as StringConstant,
    baz: 'bazValue!!!' as StringConstant, // no error, bad
}
```

Though it does work with assignment to a constant of type `T` and catches errors when we use the wrong property key.

```
const x: StringConstant = StringConstant01.bar;
const y: StringConstant = StringConstant01.qux; // error, good
```

#### Attempt 02

We have tried using an index type.

```
type StringConstantMap = {
    [key: string]: StringConstant;
}

const StringConstant02: StringConstantMap = {
    foo: 'fooValue',
    bar: 'barValue',
    baz: 'bazValue!!!' // error, good
}
```

The downside is that we lose type info on the property keys.

```
const x: StringConstant = StringConstant02.bar;
const y: StringConstant = StringConstant02.qux; // no error, bad
```

Comment: I'm probably missing something. :-) If you need the property names checked, what's wrong with `interface Whatever { foo: StringConstant, bar: StringConstant };`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that other than it not having occurred to me. I think was I was getting caught up in advanced types. It's also more repetition of property names that I would have liked.

Comment: LOL - Sorry, I genuinely thought I was failing to get the point. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an interface:

```
interface IStringConstants {
    foo: StringConstant;
    bar: StringConstant;
    baz: StringConstant;
}

const StringConstant01: IStringConstants = {
    foo: 'fooValue',
    bar: 'barValue'
    baz: 'bazValue!!!' // error
}
```

What you can't prevent is that `'bazValue!!!' as StringConstant` will not result in a compiler error.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, a type would be an additional alternative to an interface. `type StringConstantMap = { foo: StringConstant; bar: StringConstant; baz: StringConstant; }`.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: That's correct. For the trade-offs / differences, see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37233777/572644