# Typescript assigning an interface or a type to a Record<string, string>

Tags: typescript

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types) or [this article](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases), I'm still a bit confused about the subtle differences between an `interface` and a `type`.

In this example, my goal is to assign a simple object to a broader `Record<string, string>` type:

```js
interface MyInterface {
  foobar: string;
}

type MyType = {
  foobar: string;
}

const exampleInterface: MyInterface = { foobar: 'hello world' };
const exampleType: MyType = { foobar: 'hello world' };

let record: Record<string, string> = {};

record = exampleType;      // Compiles
record = exampleInterface; // Index signature is missing
```

[Try it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwFgAoZZGAe0oCM4oAuZAZzClAHMBuUgX1NJh0ABxQYAKiJQBeQqXJVa9Jq3YhufASQSUQrZBAAecALbCANhGyRYiCEwzXcd5LIIVqdRsgDkACwhzc0pkAHdKKHMAEx9kXh5tXX0jUwsISVEHdAyZQg8lb39A4LCI6Nj4rUswZCgIHSgopgAleoiogB5VTgAaFjZOAD5XQkqSUjqGqJGUs0scrnIl5AB6FeQAYUozYEtmCbbGmeM5qxxbJEW15GwooxZgDhA4MABXOuRgZmQTL%20ZOUhAA)

The assignment is possible when declaring my object with a `type`, but not when declaring a similar one with an `interface`. It says that the index signature is missing, but to my (limited) understanding of index signatures, none of `MyType` and `MyInterface` actually have one.

What is the reason why the last line does not compile whereas the previous one does?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realise it but it *does* make sense. The type `{ foobar: string }` is a *lower bound* for what you can receive. It basically means "any object which has *at least* a key `foobar`". Apparently making into a type preserves that meaning. However, for an *interface* the semantics are different and it might not have any other keys. It's a bit weird since both variables will not accept a new key called `hello` to be added. So they differ in assignability.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Record<string, string>` is the same as `{ [key: string]: string }`. A subset is allowed to be assigned to this *index signature type* is only possible if all properties of that type are known and can be checked against this index signature. In your case, everything from `exampleType` is assignable to `Record<string, string>`. This can be only checked for object literal types, as object literal types can't be changed once you declared them. Thus, the index signature is known.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7029

In contrast, interfaces are not final the moment you declare them. There is always the possibility of adding new members to the same interface due to declaration merging.

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around by providing an intermediate type which is compatible to the interface you want to assign:

```
interface MyInterface {
  foobar: string;
}

type MyType = {
  foobar: string;
};

const exampleInterface: MyInterface = { foobar: 'hello world' };
let exampleType: MyType = { foobar: 'hello world' };

let record: Record<string, string> = {};

record = exampleType; // Compiles
// record = exampleInterface; // Index signature is missing

exampleType = exampleInterface; // Index signature is missing
record = exampleType;
```