# Iterating through a compex object to modify all values in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript interface that looks something like this:

```typescript
interface IPageConfig {
    fooSection?: IFooSectionUrlMap;
    barSection?: IBarSectionUrlMap;
    blaSection?: IBlaSectionUrlMap;
}

interface IFooSectionUrlMap {
    oneUrl: string;
    twoUrl: string;
    threeUrl: string;
}

interface IBarSectionUrlMap {
    fourUrl: string;
    fiveUrl: string;
    sixUrl: string;
}

interface IBlaSectionUrlMap{
    sevenUrl: string;
    eightUrl: string;
    nineUrl: string;
}
```

What I'd like to do is go through every URL on the object -- in every property -- and change them from a relative URL to an absolute one by prepending a `/` to each one.

I've tried using `Object.keys.forEach()` and `Object.entries.forEach()` from some articles I ran across, and I've tried using `for...in` loops with defining things as `keyof`.  It always gets through the first level just fine before TS complains.  And it complaines with the same thing:

> The left-hand side of a 'for...in' statement must be of type 'string' or 'any'.ts(2405)

What am I doing wrong here?  Here's the code:

```typescript
function convertToRelativeUrls(config: IPageConfig) {
    let sectionName: keyof IPageConfig;
    for (sectionName in config) {
        if (sectionName.endsWith('Section')) {
            let section = config[sectionName];
            if (section) {

                // If I hover over it, propName has a type of never
                let propName: keyof typeof section;

                // Right here is where TS complains -- propName
                for (propName in section) {
                    if (propName && section && section[propName]) {

                        // When I try setting it, the right-hand side is fine.
                        // The left-hand side says 
                        // "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'"
                        section[propName] = '/' + section[propName];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Typo in my function.  Should be `.endsWith('Section')`, not `.endsWith('UrlMap')`.  I've fixed the original but am leaving it here so the comment calling it out still makes sense.

Comment: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-union-to-intersection/ should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Also https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581 / https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109

Comment: In TypeScript, an `object` is not the right structure for typed iteration by key, because [all objects can have excess properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing) and the compiler is ok with that (because TypeScript is structurally-typed).

Comment: Also (according to the types you've shown), this conditional should always evaluate to `false`: `if (sectionName.endsWith('UrlMap'))` because no properties in that object type end in `UrlMap`.

Comment: This problem is not impossible to solve, but another structure (such as a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)) would be a better candidate for an iterative approach like this. Are you open to using another data structure such as a Map?

Comment: @jsejcksn Good catch on the bug in my code.  In my production code it does end in `UrlMap`.  And thanks for the info!  I'm not sure I can change the data structure here, since so many things we have are dependent on it, but I'll take a look and see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by modifying some aspects of your types and your function.

---

For this approach to work, you'll need to [use type aliases instead of interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces), so that no additional fields can be added to your types after declaration: this informs the compiler that they are not open/mutable.

> In addition to the previous link to the TS handbook, you can see these links for more info: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55814516/438273), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64970414/438273), [3](https://fettblog.eu/tidy-typescript-prefer-type-aliases/)

For each interface, you would rewrite it like this:

```ts
// before
interface IFooSectionUrlMap {
  oneUrl: string;
  twoUrl: string;
  threeUrl: string;
}
```

```ts
// after
type IFooSectionUrlMap = {
  oneUrl: string;
  twoUrl: string;
  threeUrl: string;
};
```

For another approach of deriving your types from data, see [this TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgMwQSwB4QCYB4BCBDAZ2glWAgDsMCoDgAnZcgcwBpZEVUoSzLraGzAHxQAvFAAGAEgDe+IgF9Z8JGgUSA3ACgtCOOQDGwZAHtyUA3Qh4yKzlFyFipClRr1Grdqq49X-D2EACi0oKAAjJwAuKHkIFlCaDjQYuzQEgEpU5PRsOLY01BEZRKtgODpzaRlIxVkCHPVtBR0DM1ooBBMTAGkIEGpxIIBtAHIzCFG2UeAAdxMpqBmACytJgF0oQgt24AyAOgBbPDAggTERS2tbHLP6aYBVOgAbUYyM7TbyDsi6PoGxFARqMuhVFiDkAA3SbTAhoUabbZfWgHY6nc6iS5WGwQQp3OiPF5vD5aZHACLPPD-QZAsZEaHkcEQZBMZbAcHkRgbLbUMmok74i4WbE3Hz4wmvd7aLSgSBQACSADFujAIEZTOQns8ALInQEAJTVJjo2FlEBMCE63Wpw3IcEO4QgdHWbAEniE2jNCvwdFV6rMWt1YANRpNWDNFoieD+-QItvtjudrsCTA9MvA0HlOEpfuMAZeQZDbTDEct4UpNrtDqdLvcglT0q98oACngmBAAMJmFBMQElMJdEy5jUAfhiSpVarzmoLJ20YV+w7MY+90aXM51c8S5bw65XWZzU41ga3Cm0QA).

---

After converting your interfaces to type aliases, you can focus on the function. Instead of using `IPageConfig` as the type of the object parameter, you can use some [type utilities](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) to create a type which `IPageConfig` can be assigned to: `Partial<Record<string, Record<string, string>>>`. This type will allow you to work with the nested objects using `string` keys, and you can use some runtime validation to ensure that you're operating only on the patterns of keys that you want to. Here's what the refactored function looks like:

```ts
function prefixNestedStrings (obj: Partial<Record<string, Record<string, string>>>): void {
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (!key.endsWith('Section')) continue; // key pattern mismatch

    const objChild = obj[key]; // Record<string, string> | undefined
    if (!objChild) continue; // no value

    for (const key in objChild) {
      if (!key.endsWith('Url')) continue; // key pattern mismatch
      const str = objChild[key];
      if (typeof str !== 'string') continue; // type mismatch
      objChild[key] = `/${str}`;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Putting it all together:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgYgewQZQgY2ASwQOwKoBOANgLICGYUAvFAN4BQUUuEhRAXFAM7AGY4BzANyMowAO4I2nHn0EimwABYEIrYjN79h9AL4j6oSLABCZAqgzZ8xcpRoMmAMwQBXAtO5b5op5gBu6hxecjpMXJgAHp6y2iL69Ibg0DAmRGSWWLhsdtR0olwQgTbBsT5MEJgCSsAx3mFQOPxBmqHxBkYpAApkAhAAwrh+AnmOUC4o6Fk4APyc8EiZ1jkUClAARuZLuHOmW1PLtqui6+nbs-NpGQfZR2DtiU6uOFa4UGCqfpEAchA8EAATZD1LhQAAUCHWACtOD0CFgyEQADwAJXQCAIAKRZQEABooGi0BisTj8TiAHyUgCUnH8CEwAPyzgx4KJOB4UAA1hAQFB+MxoVSmUw+U5wQBCbkgAB0EBwAK4AHVMMowQByc5qqlCtlYHCuCBCKAAemNXJ57zIwGAEAIOCgAFtMFwHVa0EpEiKoGyOZCof0lJgiIyaH6ANpSgC6RtNBPRmOx9TJ9XJUAAPlBngCIH4cIDRExMGKweK-QGgwCdbg9QaY2acAgoP5EQbPSKXARWbgOVK+fay4Hg0Kxl6ixKpbL5UqVUp1WwtVWcDXDSazb2wFabXbHc7XcB3QWRT7gCE8gOKxGedHD4Xi50EGLZFBxVQaGqcVrvdX+LXV2JkjuLpuh6XpMOewaXiAkZ5AABsaAAktCyLoMFrEwuiiBhGH0Melp9IMODDPMPT4UMVSjL4iw3DgnAjsweaeGqLBqrih4SFIGhQGq7EsWxKhqIxyiqBAvHoaxTCbBY1G0YeLjuIxckEKJ7YBC0XF+IEynhFEjERJEym6KxCT0B8OZRL8-xAiCYIbqRhFVFSBg+ggRAQNKRAIAINm9AMZECI5f6oNAzmuZwHkIJyoICEgjLAI2DoQPQQA)

```ts
type IFooSectionUrlMap = {
  oneUrl: string;
  twoUrl: string;
  threeUrl: string;
};

type IBarSectionUrlMap = {
  fourUrl: string;
  fiveUrl: string;
  sixUrl: string;
};

type IBlaSectionUrlMap = {
  sevenUrl: string;
  eightUrl: string;
  nineUrl: string;
};

type IPageConfig = {
  fooSection?: IFooSectionUrlMap;
  barSection?: IBarSectionUrlMap;
  blaSection?: IBlaSectionUrlMap;
};

function prefixNestedStrings (obj: Partial<Record<string, Record<string, string>>>): void {
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (!key.endsWith('Section')) continue; // key pattern mismatch

    const objChild = obj[key]; // Record<string, string> | undefined
    if (!objChild) continue; // no value

    for (const key in objChild) {
      if (!key.endsWith('Url')) continue; // key pattern mismatch
      const str = objChild[key];
      if (typeof str !== 'string') continue; // type mismatch
      objChild[key] = `/${str}`;
    }
  }
}

const pageConfig: IPageConfig = {
  fooSection: {
    oneUrl: 'one',
    twoUrl: 'two',
    threeUrl: 'three',
  },
  barSection: {
    fourUrl: 'four',
    fiveUrl: 'five',
    sixUrl: 'six',
  },
};

prefixNestedStrings(pageConfig);

console.log(pageConfig); // See console: looks good to me
```

Compiled JS from the TS playground:

```js
function prefixNestedStrings(obj) {
    for (const key in obj) {
        if (!key.endsWith('Section'))
            continue; // key pattern mismatch
        const objChild = obj[key]; // Record<string, string> | undefined
        if (!objChild)
            continue; // no value
        for (const key in objChild) {
            if (!key.endsWith('Url'))
                continue; // key pattern mismatch
            const str = objChild[key];
            if (typeof str !== 'string')
                continue; // type mismatch
            objChild[key] = `/${str}`;
        }
    }
}
const pageConfig = {
    fooSection: {
        oneUrl: 'one',
        twoUrl: 'two',
        threeUrl: 'three',
    },
    barSection: {
        fourUrl: 'four',
        fiveUrl: 'five',
        sixUrl: 'six',
    },
};
prefixNestedStrings(pageConfig);
console.log(pageConfig); // See console: looks good to me
```