# Creating mapped object in TypeScript

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, typescript-eslint

I have an `interface` that looks like that:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    group: Options
}
```

and an `enum` that looks like this:

```
export enum Options {
    ONE = 'one',
    TWO = 'two',
    THREE = 'three',
}
```

I want to create a new object where the key will be one of the `Options` and the value will be `Person`.

I tried something like that:

```
type PersonMapped = {
    [key in Options]: Person; // error on the in keyword
}
```

But I get an error that says: `parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "]"`.
What's wrong with this code?

**Edit 1:**
Here's the code example that I try to use:

```
export enum Group {
    ONE = 1,
    TWO = 2,
    THREE = 3
}

export type Mappable = {
    [key in Group]: string
}
```

Here's the error from the ide:

[image]

**Edit 2:**
It seems that the problem is with my editor settings. I'm using `vscode` version - 1.59.1. I also have `eslint` extension installed with version - 2.1.23.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your error](https://tsplay.dev/W4pd4W).  Please consider providing a [mcve] either in the form of plaintext that can be dropped into any standalone IDE to demonstrate the issue, or as a link to a properly configured web IDE project which demonstrates the issue. Right now my guess is you're trying to write TypeScript code in a JavaScript file but that's just a guess

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53508709/use-an-enum-to-type-an-index-signature-of-an-interface-field

Comment: @jcalz, I rechecked that I am actually in TS file. I added a simple example in my question.

Comment: So your problem seems to be with your editor or project configuration and not with TypeScript.  As I said before, [your TypeScript code is fine](https://tsplay.dev/mqvgrW); I see from the image that eslint is complaining, so you might want to tag this question with eslint and whatever editor you're using, and give more details about your project/editor configuration.

Comment: @jcalz, so do I need to add other tags to this question, or should I ask it again with new tags?

Comment: I would add tags instead of re-asking if I were you, but that's your choice.  Good luck!