# How to determine from 2 types either 1 or 2

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript.

I have 2 type.

```
type Point = {
    x: number;
    y: number;
};

type Label = {
    name: string;
};
```

I have Variable Duko.

```
let Duko: ? = {...};
```

How to say that Duko is equal to Label type or Point.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: `let Duko: Point | Label = {...};`

Comment: Are you asking specifically only how to declare the variable as a `Point` or a `Label`, or are you also asking how to tell which one it is later on?

Comment: @crashmstr  [Look what i want](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-91lle)

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify that you want `Duko` to be `Label` or `Point` *but not both*.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types):

> A union type describes a value that can be one of several types. We
>   use the vertical bar (|) to separate each type, so `number | string | boolean` is the type of a value that can be a `number`, a `string`, or a
>   `boolean`.

Therefore:

```
let Duko: Point | Label = {...};
```

Also an interesting read: [Typescript: Interfaces vs Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types)

Comment: your example is not what i want. [Look what i want](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-91lle)