# filtered array of objects, nuxt, vue js

Tags: arrays, typescript, vue.js

I need to filter an array depending on the values ​​of one of the keys in the object, but I get an error:

```
Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'Object'
```

I expected that if `panel.sort` is `true`, the array `worktop` would be rendered. Otherwise, the array `groupA` would be rendered.

What am I doing wrong? Why is my `sort` key not visible?

```js
export default class PanelSettings extends Vue {
  panels: Array < Object > = [{
      id: 0,
      name: "one",
      sort: true
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "two",
      sort: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "three",
      sort: true
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "four",
      sort: true
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "five",
      sort: true
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "six",
      sort: true
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "seven",
      sort: false
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: "eight",
      sort: false
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: "nine",
      sort: false
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: "ten",
      sort: false
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      name: "eleven",
      sort: false
    }
  ];

  get worktop() {
    return this.panels.filter(function(panel) {
      return panel.sort == true;
    });
  };
  get groupA() {
    return this.panels.filter(function(panel) {
      return panel.sort == false;
    });
  };

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="panel in worktop" :key="panel.id" class="mb-3 mr-8">
    <div>
      <tw-pannel class="text-danger button">
        <tw-icon name="minus" />
        <span>{{panel.name}}</span>
      </tw-pannel>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li v-for="panel in groupA" :key="panel.id" class="mb-3 mr-8">
    <div>
      <tw-pannel class="text-primary">
        <tw-icon name="plus" />
        <span>{{panel.name}}</span>
      </tw-pannel>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#general-types) you shouldn't use `Object` type but `object`. But even then, `sort` is not a property of `object`, because javascript's [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) has no property `sort`.

Create interface or type alias (see [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types)) and use it instead of `Object`

```js
interface MyPanelObject {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    sort: boolean
}

/*OR:*/

type MyPanelObject = {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    sort: boolean
}

/* change this line: */
panels: Array<MyPanelObject> = [/*panels*/];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! but I get an errors: 1) Property or method "panelPlace" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render., , 2) ` TypeError: _vm.panelPlace is not a function `

Comment: What is `panelPlace`? Is this some method added to each `panel` object? I can't see it in your code.

Comment: oh,  i am apologize!!!!Yes, I did not delete this method. But, despite this, the interface does not work.

Answer (score 0):

While you could declare the proper type annotation for `panels`, you don't actually *need* it in your particular use case (at least from what's shown in the question).

You could simply remove the type annotation, and allow TypeScript to infer the array type without loss of type safety:

[image: screencast]