# Infer values of interface will never

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have encountered strange behavior. TypeScript version: 4.9.4 [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gJLmvJZAbwFgAoASAEEAuZLKUAc3IF9zywBPABxXSzIAvGkw48sRCggAPSCAAmGZACUICAPZQFAHlAxoyANIAaZHBBcAfMgD8x5HRAQAbtADc5ADYQwyMACMdAJg7sgA9OHIVBxknLz8YgBMwqJYuJCShLLySqrqWroWXGb6hgBqNvYBjsjOblCeZD5+YEnByWGRda7QsfF8aWAAzKkhGfhSyDkQispqmtp6IAZQxqUrFVXI5bX1Ht6+-sMdWMNdUQzM5EA)

```js
interface TestInterface {
    A: string
}

type Test = TestInterface extends Record<infer K, any> ? K : never;
let t1: Test; // A


type Test2 = TestInterface extends Record<any, infer V> ? 1 : never;
let t2: Test2; // never


type Test3 = TestInterface extends Record<infer K, infer V> ? V : never;
let t3: Test3; // string
```

I have interface `TestInterface`.

- When I try to infer only keys, it works.
- When I try to infer values, will never.
- When I try to infer keys and values, it works..

Why?

Comment: If you make `TestInterface` a type (use `type` instead of `interface`) - it would work. I think it has something with indexing. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript#answer-64971386) question. Also, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58251698/does-this-typescript-example-violate-the-liskov-subtitution-principle) answer and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-332366024) comment. It appears that  it is safer to infer type index signature than interface

Comment: `Record<any, infer V>` is equivalent to the index signature type `{[k: string]: infer V}`, and interfaces do not get implicit index signatures, so there's no match.  This is one of the few places where you can't just use `any` to mean "I don't care". If you need to write that without doing `infer K` then you should use `keyof TestInterface` instead of `any`.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining with links to sources.  If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Record` has 2 behaviours and it gets people confused all the time, but interfaces and index signatures also get people confused.

```
type Record<K extends string | number | symbol, T> = { [P in K]: T; }
```

When `K` is a union of subtypes of `string`, `number` or `symbol`, like `'A' | 'B'`, it results in an object literal type, like the following:

```
{ A: string, B: string }
```

An object literal type says:

> I know about the fields listed here, but there can be any number of supernumerary fields and they can be of any type

When `K` is a union of exactly `string`, `number` or `symbol`, like `string | number`, it results in a type signature, like the following

```
{
   [key: string]: string
   [key: number]: string
}
```

A type signature basically says:

> every possible field matching this type of key will be of this very type

And that's very different.

`Record` is also a bit weird in that `Record<any, unknown>` evaluates to `{[k: string]: unknown}` contrary `Record<PropertyKey, unknown>` or `{ [P in any]: unknown }` but that's not what caused your surprise.

Bottom line is: when you `extend` either an object literal type or an index signature, it's not at all the same kind of check.

---

The second confusing thing is: interfaces are not finite, because of [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces).

```
interface TestInterface {
    A: string
}

interface TestInterface {
    B: number
}

// same as
interface TestInterface {
    A: string
    B: number
}
```

If you can merge it at will, and even use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation), it's hard to say that an interface extends an index signature at any given time — at least that's my mental model and it works quite well.

The only exception is if you constrain your interface to a specific index signature explicitly:

```
interface TestInterface {
    [k: string]: string
    A: "foo"
}

interface TestInterface {
    B: number
//  ~~~~~~~~~ nope!
}
```

Then you are in a position to make promises: if you `extends Record<any, infer V>`, `V` will be exactly `string` (even though `A` is `"foo"`)

---

Now, as mentioned in the comments, when you write `keyof TestInterface` you get the interface's keys. Using them in `Record` will return an object literal type, and you will be good.

```
interface TestInterface {
    A: string
}
type S = TestInterface extends Record<keyof TestInterface, infer V> ? V : never; // string
```

Just take note that this is only true if the interface does not have an explicit index signature: if it has one, it won't return known keys, such as `"A"` but something like `string | number` (you always get `number` when the key is `string`) which will return an index signature when fed to `Record`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but I don't understand your phrase **I know about the fields listed here, but there can be any number of supernumerary fields and they can be of any type**. In this type `{ A: string, B: string }` possible fields only `'A' | 'B'` and we know about field types. Why there can be any number of supernumerary fields if I listed only `'A' | 'B'`?

Comment: Excess property checking fires in a couple of places where TS assumes you probably don't intend to have supernumerary properties: when you use an object literal expression as the initializer of an annotated variable declaration, and when you use an object literal expression as an argument in a call expression; But at the type level, it works exactly as I have explained and you should always assume it is so as an implementer anyway because people can pass references to your functions. https://tsplay.dev/NrDO1W