# Declare interface instead of type

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export type MessageGroups = {
    [id: string]: MessageGroupModel
};

export interface MessageGroupModel {
    groupId: string;
    memberIds: string[];
    messages: ChatMessageModel[];
}
```

Usage is like this:

```
async handleFullMessageGroupUpdate(newMessageGroup: MessageGroupModel) {
    let messageGroups: MessageGroups = await this.storage.get(StorageKeys.MESSAGES);
    if (!messageGroups) {
      messageGroups = {}
    }
    if (!messageGroups[newMessageGroup.groupId]) {
      messageGroups[newMessageGroup.groupId] = newMessageGroup;
    } else {
      messageGroups[newMessageGroup.groupId].memberIds = newMessageGroup.memberIds;
      messageGroups[newMessageGroup.groupId].memberProfiles = newMessageGroup.memberProfiles;
      messageGroups = this.mergeNewGroupMessages(messageGroups,
        newMessageGroup.messages, newMessageGroup.groupId, newMessageGroup.lastMessageUpdateTime);
    }   
  }
```

`export type MessageGroups` declaration is not clear to me. can't I use `interface` here instead of `type`?

Comment: You can indeed use `interface` here instead of `type` - the two can often be interchanged with each other. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types

Comment: @PeterOlson Yes, I saw that. Since I know `interface` well I would like to use it here. Will I miss something here if I'll use the `interface`? Do I need to change any `usage` code then?

Comment: As far as I can tell, nothing important will change if you use an `interface` instead.

Comment: @PeterOlson Thanks for the clarifications. I hope you can put it as an answer.

Comment: They are similar in this case but they have significant differences