# What is equivalent interface to the "AppThunk" type from redux docs?

Tags: typescript, redux

Redux docs contain this:

```
import { configureStore, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'

import rootReducer, { RootState } from './rootReducer'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
})

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./rootReducer', () => {
    const newRootReducer = require('./rootReducer').default
    store.replaceReducer(newRootReducer)
  })
}

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch

export type AppThunk = ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, Action<string>>

export default store
```

1. Why does the author use `type` instead of `interface` here? I've read [the answer on the difference between types and interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682220/4845952) but still don't get why would anyone need to use type instead of interface?
2. What would be the interface equivalent of these lines?

```
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export type AppThunk = ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, Action<string>>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm a Redux maintainer, and I think I may have written that particular snippet.

I'm not a complete TS expert, so in some ways the whole "`type` vs `interface`" thing confuses me a bit too.

If you look at [the original `ThunkAction` type from the `redux-thunk` typings](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/6cec3962d80853b48525a3eb99299c1cb7e4b10d/src/index.d.ts#L50-L59), you can see that it's defined using the `type` keyword:

```
export type ThunkAction<
  TReturnType,
  TState,
  TExtraThunkArg,
  TBasicAction extends Action
> = (
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<TState, TExtraThunkArg, TBasicAction>,
  getState: () => TState,
  extraArgument: TExtraThunkArg,
) => TReturnType;
```

As I understand it, a TS `interface` can extend another `interface`, but an `interface` can never extend a `type.  So, the fact that`ThunkAction`is defined as a`type`means that`AppThunk`_must_ also be a`type.

Hypothetically, you could define `ThunkAction` as an `interface`, which I *think* would look like:

```
interface ThunkAction {
    // declaring a signature here without a field name means this is describing
    // a function that matches this signature, vs an object field
    <
      TReturnType,
      TState,
      TExtraThunkArg,
      TBasicAction extends Action
    > = (
      dispatch: ThunkDispatch<TState, TExtraThunkArg, TBasicAction>,
      getState: () => TState,
      extraArgument: TExtraThunkArg,
    ) => TReturnType
}
```

However, in practice, it seems like declaring types of functions using `interface` is a rare use case.  Interfaces are generally used for objects, and `type` for anything that's not strictly an object or is a derived type.

For `AppDispatch`, it's a derived type using `typeof`, so it *has* to be `type`.