# Use of interface instead of 'any' type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

[image]is it a good idea to use interface instead of using any as a variable type.
say i have 3 functions where i am defining variables which can be of alphanumeric format.
Hence instead of defining it as of any can i do as an interface

Comment: yes its always a good practive to avoid any and create interface for types.
interface helloworld {
  name: string;
}
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea to use actual types. If you just use `any`, then why are you even employing **Type**Script and ditching the **types**?

Comment: say i have multiple variables in each function of type any, to remove type any, i will have to create multiple interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the right way. The goal of TS is to provide types instead of `any` values from javascript.

The goal is to have all variables typed, if you don't know its type - try to use `generic` or `unknown` instead of `any`. A type def is more extensible than an interface def. An interface works for objects and classes, a type works for everything including primitives, unions and infers, but a class can implement interfaces only, not types.

If you need to assert type you can use type guards:

```
const isNumber = (value: unknown): value is number {
  return typeof value === 'number';
}

const something: any = 123;
something += 1; // valid
something.callFake(); // valid

if (isNumber(something)) {
  something += 1; // valid
  something.callFake(); // invalid
}
```

In your case use can use generics.

```js
public addRow(row: Row): boolean {
  let constraints: unknown = getConstraints(this.config); // unknown fits too
  let table: any = localStorage.getItem(row.tableName);
  let rowData = {};
}

public getData<T>( // <- T, when we don't know type.
  table_name: string,   entity_name?: string,
  entity_value?: T
): boolean {
  let tableRecord: object[] = [];
  let allTableData: Array<object> = JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem(table_name) || ""
  ).data;
}

public deleteRecord<T extends string>( // <- T, when we don't know type.
  table_name: string,
  entity_name: string,
  entity_value: T
): boolean {
  return !!entity_value; // works
}

public updateRecord<T, D extends object>( // <- T, D, when we don't know type.
 table_name: string,
 entity_name: string,
 entity_value: T,
 updation_data: D
): boolean {
  if (typeof entity_name === 'string) {
    // now we know it's a string.
  }
  return !entity_value || !updation_data; // works
}
```

Comment: is this type more efficient than interface?

Comment: depends on what you needs. The goal is to have all variables typed, if you don't know its type - try to use generic or unknown instead of any. A type def is more extensible than an interface def. An interface works for objects and classes, a type works for everything including primitives, unions and infers.

Comment: Like that: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChllIBnMALmUqlAHMBuIgXyKNElkRQwEEoUOOmQQAHpBAATcskHD0AHgzZueCAD5CJZGw4IA9iErI4QkTQEXRAXmQBtAhWrIA5AEYATAGY3rAF0mIA

Comment: Try like that `function getConstraints(config: Config): Array<Column['constraints']> {`.

Comment: actually i just want the any type changed to an interface

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not clear what you want to do. Might you show what you have and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use typescript `type` definition. e.g. if u have multiple types for a variable, you can create a single type as:

`type Foo = Bar1 | Bar2 | Bar3`

where `Bar1`, `Bar2`, `Bar3` can be different interfaces or even types.