# What does "type" mean in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Reviewing some TypeScript code and I came across this and I am not sure what it means:

```
type data = {
  serial_number: string;
  hub_sn: string;
};

type rapid = data & {
  type: "rapid";
  ob: number[];
};
```

I see rapid referenced with a listener:

```
listen.on("rapid", async (data: rapid) => {
  const [ts, ob] = decodeRapid(data.ob);
  const body = `rapid,station=${data.serial_number} ${
    serialize(ob)
  } ${ts}`;
  const response = await writeToInfluxDB(body);
  console.log(JSON.stringify({ response, body }));
});
```

I am kind of lost on how the data from the listener is fed into the objects??

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37233735/1231844