# Typescript generics does not work with Readonly

Tags: typescript

Let's have the following simplified example in TypeScript:

```js
type Foo = { name: string } | undefined

function fooWorks<T extends Foo>(input: T) {
    return input?.name // ok
}

function fooErrors<T extends Foo>(input: Readonly<T>) {
    return input?.name // error
}
```

Why `fooWorks` works, but `fooErrors` does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will preserve the `Readonly` type and `undefined` as desired:

```
function fooErrors<T extends Readonly<Foo>>(input: T) {
    return input?.name // works
}
```

Note: we set `Readonly` in the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) and don't wrap it around the parameter type.

The reason, why `fooErrors<T extends Foo>(input: Readonly<T>)` causes issues is: TypeScript does not process unresolved generic type parameters (like `T`) further. [`Readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype) essentially is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). So in the function body, `input` has type `{ readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P]; }`, which unfortunately is not assignable back to `T` and its constraint `Foo`. From the compiler's perspective property `name` on the parameter cannot be found anymore.

[Playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKA7AhgWwgLigGdgAnASwwHMoBfKAHygFcMATCAM0ojYCg%20nVgGNg5OBiicEAdTikA1kQA8AFSgQAHsAjsisBAD4AFJTDNghVQEo0fKA6ikIwZqUlmLAfgB02PFAA9IFQcAp8tAJCGKLiktJwAKKkpPIq6lo6elAAShBYbBIANiDK8HCGJp6WUDZ2jk4ubh4Y5sC%20-tDBoeGRggjJqaRExqidhABECRO01kA)

Comment: I cannot change the code, because the real code is in a third-party library (react). (This is just heavily simplified example for demonstration purposes.) Could you provide some references or issues where the behavior is specified / tracked?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884 is one example of generics not being interpreted further. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995 another more prominent one (latter focused on union narrowing).

Comment: That you for the issue links!

Answer (score 1):

It gives the following error:

> Property 'name' does not exist on type `NonNullable`.

The problem is, that the TypeScript compiler *does not understand the subtle type narrowing here and throws a compile-time error* as stated [here](https://medium.com/@gregoryppabian/nullability-in-typescript-60be8c5a6d87) (though, I am not 100% sure about how helpful this blog post is for you).

Removing `undefined` from `Foo` works:

```
type Foo = { name: string }

function fooWorks<T extends Foo>(input: T) {
    return input?.name
}

function fooErrors<T extends Foo>(input: Readonly<T>) {
    return input?.name
}
```

Or you can add the [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) type excluding `null` and `undefined` from `T`, which results in `input` being `{ name: string }`:

```
type Foo = { name: string } | undefined

function fooWorks<T extends Foo>(input: T) {
    return input?.name
}

function fooErrors<T extends Foo>(input: Readonly<NonNullable<T>>) {
  return input.name
}
```

Comment: I was trying to read the link, but `5xx Oops! Something happened to Medium.`.

Comment: Retry, I seems to me that `does not understand the subtle type narrowing here and throws a compile-time error` in the post refers something different: `filter` does not return different type.

Comment: It's pretty hard to find a comprehensible explanation for the described behavior (at least for me). I keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a limitation of type aliases.

```
interface Foo  { name: string }

function fooWorks<T extends Foo>(input?: T) {
    return input?.name // ok
}




function fooErrors<T extends Foo>(input?: Readonly<T>) {
    return input?.name // error
}
```

Behaves as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately `{ name?: string }` != `{ name: string } | undefined`. Is it known issue?

Comment: `fooErrors<T extends { name: string } | undefined>(input: Readonly<T>)` does not work.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the type slightly. I have updated it. 
Known limitations are well outlined in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types