# Does TypeScript mean to treat `readonly string[]` as `readonly any[]`? Does eslint?

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

I'm using [Mock Service Worker](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/mocks/rest-api#request-handler) to test some TypeScript code, and as part of a [REST mock (same link)](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/mocks/rest-api#request-handler), I want to pull a parameter from a GET request.

I'm using this code:

```
rest.get(getFullPath(`${relativePathEntityEndpoint}/:id`), async (req, res, context) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    // ...
});
```

That `id` is showing a type of `const id: string | readonly string[]` in VS Code.

If it's an array, I want the first value. If it's a string, I'll take it as-is. Then going forward I can treat the new variable as a `string`. Simple enough.

`const singleId = pullParam(id);`

I'm performing this conversion with this convenience function.

```
function pullParam(id: readonly string[] | string): string {
    return Array.isArray(id) ? id[0] : id;
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting a typescript-eslint error with that.

```
Unsafe return of an `any` typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
(parameter) id: string | readonly string[]
```

It seems to be treating the [readonly array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) as an `any` type. As in I can't do any string manipulation tricks -- eg, let's pretend the strings in the collection are wack, can I launder it with `id[0].slice()`? No sir, you can't, because it's an `any`, and we can't trust that `slice` isn't `sendYourSSNandCreditCardsToHackers`. :sigh: That's contrived, but you get the point. It's stuck in `any`land.

Another attempt at laundering the value...

```
function pullParam(id: readonly string[] | string): string {
    return Array.isArray(id) ? (id as string[])[0] : id;
    // have also tried: 
    return Array.isArray(id) ? (id[0] as string[]) : id; -- same error
}
```

... for example, gives...

```
Type 'string | readonly string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'readonly string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Huh?

If we're calling `readonly string[]` an `any`, and it appears we are, I can't think of a creative way to say, "No, seriously, everything's fine. We just want to return your first string value."

I know I can `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return`, but I'd rather learn what I'm missing or file this as an issue with the linting. What's a better solution?

---

Ooooh, [*Typescript generics does not work with Readonly*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64790756/1028230) looks promising, but I'm not quite following why that's the case yet.

Comment: Given `const foo: string[] = []` you have an array containing only strings where `foo[0]` is `undefined`, not a string.

Comment: @Quentin But I don't think that's what I'm seeing. It's not "return of an undefined". `return Array.isArray(id) && id[0] ? id[0] : id;` (or `&& id.length`) also doesn't fix that issue... that is, even if I ensure `id[0]` is truthy, I get the "No sir, that's an `any`; it's too dangerous!" behavior.

Comment: The linked question you found is irrelevant, I'm sorry to say. This is a linter problem. TypeScript isn't the one erroring. TL;DR your linter is being dumb.

Comment: @kelsny I think it might be _two_ linters -- `@typescript-eslint` for `no-unsafe-return` and `ts(2322)`, which might be the TypeScript parser? It's at least part of Microsoft's end of TS. So even if it's the linters, I think TS is reporting something funky back. Usually when I can't follow how it inferred its types, I'm the one in the wrong, so I'm curious what I might've missed... but still suspicious I need to open some issues.

Comment: No look, `TS2322` is the error code for that type of TypeScript error. However, that error was caused by your attempt to shut ESLint up, so it's still ESLint's fault. You can try finding related issues on their GitHub repo (typescript-eslint's, not eslint) or open one if you can't find any.

Comment: @kelsny Sorry, I've got extra `[]` in those `as` attempts, which was dumb. Lemme fix that and see what it says.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform Typescript type checking to infer that a value is of type X or Y using `typeof` and `instanceof` as appropriate. Check this example:

```
/**
 * The expected Request object.
 */
interface Request {
    params: Record<string, readonly string[] | string>;
}

/**
 * The expected Response object.
 */
interface Response {
    end(v: any): void;
}

/**
 * This is your endpoint.
 * @param req Your Request object.
 * @param res Your Response object.
 */
export function endpoint(req: Request, res: Response): void {
    // Here's how to handle your question in this scenario
    const id = req.params.id instanceof Array
        ?   req.params.id[0]
        :   req.params.id;

    res.end(id);
}

/**
 * A fake Request class to test `this.params.id as string | string[]`.
 */
export class FakeRequest implements Request {
    constructor(
        public params: Record<string, string | string[]>
    ) {}
}

/**
 * A fake Response class to view the value obtained.
 */
export class FakeResponse implements Response {
    end(v: any): void {
        console.log('Value sended:', v);
    }
}

// Case 01: id as string[]
endpoint(
    new FakeRequest({ id: [ 'foo' ] }),
    new FakeResponse()
);

// Case 02: id as string
endpoint(
    new FakeRequest({ id: 'bar' }),
    new FakeResponse()
);
```

If you execute this code, the endpoint is capable to handle both situations and the Typescript compiler builds this code without problems.

Comment: Okay, unfortunately I knew I could put the code inline, but didn't mention b/c OP was already too long. That is, `export function endpoint(req: Request, res: Response): void {` works, but tell me how to abstract the part _after_ `const id =` into a function that doesn't make the linter throw up. That is, I essentially had what you have here & then tried to DRY up some related code by pulling out `pullParam` & *bam*, trouble starts. You have a working end run around my problem, but unfortunately not an answer. +1 for the beautifully written and laid out code -- & for demonstrating the end run!