# Interface cannot extend mapped type in conditional type

Tags: typescript, interface, conditional-types, mapped-types

While debugging my program, I noticed that the following example yields a compile error ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvA1hEAuKBnYAJwEsA7AcwF8BuAKDOAkIDMBDAY2gCFXC1Mc+ImSp1aoSFB4AvZLARQIAD0akAJnigAlCOziE1AHgIkKAGigBXUulJwA7qQB8AfiitSg0hABuTOhLQAIqWSnI8fMqqGtq6+kYmIhbWtg7Obh5evv60tHqkBFAARqzSuDJyAAx0+YUAjqG4IWEo1bRAA)).

```js
type Foo = {key: string};
interface Bar {key: string};

type Baz = Foo extends Record<string, unknown>? any: never;
type Qux = Bar extends Record<string, unknown>? any: never;

const baz: Baz = 0;
const qux: Qux = 0; // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

It seems interfaces cannot extend `Record<string, unknown>` whereas types can. I know there are several differences between types and interfaces in TypeScript, and I suspect the fact that mapped types cannot be used in interfaces might explain the behavior. I cannot fully understand why this map type restriction results in `Qux` being `never` even if that's the case, though.

Moreover, `interface Foobar extends Record<string, unknown> { key: string };` is a valid interface definition, which makes the error more confusing to me.

Could anyone help me understand this error?

Comment: I believe this is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types/54101543#answer-64971386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because type aliases have implicit index signature, but interfaces don't.

If you'll add index signature to the interface - the `Qux` will result in `any`:

```
interface Bar { 
    key: string;
    [p: string]: string;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBrCIBcUDOwATgJYB2A5lAL4DcAUOcBEQGYCGAxtAELtFoo9KCMzY8hUpQaioAbTATi5CgF0lUigzr16oSFD4AvZLARQIAD2ZkAJvigAlCJzhFbAHkkqANFACuZBhkcADuZAB8UAD8UOxkIFB4ZBAAbiwM%20tAAiv6WpnwCVjb2Ti5unt6UfoHBYZExcQlJUCnpRAz0rmSEUABG7EZ4xqYADAzdvQCOeXi5%20SjjQkA)

More info [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-332366024):

> This behavior is currently by design. Because interfaces can be augmented by additional declarations but type aliases can't, it's "safer" (heavy quotes on that one) to infer an implicit index signature for type aliases than for interfaces.

Comment: This technique can be used to check if type is interface or not. But not sure if it is useful)))

Comment: I actually checked the referenced issue, but had no idea that it was relevant, thank you. Still, my question remains; why is `interface Foobar extends Record<string, unknown> { key: string };` valid? If `{ key: string }` in the expression is an interface (not a type alias), it doesn't have index signature and can't be a partial type of `Record<string, unknown>`, can it? I might be missing something fundamental...

Comment: @yudai-nkt You're mixing "interface extension" https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces with conditional types https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types

Comment: Ah, got it. Yes, I was overthinking things and somehow confused these two `extends`. Thanks again!