# Typescript ERROR: Index signature is missing in type [SOME_OBJECT]

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created a function that receives a `string` keys based `object` with any desired value.

The function definition line:

```js
export const pickFromObj = <
  Obj extends { [K: string]: unknown }, 
  PickKeys extends keyof Obj
>(object: Obj, keys: PickKeys[]) => {
```

1. **First I would like to know if there is any way to make this shorter.**
2. **In addition, when I pass some the following object to the function, I receive the following error from TS compiler:**

```
Argument of type 'IExample' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [x: string]: unknown; }'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'IExample'.ts(2345)
```

IExample:

```js
export interface IExample {
  fromAddress: string;
  toAddress: string;
  status: number;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because   `{ [key: string]: unknown }`    means that the object has an index signature. So you can use any string as a key for this object, while  `IAreasInfoFormFields` does not have index signature.

Consider this example:

```js
type Indexed = { [K: string]: unknown }

interface NotIndexed {
  name: string;
}

const foo = <T extends Indexed>(obj: T) => obj

const obj: NotIndexed = {
  name: 'name',
}

foo(obj) // error
```

Here you see an error because you are not allowed to do smth like this:

```js
interface NotIndexed {
  name: string;
}

const obj: NotIndexed = {
  name: 'name',
}

obj.hello // error
```

But if you have indexed object, you are allowed to use any string key:

```js
type Indexed = { [K: string]: unknown }

const obj: Indexed = {
  name: 'name',
}

obj.hello // ok
```

One interesting thing, that  `types` are indexed by the default. If you will use `type` keyword instead `interface` keyword, this code will compile:

```js
type Indexed = { [K: string]: unknown }

type NotIndexed= {
  name: string;
}

const foo = <T extends Indexed>(obj: T) => obj

const obj: NotIndexed= {
  name: 'name',
}

foo(obj) // ok
```

This is the difference between interfaces and types. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types#answer-64971386) related answer.

So, if you use `type` keyword instead of `interface` in `Example` interface, it should compile

Comment: Thanks. I believe types are indexed by default as they are configured as 'object' and not 'structure.

Answer (score -1):

1. Oh yes there is:

```js
const pickFromObj = <O, K extends keyof O>(object: O, keys: K[]) => { };
```

2. The code above also gets rid of your indexing error :)

[Link to TS Playground here](http://interface%20IExample%20%7B%20%20%20fromAddress:%20string;%20%20%20toAddress:%20string;%20%20%20status:%20number;%20%7D%20%20class%20IClass%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20public%20fromAddress:%20string%20=%20%27From%20Address%27;%20%7D%20%20declare%20function%20pickFromObj%3CO,%20K%20extends%20keyof%20O%3E(object:%20O,%20keys:%20K%5B%5D):%20unknown;%20%20declare%20const%20example:%20IExample;%20declare%20const%20classExample:%20IClass;%20%20//%20Works%20as%20it%20should%20pickFromObj(example,%20%5B%27fromAddress%27%5D);%20pickFromObj(classExample,%20%5B%27fromAddress%27%5D);%20%20//%20Errors%20as%20it%20should%20pickFromObj(example,%20%5B%27x%27%5D);)

Answer (score -2):

come if you wanna see the light. do not complicate yourself.

basically

```js
interface Person {
    /** the first name of the person */
    first: string;
    /** the first name of the person */
    last: string;
    /** contact email of the person */
    email: string;
    /** person's age */
    age:number;
}

/**
 * @description Get the value of a property from a given obj.
 *
 * @date 06/07/2021
 * @export
 * @template Obj type definition of the obj
 * @param {keyof Obj} key a property inside of our obj.
 * @param {Obj} obj any object from where we want the value.
 * @returns {Obj[key]} the value of the prop.
 * @example
 * const last = getFromObj<Person>("last", eneto);
 */
export function getFromObj<Obj>(key: keyof Obj, obj:Obj):Obj[keyof Obj] {
    return obj[key];
}

const eneto: Person ={

    first:"Ernesto",

    last:"Jara",

    email:"email@email.com",
    age:19,
}

const name = getFromObj<Person>("first", eneto);
const age = getFromObj<Person>("age", eneto);

console.log("name", name);
console.log("age", age);
```

There you have it, if you hover over `name` or `age` vscode or yow favorite editor will say

```js
const name: string | number;
```

but you know name is an string and age is a number, so you need to let TS to know that as well.

Do it like this

```js
const name = getFromObj<Person>("first", eneto) as string;
const age = getFromObj<Person>("age", eneto) as number;
```

now if you hover over name it'll show you

```js
const name: string;
```