# Dictionary type in TypeScript not accepting a hash of methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, lowdb

I'm importing types from [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) via [@types/lowdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lowdb), and when using their `mixins()` method to configure mixins on a store, it complains that the argument I'm passing doesn't type-match:

> Argument of type 'Map<string, Function>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Dictionary<(...args: any[]) => any>'.
> Index signature is missing in type 'Map<string, Function>'.ts(2345)

I assumed that the type accepted by the `mixins` method was essentially a map of functions indexed with a string. So figured that `Map<string, function>` would be an acceptable thing to pass it. The context:

```js
async setupStore ({storeName, storeMixins} : {storeName: string, storeMixins: Map<string, Function>}) {

    const store: LowdbSync<any> = await lowdb(new StoreMemoryAdapter(storeName))

    store._.mixin(storeMixins)

}
```

I guess my confusion here is a lack of understanding of what `Dictionary<(...args: any[]) => any>` expects in real terms. I'm unable to use the type declaration myself as it is not available to me in userland. But perhaps `Map<string, Function>` is not the correct equivalent?

Comment: Please provide `Dictionary` type

Comment: I don't see a definition of the `Dictionary` interface. I assume this is a type declared by the `@types/lowdb` library which I have linked to. Looking at that repo I can't see any declaration of `Dictionary`, so perhaps it is brought in via `@types/lodash` which is a dependency. How does one go about finding definitions of these things easily?

Comment: Try `Record<string, (...args:any[])=>any>` or `{ [prop:string]:(...args:any[])=>any }` instead of `Map<string, Function>` because `Map` is not indexed.
Btw try to avoid constructor types like `Function, String etc ...`
Please let me know if it helped

Comment: This seems to work but I'm not sure as to why. Could you elaborate in a proper answer, and include how you were able to determine that `Dictionary` would be equivalent to what you've put?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is most important here:

> Index signature is missing in type 'Map<string, Function>'.ts(2345)

More information about index signatures you can find [in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)

Let's take a look on `Map` type definition:

```js
interface Map<K, V> {
    clear(): void;
    delete(key: K): boolean;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: V, key: K, map: Map<K, V>) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
    get(key: K): V | undefined;
    has(key: K): boolean;
    set(key: K, value: V): this;
    readonly size: number;
}
```

As you might have noticed there is no index signature `{[prop: string]:any}`

This means that it is impossible to do smtg like this: `Map<string, string>[string]`.
COnsider this example:

```js
type Fn = (...args: any[]) => any

type A = Map<string, Fn>[string] // error
type B = Record<string, Fn>[string] // ok -> Fn

interface C {
  [prop: string]: Fn
}

type Cc = C[string] // ok -> Fn
```

Btw, there is a small difference between types an interfaces in context of indexing.
Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types#answer-64971386) answer.

Comment: So I could potentially pass `{ [prop: string]: any }` also? Or `{ [index: string]: (...args: any[]) => any }` if I wanted to be more specific about the function signature? I.e `Record` is a convenience type for the above?

Comment: Correct. But instead of `{ [prop: string]: any }` it is safer to use `Record<string, unknown>`