# In TypeScript, why do I get an error when I assign an interface to an interface, but there is no error when I assign a type to an interface?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, why do I get an error when I assign an interface to an interface, but there is no error when I assign a type to an interface?

I want to know why this happens！

```js
// ----------- Scenes one------------
interface A {
    [key: string]: string;
 };

interface B {
    name: string;
}

let b: B = { name: "pig" };
let a: A = b; //error      The type "B" cannot be assigned to the type "A".  The index signature is missing in type "B".

// ----------- Scenes two------------
interface A {
    [key: string]: string;
 };

type B = {
    name: string;
}

let b: B = { name: "pig" };
let a: A = b; //success ？？
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript#answer-64971386