# Why is this always true? type X = {} extends {[x:string]:number} ? true : false

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements

The type {}(empty type) is almost a super type which every raw type extends it. My question is why the type {[x:string]:number} extends {}? The following type is always true:

```
type X =  {} extends {[x:string]:number} ? true : false
```

Comment: I think because of  this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300  and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript#answer-64971386

Comment: It's all about differences between interface and type declarations. My question is what's exactly the type {[x:string]:number}? Is it a type with infinite number of properties? or it is an empty type. To be clarify consider the following code:
type T1='a'|'b';
type T2 = {[t in string]:number};
type T3 = {[t in T1]:number};
const x:T2={};// fine
const y:T3={}// error! why?

Comment: `T3` expects `a` and `b` prop and you did not provide them to `y`

Comment: I know but {[x:string]:number} also says the objects of this type must have at least a property of type number and still we can assign an empty object to a variable of this type.

Comment: That's not what that type says; it says that the type is indexed by string keys with numeric values. Having no such key is entirely valid.

Comment: "Having no such key is entirely valid", can you supply any reference to this?