# TypeScript check if a string is a key value in an interface

Tags: typescript, interface

```
const string = 'world';
const string2 = 'bar';
const string3 = 'test';

interface example {
  hello: 'world';
  foo: 'bar';
};
```

How can I check if a string is a key value in an interface?

So that in the example `string` and `string2` would pass and `string3` would throw an error?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if that's what you're looking for https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBLMBzAjDAvDA5AdxHgBsATHAbgChRJYFkUAmLXAIwEN4Lrxo4okqAMwscUAKbRulZBPgAzdsHExxAD3YBbAA5EVAb0owYAC3FEiIAFy4CxMlWPyQ1tp24BfKpSgBPbSoAwmbAANYAkhAAauxEAK7i4WAAoho6egA8UapqEmAkEDlauuIA2qHiviDyReniALoAfCxR3n4BMAAaLMHiYZEx8YkpaSUZ7eLV-IIoQs0A9PMwACr+KjgARBLQGzgwJCCSMGAgdOxQiBDyvjBQZjA0COyyuBt2pBswAD4wGxzwuyAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
const string = 'world';
const string2 = 'bar';
const string3 = 'test';

interface example {
    hello: 'world';
    foo: 'bar';
};


type IsAValue<Obj, Str extends string> = {
    [Prop in keyof Obj]: Str extends Obj[Prop] ? Str : never
}[keyof Obj]

type Result1 = IsAValue<example, 'world'> // world
type Result2 = IsAValue<example, 'bar'> // bar
type Result3 = IsAValue<example, 'test'> // never
```

**`IsAValue`:**

`Prop` - represents each key
`Obj` - represents an object, in our case it is `example` interface.

This utility type iterates through each `Obj` (`example`) key and check whether `Obj[Prop]` extends second argument `Str` (`string` or `string2`). If yes - use `Str` as an object value, otherwise - use `never`.
This line `[keyof Obj]` at the end of utility type obtains a union of all values in the object. If some value mathced `Str` we will get `Str | never`. Because `never` is a bottom type, and `never` is assignable to any type, union of `Str | never` just returns `Str`.

If you want to obtain just boolean from `IsAValue`, I mean `true` - value exists, `false` - not exists. You can just add conditional type, which will check whether results extends `never` or not:

```js
const string = 'world';
const string2 = 'bar';
const string3 = 'test';

interface example {
    hello: 'world';
    foo: 'bar';
};


type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false

type IsAValue<Obj, Str extends string> = IsNever<{
    [Prop in keyof Obj]: Str extends Obj[Prop] ? Str : never
}[keyof Obj]> extends false ? true : false

type Result1 = IsAValue<example, 'world'> // true
type Result2 = IsAValue<example, 'bar'> // true
type Result3 = IsAValue<example, 'test'> // false
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAI4CcCWkDm8C88DkB3cJAGwBNcBuMKORWVDAJmzwCMBDJS6mBZNdAGYWuWAFM43YGnFIAZu1Bj4YgB7sAtgAdiygN7B4R%20AAsxxYuABceQiXJVj8OeGttO3AL5UQsAJ5aygCS0AByYgBuYkgAPAAqAHwsANpxALoqquKQpNDwyZCR0RkA-PD0AK7KNgrE0GK%20AcHQAIIAauzEVTEA8qwAVgA08ADK9JnZuXQM6Ek4IeFRsQZOyQAKSOBa8GjwANZifuBy8H39aTZjSBNiOXln65tapaPjNoVLwJ7JB0cnZ2kkmpJnlavV4GVKtVnJ16o1AvAAEoSCrEWAARhYIXanW6ak0OjEwwIRDIuCSAHoKeUkFVgP4EcjoKjYMx5q0Ol0xDF8dpdMSOFxKdSofSmkiUWjhOycVyeeo%20US8OJJMKYXUGiAQEA)

If you want to throw an error, see this exmaple:

```js
const string = 'world';
const string2 = 'bar';
const string3 = 'test';

type example = {
    hello: 'world';
    foo: 'bar';
};

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Assert<Obj extends Record<string, string>, Key extends Values<Obj>> = Obj

type Result1 = Assert<example, 'world'> // true
type Result2 = Assert<example, 'bar'> // true
type Result3 = Assert<example, 'test'> // false
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAI4CcCWkDm8C88DkB3cJAGwBNcBuMKORWVDAJmzwCMBDJS6mBZNdAGYWuWAFM43YLACeABzHwxAD3YBbOcUU4A3sHgH4ACzHFi4AFx5CJclUPwAZuEttO3AL5Vp8xQDV2YgBXCQAeABUAPhZwgG0AazEZcEd4cIBdEFkFeABBaGgxJFhQgHlWACslZXFIUmh4ACUxCCRSUP4MABo6BnRInoBpJOra%20vgA4LDyisjonBms3yaJIOJYAEYWfMLi0JV1TTEegiIyXGiAekv4ehCfHOboNdhmHB2ikoONLROOLiuNzuYgeiieL2E7wKn32qh%20xzw4kkgKcgUKIAxQA)

You might have noticed, that I have replaced `interface example` with `type example`. I made it purposely, because I have applied a constraint to `Assert` type. First argument should extend `Record`. `Record` is indexed type whereas `interfaces` in TS are not indexed by the default.
More info you will find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript#answer-64971386) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69962574/define-an-interface-that-is-a-more-concrete-type-in-typescript#answer-69962741)