# Define an interface that is a more concrete type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a type in typescript, that is an object, for which all of the properties should be of type `number`. Based on this type, I would like to create various interfaces, which are more concrete then the original type, and pass them as generic parameters to a class, which excepts a generic that extends my basic type, but I always get the following typescript error:

> Index signature for type 'xxx' is missing in type 'yyy'

Is something similar to what I want to do is possible in typescript? The best I was able to achieve, is telling my `moreConcrete` interface, that it extends the `basic` type, this way, the error goes away, but I lose autocompletion and other intellisense features when trying to use the interface.

Here's a fiddle with an example: [Fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBARghgZwJYGMoF4oG8BQV9QDaA1hCAFxQLABOSAdgOYC6l9ArgLYwQ04C+OHCgA2iBFACCAHgAqASXph2wKBAAewCPQAmE+MhQA+bEMFCGWmgDM4KaJwD2NCAGFH9FC62mCUOGxcPDQANHgEMIHcvALCHtRQWgmY9BAA7lLSTi7unt4QRgAUAJQA3FAA9BWJABZIEjqOEBL0jqppzsRQIkiktfUW9Fa29lBtNbwAss5uHl4QPhpauvqIqL4EAVAc0aHh+JHbQTGCKPGqScAATBjb6ZnjUzO581pFZZXVwHUNTS1tUEYSAAbtA4PQQGoaDRnAg4vQEqBILJmsBKKQQI5rGNvk8cnN8rcAOSIInlKr9CR2exgYBU+n+KAYsbYx40ab4vILCAhWAQFBwdgIaBY2rQJbaZAeRKOKAAAwMqDlvO+9SoNUc7BEOj5-noUJhNCAA)

And here's the code in the fiddle:

```
type basic = {
    [key: string]: number
}

class A<TInput extends basic> {

}

interface moreConcrete {
    a: number,
    b: number
}
const test = new A<moreConcrete>(); // this does not work like this

interface otherMoreConcrete extends basic {
    a: number,
    b: number
}
const test2 = new A<otherMoreConcrete>(); // this does not give any errors
const typeTest: keyof otherMoreConcrete = 'as'; // this accepts as as a key of otherMoreConcrete, because of the extension to `basic`, this should be an error
```

Comment: @kaya3 the usage of the interface is ommited here in the class, as the problem is reproductible without it also. my original `basic` interface is not so simple in the real code neither, this is just to try to show in an easy way the problem I am experiencing. Basically, what I would need, is can I define a type that constraints an interface that is extending that type?

Comment: You could restrict generic parameter of class, so it will error if you'll pass something with non numeric member `class A<T extends Record<keyof T, number>>` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVaBTAHgFxQOwCYwCUVgB7AJ13gGsUBPEgM2kQBppsBXAWwCMUyAfAOgBvAL4AoCQEtsWMgzDAU0LuRQBhEtmBkUWUROjHoYAFztufMiyMmeFzr362T0YBYgYysgOYTJUmwvaCwQgF52FAB3OHg1PS0dPSwBAAoASgBuKVl5RWVoEgwAC34AWXUk3X0VETtjc0tnGwboB2brAIkgkLCMACZoSOwYuOKyskrE7RrUzJzejFDaAAcURBQvCxp6JgmKqtmUlUiAckgzrKA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to better understand this problem, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript#answer-64971386) answer.

**TL;TR**

`interfaces` have no indexing by the default, whereas `types` have.
In order to get rid of an error, just use `type` instead of `interface`. I mean, instead of using:

```js
interface moreConcrete {
    a: number,
    b: number
}
```

use

```js
type moreConcrete= {
    a: number,
    b: number
}
const test = new A<moreConcrete>(); // ok
```

You can find extra examples in my [article](https://catchts.com/safer-types#part_2)

Is this super safe to use `type` instead of `interface` ? I don't think so. It all depends on your code and what you want to achieve. I'm not aware of all edge cases. So, it should be thoroughly tested.

It might be safe to use `type` instead of `interface` in this particular case because `A` class expects indexed type.

As for the second problem:

```js
interface otherMoreConcrete extends basic {
    a: number,
    b: number
}

const test2 = new A<otherMoreConcrete>(); // this does not give any errors
const typeTest: keyof otherMoreConcrete = 'as'; // this accepts as as a key of otherMoreConcrete, because of the extension to `basic`, this should be an error
```

You don't have error here, because there is a big difference between `otherMoreConcrete` interface and `moreConcrete`. `otherMoreConcrete` extends `basic`. It means that it has indexed property. I mean apart from having `a` and `b` it accepts any string key.

```js
type otherMoreConcrete = {
    [x: string]: string;
    a: "a";
    b: "b";
}
```

Hence, if you want to trigger en error in your last example, just use `type` instead of `interface`:

```js
type basic = {
    [key: string]: number
}

class A<TInput extends basic> {}


type moreConcrete = {
    a: number,
    b: number
}
const test = new A<moreConcrete>(); // ok

type otherMoreConcrete = {
    a: number,
    b: number
}


const test2 = new A<otherMoreConcrete>(); // ok
const typeTest: keyof otherMoreConcrete = 'as'; // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBARghgZwJYGMoF4oG8BQV9QDaA1hCAFxQLABOSAdgOYC6l9ArgLYwQ04C%20OHCgA2iBFACCAHgAqASXph2wKBAAewCPQAmE%20MhQA%20bIKGhIUTgHsaEAMLX6KO1ozY8BOGy48aAGk98GB9uXgFhJ2ooLWjMeggAdylpGztHZ1cIIwAKAEoAbigAemKoa2JzcGhrYAALXgBZWwcnFwg3TFwCKG8oDjCAoNhQvwihFCjVWOAAJncE5Jlahppm9Las3MKSsorI%20miLCFkIakpSEGsAM3L6ppaM9s6oAHJEV6LStRoaWyA)