# Typescript extract type of nested object in template type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

I have the following type:

```
type field_<T> =
    {
        value: T;
        error:
            {
                error: boolean;
                message: string;
            }
        visited: boolean;
        validate: (value: T) => boolean;
    }
```

and a form that contains all the fields:

```
interface form_model_
{
    firstName: field_<string>;
    lastName: field_<string>;
}
```

etc..

I would like to collect all the `value` fields in a way similar to:

```
type value_type<form_model_interface_> = {
    [key_ in keyof form_model_interface_]: ?*?;
}
```

what would replace the **?*?** or is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two options.

First one with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```js
type field_<T> =
    {
        value: T;
        error:
        {
            error: boolean;
            message: string;
        }
        visited: boolean;
        validate: (value: T) => boolean;
    }

interface form_model_ {
    firstName: field_<string>;
    lastName: field_<string>;
}

type value_type<form_model_interface_> = {
    [key_ in keyof form_model_interface_]: form_model_interface_[key_] extends field_<any> ? form_model_interface_[key_]['value'] : never
}

// type Result = {
//     firstName: string;
//     lastName: string;
// }
type Result = value_type<form_model_>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAv5RW)

Second one with appropriate constraint for `form_model_interface_` generic in `value_type`. Please keep in mind that in this case you need to define `form_model_` as a `type` instead of `interface` because `type` [is indexed by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript#answer-64971386)

```js
type field_<T> =
    {
        value: T;
        error:
        {
            error: boolean;
            message: string;
        }
        visited: boolean;
        validate: (value: T) => boolean;
    }

type form_model_ = {
    firstName: field_<string>;
    lastName: field_<string>;
}

type value_type<form_model_interface_ extends Record<string, field_<any>>> = {
    [key_ in keyof form_model_interface_]: form_model_interface_[key_]['value']
}

// type Result = {
//     firstName: string;
//     lastName: string;
// }
type Result = value_type<form_model_>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpvOaw)

Be aware, that there is naming convention in typescript. All types should be Capitalized and CamelCased. So `field_` should be written as `Field`.