# Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Object'.ts(2322)

Tags: typescript, interface

I want to assign my custom object to JsonObject efied in Prisma package. this code generates error that I don't know why:

```
interface JsonArray extends Array<JsonValue> {}
type JsonValue = string | number | boolean | JsonObject | JsonArray | null
type JsonObject = {[Key in string]?: JsonValue}
// ^ These are defined in Prisma package and I cannot change them

interface Object {
  name: string
}

let object : Object
let jsonObject : JsonObject 

// This line has error
jsonObject = object;

// Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'JsonObject'.
// The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types.
// Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
// Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Object'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't name your custom object type `Object`. Type `Object` is built in type for `Object` value. It may confuse people. I'm not sure whether you want to update existing `Object` type or you want just to create some custom type, it is important for interfaces because of [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

consider this example:

```js
interface JsonArray extends Array<JsonValue> { }

type JsonValue = string | number | boolean | JsonObject | JsonArray | null

type JsonObject = { [Key in string]?: JsonValue }

interface CustomObject {
    name: string
}

declare let object: CustomObject
declare let jsonObject: JsonObject

// This line has error
jsonObject = object;
```

The error you have means that `jsonObject` is indexed. In other words it means that you can use any string to access the object values.
For instance:

```js
jsonObject['hello'] // ok
```

Whereas it is not true for `object`. In `object` case you are allowed to use only `name` key to access appropriate value. You are not allowed to use `hello`.

```js
object['hello'] // error
```

Now, imagine the situation where TS allows you to do this operation:

```js
jsonObject = object;

jsonObject['hello'] // undefined, because  it has only `name` property
```

SO if you want to make it assignable you should add indexing to your `CustomObject`:

```js
interface CustomObject {
    [prop: string]: JsonValue
    name: number
}
```

Or, what is more interesting use `type` keyword for declaring `CustomObject` instead of `interface`:

```js
interface JsonArray extends Array<JsonValue> { }

type JsonValue = string | number | boolean | JsonObject | JsonArray | null

type JsonObject = { [Key in string]?: JsonValue }

type CustomObject= {
    name: number
}

declare let object: CustomObject
declare let jsonObject: JsonObject

jsonObject = object; // no error

jsonObject.name
```

Yes, there is a difference in terms of indexing between `interface` and `type`. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript#answer-64971386) and [article](https://catchts.com/safer-types#part_2)

Please keep in mind that this operation is allowed:

```js
jsonObject['hello'] // undefined but allowed
```

There is no compiler error but it is unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here.

- `Object` is a built-in javascript data type. You should name your interface something else, e.g. `MyObject`,
- You are declaring a variable `object` but it is not initialised, i.e. it doesn't have any value. You cannot use it in operation like `x = object`,
- Your interface does not fully overlap with `JsonObject`. You can either modify the interface or use `type`.

```
interface JsonArray extends Array<JsonValue> {}
type JsonValue = string | number | boolean | JsonObject | JsonArray | null
type JsonObject = {[Key in string]?: JsonValue}
// ^ These are defined in Prisma package and I cannot change them

type MyObject = {
  name: string
}

let anObject: MyObject = {name: "foo"}
let jsonObject: JsonObject 

// no error
jsonObject = anObject
```

Try it in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgFIGcD2ICCUpwCeyEAHpCACbrJ4GEA8G2AanADYCuEAfMgN4BfAFBhCABxTMQbLigC8ydGCigA5sgA+yEJwC2AI2hbkBzJnYQ4IE9IDyBgFYQEYW1lz4iJ3e3aiJKQ8HZ1dkRX4AbQBpCGJQJRV1AF0AfgAuNA9ZbhEAejzkAD1kABUACwh0FDgoFEoIGFAISmQEgAVVdD04ZHFEAGs4NRqqZABJZARrEEw3BHLrEeQwSr1hAMlkAFlCEJc3COFkHTg9CEzlVRA1YRFhSzdrfddM3ZfDgRAzi+QAIhg5j+IkeyEcwScB0y9khYQ2BR0mBI+EwUGE4OwH3CyGesLAQA).