# error: Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'NonNullable<T[keyof T]>'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript

I defined a method called **filterByFront**

```
export const filterByFront = <T>(
  value: string,
  jsonData: T[],
  setData: (data: T[]) => void,
  filterKey: keyof T
) => {
  const originData = jsonData;
  if (!!value && !!value.trim()) {
    setData(originData);
  } else {
    const filterData = originData.filter((item) => {
      const newFilterValue = item[filterKey];
      return newFilterValue
        ?.toLowerCase()    //error message shows in this line 
        ?.includes(value.trim().toLowerCase());
    });

    setData(filterData);
  }
};
```

and i called it in components like this

```
   <Input.Search
            key="filter_role"
            placeholder={t('common.filter')}
            onSearch={(value) =>
              filterByFront<IRoleListItem>(value, jsonData, setRoleData, 'id')
            }
          />,
```

the type definition

```
export interface IRoleListItem {
  authority?: string;

  id?: string;

  privilege?: string;

  prohibit?: string;

  tag_list?: string;
}
```

it shows error :

> Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'NonNullable<T[keyof
> T]>'.ts(2339)

How can I make this error disappeared

Comment: Try `filterByFront = <T extends {toLowerCase: ()=>string}>(...)=>{...}`

Comment: Please try to share minimum reproducible example. There is no way somebody can reproduce this error. I think you can get rid of react hooks/handlers in your question

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-sun-w63jew?file=/src/utils.ts  this is  minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this restriction `T extends Record<PropertyKey, { toLowerCase: () => string }>`:

```js
export const filterByFront = <T extends Record<PropertyKey, { toLowerCase: () => string }>>(
  value: string,
  jsonData: T[],
  filterKey: keyof T
) => {
  const originData = jsonData;
  if (!!value && !!value.trim()) {
    console.log(originData);
  } else {
    const filterData = originData.filter((item) => {
      const newFilterValue = item[filterKey];
      return newFilterValue
        ?.toLowerCase()
        ?.includes(value.trim().toLowerCase());
    });

    console.log(filterData);
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WG509N)

Comment: I don't think this works. If you add OP's usage of the function, you get an error about a missing index signature: [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wgX3MN). I think it might be necessary to do a runtime check rather than using a generic constraint? e.g. [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYv1bw)

Comment: @Jimmy good point. However, if OP  using interface, they might not need even generic parameter. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/NnQjVw)

Comment: Thanks ,it worked as @jimmy said ,but generic parameter is still needed I think,because this is a public metods,the jsonData passed may have other type

Comment: I think in this case @Jimmy should provide their answer. Also it worth mentioning that there is a difference between interfaces and types in terms of indexing, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript#answer-64971386). If you use `type IRoleListItem` instead of `interface IRoleListItem` it will work

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the issue is that `T` has no constraints, so we can't assume that it will have a property called `toLowerCase`. As captain-yossarian notes in the comments on their answer, types created with `type` have an implicit index signature, while types created with `interface` do not. If you are able to define your role list item type using `type`, their solution should work. If not, you might need to do a runtime check to see if `T` is a string before you can proceed to treat it as one:

```js
export interface IRoleListItem {
  authority?: string;
  id?: string;
  privilege?: string;
  prohibit?: string;
  tag_list?: string;
}

export const filterByFront = <T, K extends keyof T>(
  value: string,
  jsonData: T[],
  setData: (data: T[]) => void,
  filterKey: K
) => {
  const originData = jsonData;
  if (!!value && !!value.trim()) {
    setData(originData);
  } else {
    const filterData = originData.filter((item) => {
      const newFilterValue = item[filterKey];

      if (typeof newFilterValue === "string") {
        return newFilterValue?.toLowerCase()?.includes(value.trim().toLowerCase());
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });

    setData(filterData);
  }
};

declare const value: string;
declare const jsonData: IRoleListItem[];
declare const setRoleData: (data: IRoleListItem[]) => {};

filterByFront(value, jsonData, setRoleData, 'id');
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQCUIAbYAGQQGcZ9UBbOAbwCg45MBXGAC2gRgBPAPwAuODSjIA5gG42iACZiJMKUjkKwUgG4Iy04Cskz57bRB4IARgONrTCmJmkB9EtRj31mgL4sWUEhYOGwIJBo4dH1UKAAhQQAxKHD4AF44AB4AFQAaOABpOFBUJEUqOABrYEEIdDhsgD4ACgUdTBJOYHETDVyFACsqcIARTGdxbIBtAF1+9ipgGDGJuGbFccxJ2YBKODTGuB0IBEV5qJi0AprxApY9g+YFMIj4fmlkFcx9uCHRzbMiHqzQAhCD2p08AAyKFwMEQroAOgc9GaOz2rHYCyWX2a70+mx2gN8xRIiyeWNC4Ui0RIsS+P3xSC+iNpsWazQEwHoD0OmMpVNecCQwAA7olLlAAGodLo-Ln0KZsq41GbyBSUhDAoRgYB1YViiV0tAyyH7NIZABEvWkloxGoFUCWnCgSAN4slpq6wmREHIEFFaAAwphFmifchsJ1FMAqM0EcBkVJUTtff7A1AQ2H0YDKSTgGS8PyBXAnTAXW6sIXc1j-HmiQFKYtlptmsqoF8G+x-L51TGo5gnYLIgmeg4NPJ+yRB3gXpE-szNuIiKQKJ46NzZpPgAOh3P4M3iGQvuJ1kuCEe1zQN4qZrzmL2Au2EslUvHZcB8guvvlD6uf3AADkpyAUSQA)