# Is there a way to "enchant" a class with a type?

Tags: typescript

Say I have a simple class `class Foo {}`. Under the hood with some Javascript magic, I know that a `Foo` object can do much more than it appears to be, which is complex enough that it cannot be expressed with an interface, but possibly with a type:

```js
interface Bar { /* ... */ }
type Processor<T> = (value: T) => void;
type FooEx = { [K in keyof Bar as `${K & string}Processor`]: Processor<K> }
```

Is there a way I can say `Foo` "implements" `FooEx`, so I can use any `Foo` object as a `FooEx`? I know I can always cast/wrap it, but ideally I'd like to have it by using `new Foo()` and it should work out of the box.

Edit:

I'm sorry but the example above has oversimplified my question, which can be easily achieved by writing:

```js
class Foo implements FooEx {}
```

so here is a more complex example:

```js
type Processor<T> = (value: T) => void;
type FooEx<T> = { [K in keyof T as `${K & string}Processor`]: Processor<K> }
```

Now, this does not work:

```js
class Foo<T> implements FooEx<T> {}
                        ~~~~~~~~
// Error: A class can only implement an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.ts(2422)
```

Comment: you can extend types with `&` if that what you mean.  here is some examples https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-extend-type

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen I understand I can say `Foo & FooEx`, but what I want to achieve is, whenever I `new Foo()`, I get an object of type `Foo & FooEx` automatically.

Comment: `class Foo implements FooEx {}`?

Comment: Looks like can use implements with type as long as its not a Union type https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682220/1805974

Comment: Thanks @catgirlkelly that indeed works for the example I provided initially, but the example was an oversimplification of my problem. Please check out my edit.