# How to convert custom interface to Record<string, unknown>?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following sample code

```
interface MyInterface { foo: string; }

function doSomethingWith(x: Record<string, unknown>) { /* ... */ }

const myInterface: MyInterface = { foo: 'bar' };

doSomethingWith(myInterface);
```

It is not possible to pass the variable to the function because

> Argument of type 'MyInterface' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, unknown>'.
> Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'MyInterface'.(2345)

I solved the problem by converting the variable

`const myInterfaceAsRecord = (myInterface as unknown) as Record<string, unknown>;`

and would like to know if there are any "better" ways to pass in the interface to the function?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `type` instead `interface`

```js
type MyInterface = { foo: string; }

function doSomethingWith(x: Record<string, unknown>) { /* ... */ }

const myInterface: MyInterface = { foo: 'bar' };

doSomethingWith(myInterface);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript#answer-64971386) for more context

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to extend the interface from the record:

```js
interface MyInterface extends Record<string, unknown> { foo: string; }

function doSomethingWith(x: Record<string, unknown>) { /* ... */ }

const myInterface: MyInterface = { foo: 'bar' };

doSomethingWith(myInterface);
```