# Is there a way to define a type excludes Function from Record<string, any>?

Tags: typescript, frontend

I have a collector function like

```
const track = (data: Record<string, any>) => {
  //...
}
```

and some data generators like

```
const genData = () => ({
  name: 'x'
})
```

Currently the `track` function could accept `genData()` and `genData` as parameter without warning, and it is likely to make some mistakes.

So how to throw warning when accept a Function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only allow objects but don't know the type of the values, you can use `Record<string, unknown>`.

```
const track = (data: Record<string, unknown>) => {}

track(genData)
// Error: Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type '() => { name: string; }'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBDYBrGBeGAKAJoqiAXDAEoCmo8OAPNPAJZgDmANDAK5gpggDuYAPgCUGATADeAKBgxQkEABsyAOgUgmufImWIhkgL6TJc6DCZkwAES0ZsI9GKxSZYRAFsyxAOQAPLwb1JBGQULHMrLSEgA)

Comment: Nice approach with `unknown`

Comment: Sadly, this breaks when using `interface` :( https://tsplay.dev/mxD57m

Comment: THis is because interfaces don't have indexing by the default whereas `types` have.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript#answer-64971386)

Answer (score 2):

You can apply validator which forbids an argument if it will be a function:

```js
type NotFn<T extends Record<string, any>> =
    T extends (...args: any[]) => any ? never : T

const track = <
    Data extends Record<string, any>
>(data: NotFn<Data>) => { }

const genData = () => ({
    name: 'x'
})

track(genData)
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wz5o1m)

You can find more information about TS negation in my [article](https://catchts.com/type-negation)