# Why a same type will error when use interface and will not when using type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I hear that `type` and `interface` only have different when you want using things like `&` or `extends`, but......

Why

```
interface ITest {
  a: boolean;
}
const Itest: ITest = { a: true };
const test: { [index: string]: boolean } = Itest;
```

cant pass compile, while

```
type TTest = {
  a: boolean,
};
const Ttest: TTest = { a: true };
const test: { [index: string]: boolean } = Ttest;
```

have not?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript#answer-64971386) answer. The difference in indexing. Interfaces are not indexed by the default (tis makes them safer), whereas `types` are indexed.  Also, see [my article](https://catchts.com/safer-types#part_2) about using `types` and `interfaces`

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are basically a way to describe data shapes, for example, an object. Type is a definition of a type of data, for example, a union, primitive, intersection, tuple, or any other type.

There is an object definition here, so Interface must be used.

My personal opinion: Try to use Interface as much as possible instead of Type.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question as asked.  A type alias can indeed be an object type, as shown above via `type Test = {a: boolean}`.  What do you mean by "Interface must be used"?  The underlying issue has to do with implicit index signatures and is discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300), and this answer doesn't seem to apply.