# Property does not exist on interface in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am pretty new to React but with some Angular attempts before.

I was actually trying to implement a component which accepts a data model or object as parameter

Looks like this

```
import react from 'react'

interface SmbListItem{
    index:number;
    primary:string;
    secondary:string;
}
   

export default function SmbList({props}:SmbListItem){
    return(
        <>

        </>
    );
}
```

But its saying props does not exists on SmbListItem

What I did wrong?

Also requesting a suggestion on interface or types are the best option in this situation

Comment: you define `interface props` called `SmbListItem`. this is how your `SmbList props` looks like, when `destructuring` you should only mention the `key` among `interface props`

Answer (score 2):

```
import react from 'react'

interface SmbListItem{
    index:number;
    primary:string;
    secondary:string;
}
   

export default function SmbList({index, primary, secondary}:SmbListItem){
    return(
        <>

        </>
    );
}
```

There is no such `props` defined in your `Interface Props`

Even if you are not using `Ts`and you are sure about the `props` you would `destructure` your `props` like this

```
export default function SmbList({index, primary, secondary}){
    return(
        <></>
    );
}
```

For Your Second Question Have a look into [Types vs Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. But my confusion is if I have 10 properties in that interface, do I need to specify all those? Instead of accept it as a single object??

Comment: @SandeepThomas it's depend what kind of interface you are buidling, you can extract reusable `property`, you can merge two `interface` etc etc,
`Advanced Types, Generic TS` resolve to many code duplication , and provide dynamic typescripting

Answer (score 1):

###### Hi @Sandeep Thomas,

First, You are trying to `destructure` the `props` parameter in the function definition, but you are not passing any props to the function. In that case, You need to use `generic type` function for that case.

If you're new to `react-typescirpt` world. Then, You need to read this first:- [**TypeScript Docs**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

###### In short note:-

> A generic type is a type that allows you to define a type or function with one or more placeholder types that can be filled in with specific types when the generic is used.

I found an good example for that:-

```js
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg;
}

let numberIdentity = identity(5);  // numberIdentity is of type number
let stringIdentity = identity("hello");  // stringIdentity is of type string
```

Here is example with your code:-

```js
export default function SmbList<T extends SmbListItem>({ props }: T) {
    return <>// You code...</>;
}
```

The `props` parameter is of a type that extends the `SmbListItem` interface.