# Merging custom type with one from external library in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-types

I have a type in an external library that looks like this:

```
export declare type CreateProductInput = {
    title: string;
}
```

I want this type to have another attribute so tried to add to it in my own `index.d.ts` file:

I have tried the following:

```
export declare type CreateProductInput = {
    subtitle: string;
}
```

But that did not work. I also tried the following:

```
declare module '@path/to/library/type/file' {
    declare interface CreateProductInput {
        subtitle: string;
    }
}
```

However, doing this overwrites the type completely and I no longer have access to the `title` field.

Can one merge types like this? Basically, I want to modify the original type by adding another property to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to stick with `type` then you should be able to do this even on an imported type:

```js
type a = {
    title: string
}

type b = a & {
    subtitle: string
}

const c: b = {
    title: "title",
    subtitle: "subtitle"
}

console.log(c)
```

The other option would be to use an interface:

```js
type d = {
    title: string
}

interface e extends d  {
    subtitle: string
}

const f: e = {
    title: "title",
    subtitle: "subtitle"
}

console.log(f)
```

Check out both in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=15&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDeAoK6rAJbADYQC4oBnYAJywDsBzFAXxRVEigCMFYoAyZNDYgK6tseQiXJVaDFAGMA9pVJQZRdolQZMOfEQBEI-LoA0fdIOHaxu8wYi76jeYrn4AdLjnUAFDICUjZmgAEw4NDFsiUgoaBxQqYAgyADMYGWh0gA8EyiDiKBDeTRtLSIkY6SclJKJodVMtUT1bY3rixqhrIWbYypcId08vJN8gA). What you want to do with overwriting the type the way you're trying to do so isn't possible and is poor form. Create a new type/interface that has what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) cannot be [*merged*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces). That is one of the differences with an [interface declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) in TypeScript.

But you can create a new interface that *extends* a type, although this does not seem what you want here:

```
type CreateProductInput = {
    title: string;
}

interface CreateProductInput2 extends CreateProductInput  {
    subtitle: string;
}

declare const test: CreateProductInput2;

test.title; // Okay
test.subtitle;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgThAhsCAFOB7AJgVwMbACSAdmDsFALxQDeAUFI1MAJbAA2EAXFAM7BwWxAOYBuOgF86dISjgAzRHmjwkKdNnxFS5AExQIADxTEsvWAmRpMuAiTIV6TPjgBGrDtz4ChYydKwIPHZEBCg8DGJ+Zgh+HlUrDVttB11xOhR+ADoPTlEoAHoCqAB5AGtEEAzY4CzeN1yIcSA)

For more details, see e.g. [Interfaces vs Types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript)