# Difference between Record<A, B> and {[key: A]: B}

Tags: typescript

What is the difference between the types A and B?

```js
type A = {[key: string]: string | number | boolean | null}
type B = Record<string, string | number | boolean | null>
```

Comment: On the face of it, there is no difference, yet I had a situation this week where the `Record` variant triggered a "nesting is excessively deep" error and the indexed type did not.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen you can check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript#answer-64971386), the second part. THis is because interfaces are eagerly evaluated whereas types not. This syntax `[key: string]` is aka `interface` indexing

Comment: Could you [edit] the title to say `Record<string, B>` vs `{[key: string]: B}`?  Or maybe edit the question to indicate that `string` is just an example and you want to understand the difference in general?  It has an effect on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference in indexing. When you use `Record`, you can use a union of string:

```js
// ok
type B = Record<'a' | 'b', string | number | boolean | null>;

// error
type A = { [key: 'a' | 'b']: string | number | boolean | null };


// works :D
type A_1 = { [key: `a${string}` | `$b${string}`]: string | number | boolean | null };
```

But you are not able to use unions in aka `interface` indexing (see type A).

Please see [Symbol and Template String Pattern Index Signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures) to better understanding why `A_1` works

Answer (score 1):

In general, type A and type B are functionally equivalent and represent object types with arbitrary string keys and values that can be string, number, boolean, or null.

**The difference lies in the syntax used to define them, with type A using index signature syntax and type B using the Record utility type.**

Answer (score 1):

There is no functional difference. Though generally the `Record` type can be quite a bit easier for humans to read.

The `Record` utility type is built into TypeScript, but it doesn't require any special syntax or anything to define it. It's simply a shorthand, and you can find its source definition within TypeScript's `lib.es5.d.ts` file:

```js
/**
 * Construct a type with a set of properties K of type T
 */
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
};
```

If you were to hover over your type `B` in an IDE with TypeScript support, including the TypeScript Playground, you will see that it gets transformed to this:

```js
// type B = Record<string, string | number | boolean | null>
type B = {
    [x: string]: string | number | boolean | null;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQlC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwDwGdhMBLAOwHMAaKQkiqAHylIFcBbAIwk0ag-XQAbCAENSvVoMEA+IA)

Which is identical to your type definition of `A`.