# How to make Object.fromEntries() return exact typings?

Tags: javascript, typescript

[Find my current (non-working) code in the following playground please](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwLIE8CiL0DeAUHHABIDyAqgEoD6FAcjnALxwDkltDzHANCTgARAIIBNXi3YcxkpjgFCMTACpkpbTisbqpSgL5EioSLAT44FGAAtgUPGjjFSFdTnoAFGhU8fV8sxaHG5kHnTevv6BioKu7l4%20fjQBdKoA6hTBoeGRyakZFBxERkQAlogw9gBmAIYAxsBwNBAA7s5CAG61ADbIwABccADWwFgQ1XAwWGDAE5i4lgA%20I2Pz07Pz1nYO%20HFTEDC9Q-gARvYlxhVVUHWNcKq1pz3AeDBQWB2kpDBlqMB0VrQUYAExOaHOUH2pEOOzoYCgEFmsCwdAgiEGcDO9mhcFh9nhiOR0zoMCB4NQkMuRA2TVUUFqiAAztVoP8QZ4ifZfsAmVpRuNJp4yvVhgAeR7PV6VD78Ti-f6A4HAEHFFYcfFQQlI7mo9HANWcTXa4moskQDgAPmM9XRTPgMAg9MZLLZKs5OpRjFq-y0AApun1MS1WgBtDiB-ocAC6AEohs7mayoOyPcSyry2JavkzWmUYPUbHAA71%20rGvt9SPVakymthHKgAHTcegKAZCSvV2sLBuNuRSduVqs1uuLNCNnR6NsdodQYAwZBQRDyv4AoFQUHFIdwEHAOrIHowQfbuBzhdLuCR4CNx0AGTa9gAwiO-eWaw8GUm3RyubAM0yZyMUoAHpgPINoDimGYmlsMo%20QAfkQohQLgUQHTsOBUAgf5KlPedF2ZOAhgIUNhiGe0oAqABzaMKUhIwUIASTgVpGXgfNILPAidywRAfRFOBrnsQMWPzItbCaSiqJsB1P1dFMVTgBFPWmLEfWAIhbWZWSXWTdB2D9RFWiZIYQ1DOMswrUguIvChTgAK2AeoYEbapEVQN5KN5Qy2iZRtUFqMBDMs0NHUTeTU1-aZvX%20QzGyvWM5SgG9Dl6ONYyEAwgA)

Currently `Object.fromEntries` returns `{[k: string]: number}` dynamically, but I'd like it to be typed. It would have to return a type with exactly the keys returned by `TransformedProperties` method and `number` type for the value.

This way, when I call the `transform` method, it knows that the type is for example:

```js
{
  time_worked: 10,
  other_property_one: 1,
  other_property_two: 0,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your just going to have to cast here, `Object.entries` is dynamic in nature, but if your sure that these props will exist, that shouldn't be a problem.

First though, I would change your `TableEntry` into a type, it's practically the same as an interface, but you will get less issues using a type.

```
type TableEntry = {
    time_worked: number,
    other_property_one: number,
    other_property_two: number
}
```

Then you can cast the return into `TableEntry`

```
const transform = (rows: Row[]) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(rows.map(r => 
    [toTransformedPropertyName(r.value), r.total])) as TableEntry
}
```

[Updated TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.2.0-beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwLIE8CiL0DeAUHHABIDyAqgEoD6FAcjnALxwDkltDzHANCTgARAIIBNXi3YcxkpjgFCMTACpkpbTisbqpSgL5EioSLAT44FGAAtgUPGjjFSFdTnoAFGhU8fV8sxaHG5kHnTevv6BioKu7l4%20fjQBdKoA6hTBoeGRyakZFBxERkQAlogw9gBmAIYAxsBwNBAA7s5CAG61ADbIwABccADWwFgQ1XAwWGDAE5i4lgA%20I2Pz07Pz1nYO%20HFTEDC9Q-gARvYlxhtNqrWnPcB4MFBYWi6kU2WowHSt0KMAExOaHOUH2pEOOzoYCgEFmsCwdAgiEGcDO9nBcEh9mhsPh0zoMD%20wNQoMuRGucFUUFqiAAztVoN8AZ48fYYGVgHStKNxpNPGV6sMADy3e6PSovficDnfX7-YAA4orDjYqC4uHsxHI4DKzhqjX4xFEiAcAB8xnqyLp8BgEGptIZTMVrM1CMYtW%20WgAFN0%20qiWq0ANocP39DgAXQAlEMHfTGVBma78ZzuawzR04HTWmUYPUbHBfb1%20lHMx9SPVanSmthHKgAHTcegKAZCcuV6sLOv1uRSVvlitVmuLND1nR6FttgdQYAwZBQRAyr4-P5QQHFAdwAHAOrIHowfubuAzucLuBh4D1u0AGTa9gAwkPvaWq1SafHnSy2bBU1OjKUAHoAPINoDimGYmlsMpuQAfjgoggLgURbTsOBUAgb5KmPWd53pOAhgIINhiGG0oAqABzCMSVBIxEIASTgVpaXgXMwJPXCtywRBPUFOAKiqKA-UY3MC1sJoyPImxbXfJ1E0VOAYTdaY0U9YAiCtelpMdBN0HYb1YVaOkhkDINozYDN3lIdizwoU4ACtgHqGB62qWFUCeMiuX0to6XrVBajAfTzLgIM7TjWSk2-aYPW%20fT6wvKNpSgK9Dl6aMX25MUHg8rASjgK4ZJ071TKjesDUUo0kRRIA)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll try. What is the advantage to use a type here over an interface please? I use interface a lot in my app actually.

Comment: @Jedupont  You could check this out -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript   Don't worry you don't need to convert all your interfaces to types, you can replace as required.   If you try the playground I updated, and put back to interface you will see the issue it causes here.