# How to declare objects whose keys are unrestricted and values are arrays?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, interface

I would like to have a list of objects whose:

- keys are unrestricted and unique for each object
- values are string arrays

For example:

```js
const obj1 = {
    'animals': ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'],
    'fruits': ['apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'kiwi', 'grape']
}
const obj2 = {
    'name': ['Einstein', 'Hitler'],
    'country': ['Nigeria', 'Afganistan', 'Vietnam', 'Egypt']
}
```

How do I declare them?

Comment: you can do this by defining interface with an index signature that allow for unrestricted keys and enforces that the values are string arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COnsider this approach:

```js
interface A {
  [prop: string]: Lowercase<string>[]
}

const obj1: A = {
  'animals': ['Cat', 'dog', 'mouse'], // expected error
  'fruits': ['apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'kiwi', 'grape']
}

type B = Record<string, Capitalize<string>[]>

const obj2: B = {
  'name': ['Einstein', 'doe'], // expected error
  'country': ['Nigeria', 'Afganistan', 'Vietnam', 'Egypt']
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wga5bm)

`Lowercase` and `Capitalize` are string utility helpers to assure that each string value should match some pattern

---

**Question**: Why `A` is an `interface` and `B` is a `type` ?

**Answer**: There is a big difference between types and interfaces in terms of indexing.
See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript#answer-64971386) and my [article](https://catchts.com/safer-types#part_2). Use `interface` when you want to have more strict rules about object type shape.

Comment: wow, you notice the pattern that I don't even aware of :D. Anyway, why is A interface and B type? Why don't you use one same for both?