# How to solve dynamic typing problem using TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement a generic table component.

The idea is that when the component is used elsewhere, it will be possible to view all remaining props that can be assigned to the component.

For example, by default I set the props below. But you can customize the component using several props that the table component receives:

```
<MantineDataTable
      withTableBorder
      withColumnBorders
      highlightOnHover
      loaderType="oval"
      loaderSize="sm"
      loaderBackgroundBlur={1}
      fetching={isLoading}
      records={records}
      rowStyle={() => (theme) => ({
        fontSize: !mediumScreen ? theme.fontSizes.sm : theme.fontSizes.xs,
      })}
      columns={columns}
      {...rest}
    />
```

But I'm not able to get Intelisense to identify the props that you can add to the component to customize it.

I have the following typing error:

```
An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.
```

On this type:

```
interface DataTableProps<T, TRecords> extends MantineDataTableProps<T> {
  records: TRecords[];
  columns: DataTableColumn<TRecords>[];
  isLoading?: boolean;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/staging-dew-jwcfw4?file=%2Fsrc%2FDataTable.tsx%3A25%2C5-39%2C7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into a limitation of interfaces due to generic use. You can fix it by using a type alias instead:

```
type DataTableProps<T, TRecords> = MantineDataTableProps<T> & {
  records: TRecords[],
  columns: DataTableColumn<TRecords>[],
  isLoading?: boolean,
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/staging-dew-forked-6m6qd3?file=%2Fsrc%2FDataTable.tsx%3A12%2C2)

> [A class can implement an interface or type alias, both in the same exact way. Note however that a class and interface are considered static blueprints. Therefore, they can not implement / extend a type alias that names a union type.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript/52682220#52682220)