# What is the difference between interface and type?

Tags: typescript

When a generic type does extends check. Type and interface have different behaviors.

Typescript playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8BQUNQNoEsB2AJhAB5QBcAzsAE74DmAumXgK4C2ARhNepgIZkorTt1QBfVKnzBuAMz4BjaAEk8M6vKUpeGAUPZceE1KEhQAglCRwzJGYQpQAShAUB7agQA8VWnjoANPoi1AB8UAD8UDQs0ILyADYU0AD0KTEQJvBQAEJWUKrqmtB2EA7Orh7evvRBwobhURnkUInJUGltmUA

1, Why it throws the error?

2, What is the difference between interface and type?

> The question [Interfaces vs Types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript) doesn't explain my question.