Difference when passing type or interface to function
I want to define a type for JSON values in TypeScript (on version 5.4.3), which may look something like this:
export type JsonPrimitive = string | number | boolean | Date | null;

export type JsonObject = {
    [key: string]: JsonPrimitive | JsonObject | JsonArray;
};

export type JsonArray = (JsonPrimitive | JsonObject | JsonArray)[];

Now I have a function which expects such a JsonObject. When I call the function it seems to make a difference if I call it with an interface or a type. More precisely:
function myFunc(jsonObject: JsonObject): void {
  // ... some implementation
}

interface MyInterface {
  value1: string;
  value2: string;
}

type MyType = {
  value1: string;
  value2: string;
}

const myInterface: MyInterface = {value1: '', value2: ''};
const myType: MyType = {value1: '', value2: ''};

// this works without error
myFunc(myType);
// this does not work, "Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type MyInterface"
myFunc(myInterface);

Playground
This does not make sense to me. What is the difference between type and interface that prevents  the passing of interface here?

This is by design (see microsoft/TypeScript#15300). interfaces can be augmented by additional declarations but type aliases can't. Does that answer your question? If so, I'll write up an answer or find a suitable duplicate.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript

@Behemoth Yes, that thread is perfect, thanks a lot! Do what you prefer, if you want to write up an answer I'll accept it

Also worth noting that although JSON.stringify will serialize Date objects as ISO 8601 timestamps there's no date type in JSON....

First, there are quite a few differences between interfaces and type aliases. You can take a look at Interfaces vs Types in TypeScript for some very good explanations.
The specific issue (microsoft/TypeScript#15300) you ran into is intentional behavior and is consciously by design. It is considered to be safer to infer  implicit index signatures for type aliases than for interfaces. Meaning MyType is assignable to JsonObject because it is inferred with the index signature whereas MyInterface is not (unless you explicitly define it) and therefore produces a compiler error.
The reason is that an interface can be extended with declaration merging while a type alias cannot. Yes, a type alias can be augmented with intersection types too but you can't do something like this:
type MyType = {
  // ~~~~~~~~~ Duplicate identifier 'MyType'.
  value1: string;
};

type MyType = {
  // ~~~~~~~~~ Duplicate identifier 'MyType'.
  value2: string;
};


If you really wanted to use an interface for whatever reason you can create a shallow copy of the original value. Then TypeScript infers the new literal value and no longer MyInterface.
myFunc({...myInterface});

TypeScript Playground
