# typescript interface require one of two properties to exist

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an interface that could have

```
export interface MenuItem {
  title: string;
  component?: any;
  click?: any;
  icon: string;
}
```

1. Is there a way to require `component` or `click` to be set
2. Is there a way to require that both properties can't be set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript Interface - Possible to make "one or the other" properties required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688318/typescript-interface-possible-to-make-one-or-the-other-properties-required)

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Not with a single interface, since types have no conditional logic and can't depend on each other, but you can by splitting the interfaces:

```
export interface BaseMenuItem {
  title: string;
  icon: string;
}

export interface ComponentMenuItem extends BaseMenuItem {
  component: any;
}

export interface ClickMenuItem extends BaseMenuItem {
    click: any;
}

export type MenuItem = ComponentMenuItem | ClickMenuItem;
```

Comment: Interesting.  I have never exported a "type" before.  So it simply means MenuItem can be one or the other ?

Comment: I like this better than the one I did below.  Link that helped me understand "type" http://stackoverflow.com/a/36783051/256793

Comment: Yes: TS has `AND` and `OR` operators for its types. If you're doing something like this, the OR can be nice to give you a single collected name after declaring a bunch of individual types.

Comment: and if you do it *just* right, the compiler may be able to infer which of the types you mean and narrow things correctly. Even if not, the compiler *will* verify the type you're passing meets at least one of the requirements.

Comment: Hi guys, how do you force to choose between one of the interfaces, but not both? With that type, an object with both `component` and `click`  wont make an error...

Comment: @DanielRamos you can add `click?: never` on `ComponentMenuItem` and `component?: never` on `ClickMenuItem`.

Comment: @daniel i think that‘s because of this bug in typescript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863

Comment: mmmmm and how am I supposed to implement a type? The point of making an interface is to make sure that the class will have certain methods and properties. In brief, I want my class to have whether one property or another, but there must be at least one of them. How do I do that?

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing w/ just PropTypes for a project that doesn't have typescript?

Comment: I am getting only title and icon when i am using type MenuItem

Comment: Any way to make this compatible with parameter destructuring? I get TS errors if I try `function myFunc({ title, icon, component, click }: MenuItem)`

Property 'component' does not exist on type 'MenuItem'.
Property 'click' does not exist on type 'MenuItem'.

Comment: There's a library with a bunch of utility types from Sindresorhus known as type-fest. Link [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest)

Comment: @CletusW I don't think it's possible to cleanly de-structure every prop at once this way. Best alternative seems to be: destructure the common props & spread the rest like `{ title, icon, ...rest }`, then destructure rest conditionally like `if ('click' in rest) { const { click } = rest; handleClickCase(click); } else { const { component } = rest; handleComponentCase(component); }`. It's a bit more verbose, but it's more readable because you're explicitly targeting the different scenarios, and typescript knows that `!('click' in rest)` implies `'component' in rest`.

Answer (score 362):

With the help of the `Exclude` type which was added in TypeScript 2.8, a generalizable way to require at least one of a set of properties is provided is:

```
type RequireAtLeastOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>> 
    & {
        [K in Keys]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Pick<T, Exclude<Keys, K>>>
    }[Keys]
```

And a partial but not absolute way to require that one and only one is provided is:

```
type RequireOnlyOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>>
    & {
        [K in Keys]-?:
            Required<Pick<T, K>>
            & Partial<Record<Exclude<Keys, K>, undefined>>
    }[Keys]
```

[Here is a TypeScript playground link showing both in action.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20RequireAtLeastOne%3CT%2C%20Keys%20extends%20keyof%20T%20%3D%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20Keys%3E%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20Keys%5D-%3F%3A%20Required%3CPick%3CT%2C%20K%3E%3E%20%26%20Partial%3CPick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3CKeys%2C%20K%3E%3E%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5BKeys%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MenuItem%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20title%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20component%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20click%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20icon%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ClickOrComponent%20%3D%20RequireAtLeastOne%3CMenuItem%2C%20'click'%20%7C%20'component'%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20withComponent%3A%20ClickOrComponent%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22test%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20component%3A%2052%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20icon%3A%20%22icon%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20withClick%3A%20ClickOrComponent%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22test%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20click%3A%2054%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20icon%3A%20%22icon%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20errorWithNeither%3A%20ClickOrComponent%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22test%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20icon%3A%20%22icon%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20noErrorWithBoth%3A%20ClickOrComponent%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22test%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20click%3A%2054%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20component%3A%2024%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20icon%3A%20%22icon%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20errorWithBothWhenOneHasWrongType%3A%20ClickOrComponent%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22test%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20click%3A%2054%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20component%3A%20%22should%20be%20number%20here%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20icon%3A%20%22icon%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RequireOnlyOne%3CT%2C%20Keys%20extends%20keyof%20T%20%3D%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20Keys%3E%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%26%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20Keys%5D-%3F%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Required%3CPick%3CT%2C%20K%3E%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%20Partial%3CRecord%3CExclude%3CKeys%2C%20K%3E%2C%20undefined%3E%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5BKeys%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20OnlyOneClickOrComponent%20%3D%20RequireOnlyOne%3CMenuItem%2C%20'click'%20%7C%20'component'%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20noErrorWithOnlyOne%3A%20OnlyOneClickOrComponent%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22test%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20click%3A%20534%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20icon%3A%20%22icon%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20errorWithBoth%3A%20OnlyOneClickOrComponent%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22test%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20click%3A%20534%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20component%3A%2053%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20icon%3A%20%22icon%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20interface%20will%20be%20used%20to%20trick%20OnlyOneClickAtComponent%20into%20allowing%20an%20object%20with%20both%20%20%0D%0Ainterface%20ClickMenuItem%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20title%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20click%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20icon%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20hasBoth%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22test%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20click%3A%2054%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20component%3A%2024%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20icon%3A%20%22icon%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20No%20error%20because%20excess%20properties%20are%20only%20disallowed%20when%20directly%20assigning%20an%20object%20literal%20%0D%0Aconst%20temp%3A%20ClickMenuItem%20%3D%20hasBoth%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20No%20error%20despite%20temp%20actually%20having%20both%20because%20TS%20only%20knows%20that%20temp%20is%20a%20ClickMenuItem%20%0D%0Aconst%20trickIntoAllowingBoth%3A%20OnlyOneClickOrComponent%20%3D%20temp%0D%0A)

The caveat with `RequireOnlyOne` is that TypeScript doesn't always know at compile time every property that will exist at runtime. So obviously `RequireOnlyOne` can't do anything to prevent extra properties it doesn't know about. I provided an example of how `RequireOnlyOne` can miss things at the end of the playground link.

A quick overview of how it works using the following example:

```
interface MenuItem {
  title: string;
  component?: number;
  click?: number;
  icon: string;
}

type ClickOrComponent = RequireAtLeastOne<MenuItem, 'click' | 'component'>
```

1. `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>>` from `RequireAtLeastOne` becomes `{ title: string, icon: string}`, which are the unchanged properties of the keys not included in `'click' | 'component'`
2. `{ [K in Keys]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Pick<T, Exclude<Keys, K>>> }[Keys]` from `RequireAtLeastOne` becomes

   ```
   { 
       component: Required<{ component?: number }> & { click?: number }, 
       click: Required<{ click?: number }> & { component?: number } 
   }[Keys]
   ```

   Which becomes

   ```
   {
       component: { component: number, click?: number },
       click: { click: number, component?: number }
   }['component' | 'click']
   ```

   Which finally becomes

   ```
   {component: number, click?: number} | {click: number, component?: number}
   ```
3. The intersection of steps 1 and 2 above

   ```
   { title: string, icon: string} 
   & 
   ({component: number, click?: number} | {click: number, component?: number})
   ```

   simplifies to

   ```
   { title: string, icon: string, component: number, click?: number} 
   | { title: string, icon: string, click: number, component?: number}
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for descriptive examples. Really informative.

Comment: Thanks for an extremely informative and well formed response. I've been playing with this example so I can better understand it. It appears that if you give `component` and `click` a type other then `any` an object with both at least one set of valid properties will pass. I assume that is because of the way the type reduces to `{ title: string, icon: string, component: any} | { title: string, icon: string, click: any}` Which states the type is 3 properties instead of 4 with one being optional. 

I'm trying to find documentation on the use of the array in the map notation but can't.

Comment: This. is. pure. genius. You should definitely submit them here https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest

Comment: @SamR That is a really good point. I updated the answer to add `& Partial<Pick<T, Exclude<Keys, K>>>` to `RequireAtLeastOne`. I also updated the playground link so `component` and `click` are `number` types instead of `any` to show an example of it now correctly declaring an object invalid in the case you brought up. Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone explain what the hyphen (minus sign) in the expression `[K in keys]-` does?

Comment: @Lopsided It removes any optional modifiers that might have existed for `K` in the original object `T`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655419/mapped-types-removing-optional-modifier 

As for its purpose in `[K in Keys]-?:` specifically: I just did some testing and it looks like it actually doesn't make a difference in the final result, but I put it in just to be certain that `RequireAtLeastOne` behaves the same way regardless of whether the properties specified for `Keys` were originally optional or not.

Comment: A little more complex scenarios, how would it be to `RequireOnlyOneOrNoneOfThem`? And also how to request a combination? Example: `type OnlyOne = RequireOnlyOne<MenuItem, 'click' | 'component' | ('label' & 'options')>` Or click, or component, or label with options

Comment: Note: This is part of the official Microsoft Azure Typescript SDK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/keyvault-certificates/requireatleastone?view=azure-node-latest

Comment: Since TS 3.5 we can make the "at least one of" even shorter by using the `Omit` helper (a shortcut for `Pick` + `Exclude`): `type RequireAtLeastOne<T, R extends keyof T = keyof T> = Omit<T, R> & {
  [ P in R ] : Required<Pick<T, P>> & Partial<Omit<T, P>>
}[R];`. The base frame is the same, so only warrants a comment (quick note: in `[K in keys]-?:`, the `-?` modifier can be safely omitted: optionality is preserved in both versions)

Comment: This is a cute solution to the OP but is not generalizable. In my case, I want properties (A and B) XOR (property C), and it's not at all clear how to use this solution for my very similar problem.  I vastly prefer to turn the problem interface into a [discriminated union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions), as it makes for much more readable code than using advanced language features like this.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine i think one more updated answer for RequireOnlyOne is: ```export type RequireOnlyOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> = Omit<T, Keys> &
  {
    [K in keyof Required<T>]: Required<Pick<T, K>> &
      Partial<Record<Exclude<Keys, K>, undefined>>;
  }[Keys];
``` We can change the -?: operator to set the Type from the second generic type as required

Comment: @RossBrasseaux Although I'm late to the party, for future readers: This minus sign (-) in `-?` is called a "modifier prefix", and what it does is, it removes the ? modifier of keys while remapping. Here's the link to the documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers — I've also added an explanation of how the `RequireAtLeastOne` type works in the next comment.

Comment: 1. The Keys generic param is optional. If is provided, only those keys will produce a new object type in the final union, if is not provided, all keys of T will produce object types in the final union.
2. The first Exclude excludes all keys that are not in `Keys` param, and merges them in all the object types in the final union, without any changes to their ? modifier.
3. The -? removes the optional modifier on all the target keys.
4. `Required<...> & Partial<...>` finalizes the trick! The `Required` part makes the current key required, the `Partial` part makes all remaining keys optional.

Answer (score 136):

There is a simpler solution. No need to rely on [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) or
complex [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) <sup>[(see answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725198/5669456)</sup>:

> 1. Is there a way to require component or click to be set? *(Inclusive `OR`)*

```
type MenuItemOr = {
    title: string;
    icon: string;
} & ({ component: object } | { click: boolean }) 
// brackets are important here: "&" has precedence over "|"

let testOr: MenuItemOr;
testOr = { title: "t", icon: "i" } // error, none are set
testOr = { title: "t", icon: "i", component: {} } // ✔
testOr = { title: "t", icon: "i", click: true } // ✔
testOr = { title: "t", icon: "i", click: true, component: {} } // ✔
```

A [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (`|`) corresponds to inclusive `OR`. It is [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with the non-conditional properties.

Use the [`in`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) operator to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the value back to one of the constituents:

```
if ("click" in testOr) testOr.click // works
```

> 2. Is there a way to require that both properties can't be set? *(Exclusive `OR` / `XOR`)*

```
type MenuItemXor = {
    title: string;
    icon: string;
} & (
        | { component: object; click?: never }
        | { component?: never; click: boolean }
    )

let testXor: MenuItemXor;
testXor = { title: "t", icon: "i" } // error, none are set
testXor = { title: "t", icon: "i", component: {} } // ✔
testXor = { title: "t", icon: "i", click: true } // ✔
testXor = { title: "t", icon: "i", click: true, component: {} } //error,both set
```

Basically *either* `component` *or* `click` can be set, the other should [never <sup>1</sup>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) be added at the same time. TS can make a [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) out of `MenuItemXor`, which corresponds to `XOR`.

This `XOR` condition for `MenuItemXor` is not possible with [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40510700/5669456).

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwoF4oG8oBmccAXFCgK4IBGEATlAL4CwAUGwPQecdQCSAORgAZAKoBlPgDUAolADyAJR5s2oSFACy6Cn2AQE8hjlxso5qMACWwADYQyAZ2B0rKAOYBuMxasBjVCcXNy82RigAMigACnwApFR0YDJ4BLQMJigAHzwoP1t-AGsyamJ7AEMUJgBKHihqOnK-QohgRyhyumgrBLpgSuTIqAALcvawLr8IABN0Kag4ADd6bNVWe0x9ZyMybUo9AyNvVi3gI2xc6zsHKAAiYFuAGih-QLurW8yuKHo6ODpnihEh0ulBHK01BBtsZLjZ7GR7k8XgEUAiPs94sh0oN8ERSFAACwAJky4W+gBRySHQi74K7wu4PZ6vVHvJH5IpkFwUaBk3iUk5Qs4w2lwm6IpkotFsgrNTl0bkYxBYpJkXHEMjE0lQClrb4CTp-ADu9SahUscAWaAWBEsw2gKOcNm5GEcbCsNuit3ZzU+bksgqM1TwPnMpyMADpvWbvob-oVXawLNreGG6JGlYkMt9fv8wm6PV6M9jfVVU0HTImLKn02kksmoLG6PGQ-Xq1H6zm6Hn2D2uHUZAANEQSaRyJQqHvqaB7XT6BAD-40lt0m7OVweY5J5lBdehVjhKLRFtJnJxIsq2DnjCePIywoAfjIaGWDBYlaT5lPeSvwEf5AgL43lGJRlBAlRMC2tQ9hs-rOAudC7DoBzzv8xynPBNKWKKCKMsiby3B8Xy8J2gLAp00DgsAVLABhJhYdcOFIturKKrWGCqoQ6qEiS4S8lA-LoYudEroxEr4eit4cpY8o8vWAmCrRsIMQyTGSixkmytJCrfmxOKcfimq8R2dB-AC9RwMAwwghREK9rw+omXAxrUKa5qWtAcA2pZ9qoI6wDOm0+YxIJaaYpmmAAIRYDgFAoLMBBuDM5bLgp-w1sqWa8I28bPKkGVUe+sE0Wl7bfLF8WJdMYQ-LY4K5N8IUdBQwCIOU1h+OUti2CA5AGk5MwpXBJV3vW2WOM8pRwBUKCDcVoU-vW5UQAlaBVfuQA)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Technically, `prop?: never` gets resolved to `prop?: undefined`, though former is often used for illustration.</sub>

Comment: How to deal with `testOr.click;` that returns the error `Property 'click' does not exist on type 'MenuItemOr'.` ?

Comment: @EduardoDallmann you can use the [`in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator) to check, if either properties exist on the object ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAshB2BXAksCBbA8gJygXigG8BYAKCgqmAEtgAbCALigGdhtr4BzAbjMqjUAxgHt4zNh259SAXygAyKAApCUUejBiEwZknQAjCLnkAfIurrCA1swMiRDAIbwosgJRkyAEwhC6TtjQDMBUEGw4zHBIqBg4PFAA9IlQXNQAbgisIujQaBG46YHUTgYMUADutAAWsAgoaFi4oJBepNQAZioARP423YKu+cA47kT8lMM4AHR9QtZJKRUi2NYsExTJYQWzOVrwOotQxtgrZPJknT0a+zoDnNsj2GMk5JPhT7ua2vChW8urdZvTYpKbYWZWeZHE5nORAA))

Comment: Nice answer! But can you explain how it works? I have a hard time understanding the union (`|`) with only a right operand. Thank you

Comment: @NorTicUs If you mean the leading `|` inside `& ( ... )` of `MenuItemXor`: this is just a shortcut for the union operator for better type formatting / separating over lines. Like [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAECMHsBcAtQIYCcCmoDOCC2KCwAoaATwAc0AxSSUAXlANEdAB8NokBLAOwHMGnWXAK5ZwKJP0YFiZUJUgAmWm068WoYaPFA) - no magic involved :)

Comment: It's slick but a slight loss in readability IMO compared to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281828/2306481

Comment: @Sheraff I guess, it boils down to usage of [interfaces vs type aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types). Personally, I prefer type aliases in most cases, as they can be used more flexibly than interfaces. It certainly is also a matter of taste/style.

Comment: Any way to make this compatible with parameter destructuring? I get TS errors if I try `function myFunc({ title, icon, component }: MenuItemOr) {}`

Comment: @CletusW You might define `component` additionally as weak property - either in the `MenuItemOr` type or if it's just for one case as parameter intersection `MenuItemOr & { component?: object }`, see [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/QmbebN). In this case, the destructured `component` property gets type `object | undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer @ford04. I'm curious if you can look at my similar [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/t0e1i?file=/index.ts:22-27) (lines 22-27) and see why the type checking doesn't work as I'd expect. What am I missing?

Comment: @JeremyThomerson use `loc.url !== undefined` instead. A truthy check is not sufficient, as in the false case, `loc.url` might still be an empty string `""`, which does not fit the `LocalLocation` type constituent expecting `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks @ford04! I got so focused on the truthy case, I totally forgot that `Boolean("")` is falsy 

Comment: the `in` operator recommendation was very helpful ( I wish optional chaining (`obj?.myProp`) also worked)

Answer (score 21):

An alternative without multiple interfaces is

```
export type MenuItem = {
  title: string;
  component: any;
  icon: string;
} | {
  title: string;
  click: any;
  icon: string;
};

const item: MenuItem[] = [
  { title: "", icon: "", component: {} },
  { title: "", icon: "", click: "" },
  // Shouldn't this error out because it's passing a property that is not defined
  { title: "", icon: "", click: "", component: {} },
  // Does error out :)
  { title: "", icon: "" }
];
```

I've asked a similar question at [How to create a Partial-like that requires a single property to be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230773/how-to-create-a-partial-like-that-requires-a-single-property-to-be-set)

The above could be simplified, but it may or may not be easier to read

```
export type MenuItem = {
  title: string;
  icon: string;
} & (
 {component: any} | {click: string}
)
```

Note that none of these prevent you from adding both because TypeScript does allow extra properties on objects that use AND/OR See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15447

Comment: You could use `&` to and extract `title` and `icon` to a separate type. :)

Answer (score 18):

I use this:

```js
type RequireField<T, K extends keyof T> = T & Required<Pick<T, K>>
```

Usage:

```js
let a : RequireField<TypeA, "fieldA" | "fieldB">;
```

This makes `fieldA` *and* `fieldB` required.

Comment: For other readers: please note that this type will not make *one of* ( OR context ) the properties to be required, but rather both of them ( that said, in an AND context it will do just fine ).

Comment: I had to tweak the solution a little bit to make it work here: `type RequireField<T, K extends keyof T> = T | Required<Pick<T, K>>`. I changed the intersection operator (`&`) to the union operator (`|`).

Answer (score 9):

I ended up doing:

```
export interface MenuItem {
  title: string;
  icon: string;
}

export interface MenuItemComponent extends MenuItem{
  component: any;
}

export interface MenuItemClick extends MenuItem{
  click: any;
}
```

Then I used:

```
 appMenuItems: Array<MenuItemComponent|MenuItemClick>;
```

But was hoping there was a way to model it with a single interface.

Comment: Actually Microsoft suggests it should be: `<MenuItemComponent|MenuItemClick>[]`

Answer (score 7):

I like using `Pick` along with a base type that includes all properties to establish these kinds of conditional requirements.

```
interface MenuItemProps {
  title: string;
  component: any;
  click: any;
  icon: string;
}

export type MenuItem =
  Pick<MenuItemProps, "title" | "icon" | "component"> |
  Pick<MenuItemProps, "title" | "icon" | "click">
```

This is clean and also flexible. You can get arbitrarily complex with your requirements, asserting things like "require either all the properties, just these two properties, or just this one property" and so on while keeping your declaration simple and readable.

Comment: interfaces cannot "=" a type.  If this was `export interface MenuItem = ...` it would be valid.

Comment: @J'e I think you mean `export type MenuItem = ...`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple way to implement either but not both

```
type MenuItem =  {
  title: string;
  component: any;
  click?: never;
  icon: string;
} | {
  title: string;
  component?: never;
  click: any;
  icon: string;
}

// good
const menuItemWithComponent: MenuItem = {
  title: 'title',
  component: "my component",
  icon: "icon"
}

// good
const menuItemWithClick: MenuItem = {
  title: 'title',
  click: "my click",
  icon: "icon"
}

// compile error
const menuItemWithBoth: MenuItem = {
  title: 'title',
  click: "my click",
  component: "my click",
  icon: "icon"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution:

```
type RequiredKeys<T, K extends keyof T> = Required<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K>;
```

```
type MenuItem2 = RequiredKeys<MenuItem, "component" | "click">;
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach combines `never` and `Omit`. Benefits here are that it's easy to understand and also easy to update if you need to add more properties.

```js
interface Base {
  title: string;
  icon: string;
  component?: never;
  click?: never;
}

interface OnlyComponent {
  component: any;
}

interface OnlyClick {
  click: any;
}

export type MenuItem = (Omit<Base, 'component'> & OnlyComponent) | (Omit<Base, 'click'> & OnlyClick);
```

You can use `in` to narrow an instance of `MenuItem`:

```js
const item: MenuItem = {
  title: 'A good title';
  icon: 'fa-plus';
  component: SomeComponent;
};

//...

if('component' in item) {
  const Comp = item.component;
  //...
}
```

Comment: The `never` option seems to also be useful for excluding certain properties when defining an interface with string-enumerable indexes, e.g. `interface Columns{ [column: string]: any; columns?: never; }` to prevent confusion with a wrapping class `interface ColumnData{ columns: Columns; }` (real example; I kept missing places I needed to unwrap before passing to functions, but this should help). The only concern I might have is whether, at runtime, I might end up with a column named `columns`; but since Typescript compiles to JavaScript, this type-checking should be lost by runtime, correct?

Answer (score 0):

To just extends upon the cool answers above! And for the people that land here while searching for a **Partial** version with requiring capability! Here a snippet i made to take!

## PartialReq

You want to have a Partial of an interface, but in mean time require some of the fields! Here how it's done

```js
export type PartialReq<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    Pick<Partial<T>, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>>
    & {
        [K in Keys]: T[K]
    };
```

## Use example

```js
export interface CacheObj<SigType = any, ValType = any> {
    cache: Map<SigType, ValType>,
    insertionCallback: InsertionCallback<SigType, ValType> // I want this to be required
}

// ...

export class OneFlexibleCache<SigType = any, ValType = any> {
    private _cacheObj: CacheObj<SigType, ValType>;

    constructor(
        cacheObj: PartialReq<CacheObj<SigType, ValType>, 'insertionCallback'> // <-- here
                                                                           //  i used it
    ) {
        cacheObj = cacheObj || {};

        this._cacheObj = {

// ...

// _______________ usage
this._caches.set(
    cacheSignature,
    new OneFlexibleCache<InsertionSigType, InsertionValType>({
        insertionCallback // required need to be provided
    })
);
```

Here you can see that it work perfectly

[image]

If the required not provided

[image]

## UPDATE: For the usage that i implied above here a better answer

I just went by the doc and found **Omit**.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk

I came to add it. But before i do, I just seen this cool answer. It cover all:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216010/7668448

Just check it out! It show how to do it for all the different version of Typescript! And for the sake of not repeating ! Go and check!