# Typescript interface with BOTH properties or NEITHER

Tags: typescript, interface

I have key-value pairs that 'come in pairs'. In other words, if I have one key-value pair `A:B` then I also want to require my object to have `C:D`, but it can also have neither pair. (Think `message:string` for one pair and `min-length:number` for the other pair.) Is there an elegant way to make an interface made up of an arbitrary number of such pairs?

Edit: 
For clarification, I want to design an interface for objects where these would be allowed:

```
{
    //First pair
    message1: string;
    minLength1: number;
    //Second pair
    message2: string;
    minLength2: number;
    // ...
}

{
    //First pair omitted altogether

    //Just the second pair
    message2: string;
    minLength2: number;
}
```

... but where objects like the following are NOT allowed because you only have one half of a pair:

```
{
    //First pair
    message1: string;
    // minLength1: number; // Error †
    // ...
}
```

† Error: if `message1` is included then you must also include `minLength1`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For a given pair of properties, the closest approximation you can make to requiring both properties or neither is a union of the type with both properties and a type with optional properties of type `never` (which prevents the properties from being present with a value other than `undefined`).  I got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52722384).  This will give you an error in the right cases, though the error message may not be particularly helpful.  Then you can just intersect the unions for all the pairs of properties you want (as long as you don't have more than about 10 pairs, because when TypeScript simplifies a type, it distributes intersections of unions to make unions of intersections, which will blow up the size of the type exponentially).  For your example:

```
type AllOrNone<T> = T | {[K in keyof T]?: never};

type MyType = AllOrNone<{
    message1: string;
    minLength1: number;
}> & AllOrNone<{
    message2: string;
    minLength2: number;
}>;
```

If you're really bothered by the `undefined` case and are willing to use a generic function to validate your objects instead of writing down a single type, then you can do something like this:

```
type CheckAllOrNone<A, T> =
    T | (keyof A & keyof T extends never ? {} : never);

type CheckMyType<A> = CheckAllOrNone<A, {
    message1: string;
    minLength1: number;
}> & CheckAllOrNone<A, {
    message2: string;
    minLength2: number;
}>;

function checkMyType<A extends CheckMyType<A>>(arg: A) {
    return arg;
}
```

Comment: For anyone already using `type-fest`, this type is available as [`RequireAllOrNone`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/require-all-or-none.d.ts)

Comment: Could you use this type to generic a key pair based objects ? Like: `{ \`key_${number}_1\`: number, \`key_${number}_2\`: number }`