# How to define all-or-nothing type?

Tags: typescript

I want a generic type that satisfies the below cases:

```
type AB = {a: string, b: string};
type AllOrNothing<T> = ...                   // how to define this such that...

const empty: AllOrNothing<AB> = {};            // case 1: nothing, OK
const ab: AllOrNothing<AB> = {a:"a",b:"b"};    // case 2: all fields, OK
const a: AllOrNothing<AB> = {a:""};            // case 3: partial, NOT OK
```

I have tried the below:

```
// case 1 fails compile
export type AllOrNothing<T> = { [k in keyof T]: T[k] } | { [k in keyof T]: never };

// case 3 passes compile
export type AllOrNothing<T> = { [k in keyof T]: T[k] } | {}
```

Comment: `T | { [key: string]: never }`?

Comment: Alternatively, maybe you can rethink your design. Do you really need this over `T | undefined` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript interface with BOTH properties or NEITHER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056655/typescript-interface-with-both-properties-or-neither)

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is almost correct, you need to set all of the properties to never but also make them optional.

We can use `Partial` for that.

```js
type AllOrNothing<T extends Record<string, any>> = T | Partial<Record<keyof T, never>>;

type AB = { a: string, b: string };

const empty: AllOrNothing<AB> = {};               // OK
const ab: AllOrNothing<AB> = { a: "a", b: "b" };  // OK
const a: AllOrNothing<AB> = { a: "" };            // NOT OK
const c: AllOrNothing<AB> = { c: "" };            // NOT OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using conditional types

First create your type like so:

```js
type AllOrNothing<T> = 
T extends "all" ? { a: "a"; b: "b"; } 
: T extends "nothing" ? { a: "" } : never
```

This essentially creates a type saying if `T` is equal to `all` then it will be type a and if `T` is equal to `nothing` then it will be of type b. Otherwise it will never be a type

Then your type would work something like:

```js
// This will have the all type
const all: AllOrNothing<"all"> = { 
    a: "Hello",
    b: "World"
}

// It is an empty object
const nothing: AllOrNothing<"nothing"> = {
    a: ""
}
```

Read about conditional types here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html