# how to implement AllOrNone When have to check one more depth

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In my project, there is a Header Component that is used throughout the page.

Each page that use Header Component can pass option whether to show button or not required in each pag and event handler.

Current Header Component Prop interface is as follow

```
interface HeaderProps {
  options?: {
    back?: boolean;
    close?: boolean;
    next?: boolean | [boolean, Disabled];
    complete?: boolean;
    notification?: boolean;

  };
  onClickBack?: () => void;
  onClickClose?: () => void;
  onClickNext?: () => void;
  onClickComplete?: () => void;
  onClickNotification?: () => void;
}
```

If Header Component got back option in options prop, Header Component must get onClickBack function. and vice versa is same. The following examples may help with understanding.

```
// ❌ make error
<Header options={{ back: true }} />

// 
<Header options={{ back: true }} onClickBack={() => console.log('dummy')}/>

// ❌ make error
<Header options={{ close: true, save: [true, false] }} onClickClose={() => console.log('dummy')}/>

// 
<Header options={{ close: true, save: [true, false] }} onClickClose={() => console.log('dummy')} onClickSave={() => console.log('dummy')} />

// 
<Header />
```

I was trying to implement type by refering to

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056655/typescript-interface-with-both-properties-or-neither](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/require-all-or-none.d.ts#L32

So i implement code like this.

```
type Disabled = false;

interface HeaderProps {
  options: {
    back: boolean;
    close: boolean;
    next: boolean | [boolean, Disabled];
    complete: boolean;
    notification: boolean;
  };
  onClickBack: () => void;
  onClickClose: () => void;
  onClickNext: () => void;
  onClickComplete: () => void;
  onClickNotification: () => void;
}

type AllOrNone<A extends HeaderProps, U extends A> = (
  | Required<U>
  | Partial<
      {
        options: Record<keyof U['options'], never>;
      } & {
        [M in keyof Omit<U, 'options'>]: never;
      }
    >
) &
  Omit<HeaderProps, 'options' | keyof Omit<U, 'options'>>;

type Props<A extends HeaderProps> = AllOrNone<
  A,
  { // ‍♂️ error here
    options: {
      back: boolean;
    };
    onClickBack: () => void;
  }
>;
```

as you see above code, it makes error

> Type '{ options: { back: boolean; }; onClickBack: () => void }' does not satisfy the constraint 'A'.
> 'A' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ options: { back: boolean; }; onClickBack: () => void; }'. ts(2344)